# What is the official stance of the SE team on the recent Net Neutrality rulings?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I was a little surprised not to see anything here on Meta or on the SE blog regarding the recent Net Neutrality rulings in the US.

I'm hoping to find the team's official take on the issue and whether or not they expect to be making any changes to deal with the potential change in landscape.

Please note: I'm looking for an **official** response. I realize this may be a controversial issue and I really don't want to stir up debate.

So... What, if any, is the official stance of the SE team on the recent Net Neutrality rulings?

---

From: [Wikipedia, Net neutrality in the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_neutrality_in_the_United_States)

> On January 14, 2014, the DC Circuit Court determined in the case of
>   Verizon v. Federal Communications Commission[[38]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_neutrality_in_the_United_States#cite_note-38) that the FCC has no
>   authority to enforce Network Neutrality rules, since service providers
>   are not identified as "common carriers".[[39]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_neutrality_in_the_United_States#cite_note-39)It did, however, agree
>   that FCC has the ability to regulate broadband and may craft more
>   specific rules that stop short of identifying service providers as
>   common carriers, according to lobbyist group Public Knowledge.[[40]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_neutrality_in_the_United_States#cite_note-40) The
>   likelihood of this occurring under new FCC Chairman Tom Wheeler is
>   low, as he has stated in the past that he is not opposed to providers
>   receiving consideration to prioritize certain traffic.[[41]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_neutrality_in_the_United_States#cite_note-41)

Comment: Can you provide some specific links please, and perhaps a line or two about those rulings? The question won't make much sense in five years' time otherwise.

Comment: Have I missed something? Didn't recent rulings essentially send the FCC back to the drawing board, meaning there's is not all that much to have an official stance on just yet?

Comment: @Pëkka I was having a somewhat difficult time finding any unbiased reporting on the issue... I'll keep looking.

Comment: @apaul34208 what kind of official response are you looking for?  Unless I am missing something, unless a site or provider is going to be impacted directly by decision, the answer is still only going to be a matter of opinion.  Stack Exchange doesn't really drive enough bandwidth to really be impacted by this, so they are more of an observer, correct?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I wasn't sure if Stack Exchange would be impacted or not, that was a big piece of what I was looking for. Mostly it seemed odd that something that could change the internet as we currently know it hasn't been publicly addressed in any way.

Comment: @Bart Have you seen any unbiased reporting on the FCC going back to the drawing board? I've read about it in the The New York Times and The Wall Street Journal, but both seem to be a bit opinionated as to what that means for the outcome.

Comment: Well ... in how far is a newspaper unbiased. But at the very least the FCC didn't appeal the latest ruling, and isn't going to (or so I read). Of course this will no doubt mean a rewrite of the same stuff in a different form, but unless that is concrete, and there's something to respond to, I'm not sure it really serves a purpose to address the issue in too much depth. Then again, you're not looking for my answer anyway. ;)

Comment: I think this question is answered pretty much in entirety by https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297816/307622.