# Net Neutrality and Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, politics, net-neutrality

**It's July 12th! (2017)** (in Coordinated Universal Stack Exchange Time)

Today we're gonna be showing a banner directing readers to the blog post (and thus, indirectly, this discussion) from every Stack Exchange site.

Special thanks to [Jon Chan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/242868/jon-chan) for whipping up a *dismissible* banner for this, so we didn't get stuck abusing system messages for it.

BIG thanks to everyone who has participated in this discussion thus far; there's a lot of good information and debate here, I've learned a lot from it and I hope y'all did too.

This discussion started as a way to help me focus my thoughts while I was working with [Kaitlin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/315919/kcpike) on [the blog post to announce this company's support](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/30/raise-voice-proclaim-need-net-neutrality/) for Fight for the Future's [Internet-Wide Day of Action to Save Net Neutrality](https://www.battleforthenet.com/july12/).

In particular, I want to get a better feel for why would anyone be *against* this. To better understand both why folks feel it's important *and* what gives them pause when asked to support it.

So if you've got something to add, please do write an answer!

### A bit of background

Back in 2014, the United States Federal Communication Commission, in response to numerous complaints and concerns, implemented a set of rules that prohibit Internet Service Providers from blocking specific content providers or charging them for access to their networks. Essentially, a set of rules that prevent an ISP from double-dipping on service they're already being paid for, or blocking access to specific websites just for the hell of it.

In order to do this, they had to change how ISPs were classified, moving them from a "Title I" classification to "Title II" - more or less the same framework for regulation that's been in place for phone companies for decades, establishing them as a so-called "[common carrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_carrier)" - that is to say, one which may not discriminate between customers. If you already assumed that this is how the Internet worked, you're not alone; however, due to how they were classified previously the [Federal Communication Commission (FCC)](https://www.fcc.gov/) had been unable to *enforce* rules that would ensure that traffic over the Internet would continue be allowed to work as, well, traffic over the Internet was expected to work.

In 2016, US President Donald Trump appointed Ajit Pai as Chairman of the FCC. [Pai is former Associate General Counsel for Verizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajit_V._Pai) and he is [leading the Net Neutrality rollback](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/jul/12/ajit-pai-fcc-net-neutrality-open-internet).

If this all sounds really boring and procedural... Well, it is. The bit that's gotten so many people worked up is that there are companies and officials actively fighting against it, including the current chairman of the FCC.

### The reason to get interested in this now

I'm gonna save some space here and link to a couple of relevant sites:

- [The proposed rule change from the FCC](https://apps.fcc.gov/edocs_public/Query.do?numberFld=&numberFld2=&docket=17-108&dateFld=&docTitleDesc=)
- [A fairly thorough article on Ars Technica covering this proposed change](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/05/net-neutrality-goes-down-in-flames-as-fcc-votes-to-kill-title-ii-rules/)

I strongly encourage reading both of them if you wanna get a better feel for what this is about, but the short version is: fairly soon, the FCC will vote on these proposed changes. So if there's a chance at influencing the outcome of that vote, we gotta speak out now.

### Your thoughts

So why bring this up for discussion? Because this is something that has the potential to *directly* affect Stack Overflow, both the company and anyone using the site. Even folks who aren't based in the US have probably benefited from the work of those who are at one point or another; if nothing else, this is where our servers live so any additional headaches when it comes to providing access are gonna be a problem.

More than that though... As many of you have observed at one point or another, y'all are smarter than me. Better informed. So if this is something Stack Overflow is gonna be involved in, it should be *your* voices that are heard, whether in support of this campaign or *especially* if you have objections. As [I said a few months back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342903/well-always-endeavor-to-do-whats-right-well-try-to-do-it-better-next-time/342929#342929), we *need* more of this sort of discussion here on meta, and this is a prime example of an issue where informed public discussion is critical.

So let's hear it: why should or shouldn't we all head over to https://www.battleforthenet.com/ right now and use the handy form to send a letter to the FCC?

---

Hat-tip to Alexander O'Mara for digging up two fascinating questions on net neutrality from Network Engineering and Economics:

- [Network Neutrality, how does it actually work, technically speaking?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/network-neutrality-how-does-it-actually-work-technically-speaking)
- [Is net neutrality not important in a competitive market of internet providers?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4685/is-net-neutrality-not-important-in-a-competitive-market-of-internet-providers)

Hat-tip to BobbyA for sharing this Ars Technica piece on [How to write a meaningful FCC comment supporting net neutrality](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/07/saving-net-neutrality-tips-for-writing-persuasive-comments-to-the-fcc/)

Special thanks to EBrown for writing a detailed response here, [including advice for folks who don't live in the US](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297816/net-neutrality-and-stack-overflow-stack-exchange/297821#297821).

And props to Ben Collins for writing at length about why he believes [the government shouldn't be involved in this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297816/net-neutrality-and-stack-overflow-stack-exchange/297826#297826).

Procedural note: I'm gonna be clearing comments on the question (deleting them) periodically as a practical measure - *please* leave an answer if you've something useful to add here. [Alternately, join me in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1114/discussion-on-question-by-shog9-net-neutrality-and-stack-overflow-stack-exchan).

Comment: Don't feel like writing an answer? Tired of informative, well-considered debate? Hate not being interrupted by tangential opinions while you're typing? [Join me in chat!](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1114/discussion-on-question-by-shog9-net-neutrality-and-stack-overflow-stack-exchan)  But if you wanna post here, please do it in an answer; I'll be clearing comments on this question periodically from here out.

Comment: Meta: assuming you might use that dismissible banner for other things in the future, I hope that the dismissal that's sticky enough to last the day isn't sticky enough to last forever.

Comment: It is a shame that the whole post just fails to address why a non US citizen is reading this, at least until the edit mentioning EBrown's answer.

Comment: Umm, it's July *13*. not July 12 folks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a past event and new answers can't really be relevant anymore. (Ideally, historical lock would be applied)

Comment: Net Neutrality is in the news again. There is a question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303548/168333) asking if Stack Overflow (the company) will involve itself and/or the community in this discussion.

Comment: Wanted to post an answer but question is closed. There is a statement in Russia's civic code basically saying that air cannot be sold i.e. it is illegal to ask for payment for doing nothing (intellectual rights obviously do not fall under this statement because author produced the thing he owns before asking to pay for usage of it). It means that any attempt to require payment from either client or resource to access some specific resource at full speed would be illegal (but it won't be illegal to throttle access to the specific resource indefinitely). Is there anything similar in USA?

Comment: Why am I not surprised that "50,000 net neutrality complaints were excluded from FCC’s repeal docket"?  https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/12/fcc-refused-to-include-50000-net-neutrality-complaints-in-repeal-docket/

Comment: [Now the FCC has voted to repeal net neutrality](http://money.cnn.com/2017/12/14/technology/fcc-net-neutrality-vote/index.html), it's up to Congress to overturn the decision. But it doesn't look good.

Comment: Want to visualize the internet without Net Neutrality?  See https://medium.com/@lex.sheehan/net-neutrality-illustrated-b4d23d9d5320

Comment: I was told there would be a zombie apocalypse as a result of net neutrality being... controlled by elected representatives of the people rather than an unelected body of bureaucrats? Goddamnit, where's my zombie apocalypse? I've been preparing for YEARS and I'm turning blue in certain parts.

Comment: I'm at this moment preparing a meal of [chickens and rice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53811/why-was-apocalyptic-defense-closed/53869#53869) - if you hear a knock on your door later tonight, don't answer it @Won't. No matter how much I tell you I'm fine.

Comment: I almost think I support what you're saying, and I don't understand what you actually Posted.

Your explanation of the problem is so full of technicalities, they cancel each other out and leave the whole meaning… uh… nothing obvious, anyway.… 

Could you re-phrase this, and take back your original?

Answer (score 516):

In Russia, not only don't we have laws specifically restricting ISPs from doing such nasty things, but also Internet censorship is actively put to practice by one of our federal services, [Roskomnadzor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Service_for_Supervision_in_the_Sphere_of_Telecom,_Information_Technologies_and_Mass_Communications).

Most of the ISPs in Russia don't even have means of [DPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection), which is why sites are primarily blocked by IP addresses, which often leads to catastrophic consequences. For example, they are not hesitant to add IP addresses from pools of Amazon and such, which can effectively block thousands of websites. Not to mention that some social networks (e.g. DeviantArt) and blogging platforms (e.g. Blogger and Tumblr) are blocked entirely just because some small fraction of their users post something "inappropriate for children" (but it's blocked for everyone, not just children).

We've lost this battle a long time ago, and now it became a guerilla war: recently Russian Internet-freedom activists started to sabotage censorship by buying blacklisted domains and setting their DNS records to IP addresses of Roskomnadzor sites, `*.gov.ru` sites, and some of the most popular resources out there (Wikipedia, Google, etc.). Many smaller ISPs directly add IPs from DNS records to their blacklists, and as a result, they blocked those websites.

With that being said, I honestly envy you guys in the USA. First, you still have a chance to affect the decision of the FCC. Second, you are, as far as I can see, much more politically active in general compared to us Russians.

Don't give them any chances to limit your rights. If they will have a chance to use censorship of any kind, they most definitely will, as the [law of the instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) says.

Good luck.

---

Note for net neutrality naysayers and those who are pro-censorship.

You are welcome to visit Russia. If at some point your MacBook will stop receiving updates, or your favorite news site doesn't work, it's probably because they accidentally blocked some IP address from a floating IP address pool or something like that. Enjoy the pain.

@Machavity And yes, they have already blocked Google at least once, that time by accident.

Comment: I'm not surprised by this (Putin isn't exactly a free speech guy). But saying that Net Neutrality is about censorship is a gross mischaracterization of this issue. In fact, outright censorship would be illegal in the US (Constitution and First Amendment). And it should be noted that the EU (which has Net Neutrality) is also a [growing proponent of Internet censorship](http://dailycaller.com/2016/12/05/eu-threatens-massive-internet-censorship-if-big-tech-wont-come-to-heel/). Let's not conflate censorship with Net Neutrality.

Comment: @Machavity I read this as a warning of "it's a slippery slope, and it starts here". The border between "censorship" and "protecting your customers' interests" is fuzzy and hard to argue about. It's a different battle, but to my understanding net neutrality is currently the main restriction on ISPs that prevents that battle from starting.

Comment: @Machavity Censorship is directly forbidden by Russian Constitution as well ([article 29, part 5](http://constitution.ru/10003000/10003000-4.htm): "Цензура запрещается." / "Censorship is prohibited."). But guess what? They say it's "for protecting the children". So they block everything left and right. How can you protect children by blocking LINE messenger, for example? (And now they want to block Telegram.) It was already shown that blocking sites selling illegal drugs did *not* lead to a decrease of illicit drug use among teenagers, so their "reasons" are merely excuses.

Comment: As for Putin, you may mistakingly think that he's a rare exception, but I imagine that many ISP companies in the USA can possibly have their own smaller putins who would like to do, if allowed, anything what benefits them. Power corrupts.

Comment: This answer basically boils down to censorship.  Net Neutrality is not about censorship.  It is about charging, limiting or slowing access, bandwidth, etc by the ISP's.  These are different matters entirely and should be handled differently.

Comment: @Matt Net Neutrality is about censorship too. Yes, my answer is about censorship. But it's still relevant. Throttling can be used as a "mild" censorship as well, but it's not the point. What I wanted to say is, once you give anyone control over what you see on the Internet, they will abuse it for their benefit. For example, most social networks do that by suggesting you the posts which you are most likely to like/share, not those that will inform you about most important things. In the long run, for a large number of people, it's a big deal. Fewer things like that you have, the better.

Comment: They blocked Github at least 2 times, and for quite prolonged period of time. Linkedin is blocked to this day. To those who claim it's the problem of Russia only, I should remind that US banned all of US-based services in Crimea, from GMail to Docker.

Comment: A crime happened. A website posted an information (e.g. child pornography) which is not allowed in Russian Federation. A court ruled that while the information cannot be removed from a foreign website, our ISPs can block this information. Collateral damage happened. Certain not-illegal information was blocked as well. Does that mean that we should allow circulation of child pornography in our country? Nay. Obey the law. Those so-called "Internet-freedom activists" are criminals and have to be prosecuted. Do not endorse such criminal activities.

Comment: @Abyx - a crime happened. A website user posted child porn (which is illegal pretty much everywhere btw). Punishing people who had nothing to do with this is counterproductive and isn't harming the people who perpetrated the crime. We should force our governments to fund a UN special unit to provide investigators to find the culprits and do horrible things to them so that it can not happen again. We do have international police and ways of dealing with international crime. We do have international courts. We can find and we can prosecute these people, then do horrible things to them.

Comment: @Matt The OP literally calls for answers that expand upon the topic. That means answers can focus primarily on one aspect to the exclusion of others.

Comment: @Abyx We have an example of country that is fine to kill millions for the sake of prosecuting one Iraq leader for disobedience. If collateral damage happens, it cannot be called law.

Comment: I think you've got it backwards, net neutrality _is_ censorship.  There are many references to "legal" content being ok for the ISPs to not be neutral about.  I dont want all the stuff that is categorized as hate speech by relativists winding up getting censored and thats where we would be heading had Clinton been elected. So I'm glad they're taking the weed wacker to Net Neutrality.

Comment: @PeterTurner I *know* we have it forwards. It appears you have it qɐɔʞʍɐɹps ⅋ ndsᴉpǝpoʍu. Title II explicitly disallows censorship, and makes no exceptions for your beloved hate speech. You might try checking your facts [redacted unnecessary and speculative insult --ed.].

Comment: @alex I see what you mean, and I'm wrong about Title II.  So, I think we agree any Net Neutrality bill that includes references to censorship of any kind should be opposed...  I wonder why, if content policing was a provision in every Net Neutrality _bill_ that we even consider the current rules Net Neutrality?

Comment: This is a little confusing. It seems as though @AlexanderO'Mara is berating government regulation (in Russia) for being a problem, and then saying that government regulation (in the US) is the solution.

Comment: @SuperJer It's only confusing if you don't know the difference between regulation (to prevent censorship by ISPs) and government censorship. I actively oppose things like SOPA, which could have been misused for censorship.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara My point is, the perceived need for net neutrality regulation here in the US is actually the result of a complex system of other regulations that should be rolled back instead. These other regulations effectively establish monopolies, prevent competition, and disable the consumer's ability to hold the companies with which they do business from effectively holding them accountable.  Net neutrality regulation adds another layer of complexity that will have far-reaching unintended effects that are obscured by the wash of causes already in place.

Comment: @SuperJer That's not a perceived need, it's a practical need. Sure, we should roll back those anticompetitive regulations. Then, and only then, should we even considered removing the protection we have in the mean time. Funny how the ISP monopolies and their government tools don't want to do that, though. They just want to take away the protections we do have.

Comment: Net neutrality is a practical need.  It is only perception that the only way to get it is through regulation.

Comment: @SuperJet Sure, but that's not really what we are discussing here. There are only two options present in the immediate future. Net neutrality by regulation, or lose net neutrality entirely.

Comment: @PeterTurner Net neutrality means no censorship.  It sounds like you want even more net neutrality than we have now, not less.  The FCC's basically doing the opposite of what you want.  That's what everyone's upset about.

Comment: Well, if that isnt the most understandable way to explain it to US citizen how important this issue is. The bottom line just being, "Do you want to end up like Russia?" all are gona say "Hell, no!"

Comment: we are suffering from that in Egypt too, low speed and bad services with high cost

Comment: its not ok if the same people who say "putin is not a free speech guy" are ok with "trigger warning culture","bocking youtube videos", "blocking users for tweets"

Comment: @RandRandom: With due respect - stoking up anti-Russia fears is not the way to go. If you ask people that they would not think about the IP-based censorship, they would have the image the mass media promotes of all "The Russians" as some devious schemers hell-bent on undermining US society.

Comment: This sounds like **propaganda**.

Comment: I want to upvote this post 1001 times, and downvote some of this post's comments. Vox Populi here I come!

Comment: **INDIA** Govt. [TRAI rules in favour of Net neutrality](http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/technology/internet/TRAI-rules-in-favour-of-Net-neutrality/article14068029.ece)

Comment: To me this answer is a strong reason to vote to roll back the FCC changes.@scriptin is talking about the abuses of government in Russia, yet supports giving more power to our government here as though they are the ones who can best prevent these abuses of power. Very contradictory in my opinion.

Comment: @BVernon The US govt is doing the opposite of ours. So, naturally, I support *right* things your govt does. Those regulations you currently have are intended to make the internet a better place, while Russian govt is trying to basically destroy it. Your analogy is thus flawed. The right analogy is to compare Russian govt with ISPs in the USA which want to introduce their own control mechanisms.

Comment: @BVernon And I am *not* supporting "giving more power to [your] government." The FCC already has all the power, I just don't want them to abuse it in order to please few people (owners of ISPs) and harm the rest (you and me). Please don't try to distort my intents. If you have any questions regarding my opinion, please ask me.

Comment: @scriptin You're right. What government so far removed from its founding documents ever treated their precepts with very much regard anyway? "Our Constitution was made only for a moral and religious people. It is wholly inadequate to the government of any other." -John Adams. The government is becoming increasingly amoral due primarily to greed and an ambition to be re-elected. :(

Comment: The answer is factually incorrect - Tumblr, DeviantArt, blogger.com - are not blocked, however, some pages from them may(which I do not wish to spend the time to check that) - because there is url based filtration too, and it works for non-https. From one of the comment - Linkedin is indeed blocked. But, by any means prevent them in US, in Britain in any place from going any inch forward. If you have means to defend yourself - do that. It starts slow and leads to places you won't be. Is that blocking or speed limitation - no matter how they justify it - do not buy it it is the boiling frog.

Comment: @scriptin I am not trying to twist your comments. I clearly said that "to me" your reasoning leads to an opposite conclusion than the one it leads you to. And you yourself just made clear that you do support giving government power when they are doing the right thing. I whole heartedly disagree that "currently doing the right thing" is EVER a basis for which we should give a government more power.

Comment: @MolbOrg Those sites are blocked *entirely* because they are blocked by IP. There are indeed only a few pages in the black list, but due to the lack of DPI capabilities of ISPs, this is enough.

Comment: @BVernon Again, as I said, the FCC already has all the power they need, there is no "giving".

Comment: @MolbOrg Good for you. There are no better options in my place.

Comment: @scriptin call them each day and polite eat their brains. Say you will write rospotrebnadzor, and write if they do not move, take your time. Press them, they do not offer you good quality service. Even if they a small provider, and do not have the proper equipment, they can solve the problem. Do not start from an offense, be polite - but they have to solve the problem. Call them regularly. Even the cheapest provider can solve the problem, they may be not able to do so for everyone but they definitely able do things individually, just stimulate them to do that.

Comment: I do not understand why this answer has been up-voted so many times when it is clearly contradictory. If this answer comes down more on one side it would be against Net Neutrality. These votes seem to show that most people voting do not understand the issue at all.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph, Linked.in is blocked because it does not adhere to public data storage policy. It will be unblocked once it does. Surprise: EU have laws like this too. Your comment and most of this retarded post is full of liberast spin.

Comment: @RandRandom, yeah, red scare always was most effective tactics, isn't it? Speak tons about US.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Even though I'm proudly communist, I appreciate your answer. Both European and Russian laws make no sense, because there is no reason to have servers physically located anywhere. They can silently make backups to a server abroad, sell data to foreign companies and do other nasty things without any violation of law. Cryptographic proofs of data location are physically impossible, hence all stupid laws like that cannot be enforced, hence are not laws, but abstruse gibberish.

Comment: @scriptin No, they don't have the power they need. The courts have already ruled that they don't (google it). It's just that they proceeded against the courts ruling anyway under the Obama administration. It's time for the rule of law to be respected again.

Comment: It _could_ be about censorship.  Giving ISPs the freedom to throttle traffic selectively makes it easier for them to think up legal (but dishonest) excuses for throttling sources that promote net neutrality.  Or promote some other social/political position.

Answer (score 154):

## Summary

Absolutely encourage people to vote to continue the "common carrier" enforcement of ISP's. We do it for telephone companies, we should do it for *all* communication companies. (Including TV, radio, Internet, etc.)

### But...

**However**, we need to empower the people to understand what the *broader* effect of the lack of net neutrality is. The comments on Patric Hoffman's answer help indicate that *even some high-profile users here don't quite get it*, and I think a big portion of that is coming from persons *outside* the U.S., having lived here for my entire life, and growing up *through* the net-neutrality discussion, it's easy for me to visualize, but we need a *good* explanation and information for our foreign friends. You cannot ask this many people to support something of this magnitude *without helping them understand it*. You absolutely have to teach them, even if it takes a little while, why it's necessary.

We need a good potential example, how Stack Exchange (and the broader Internet community) would be affected by this change. How ISP's could begin extorting Stack Exchange for additional money for *any arbitrary reason,* how the entire Internet *as a whole* could be negatively affected. Hell, [according to this article up to **70%** of Internet traffic comes through Northern Virginia](http://www.nextgov.com/big-data/2016/01/70-percent-global-internet-traffic-goes-through-northern-virginia/124976/)<sup>No idea on accuracy, but if it's even halfway decent that's still roughly 35% of **all** Internet traffic, coming through the U.S., which makes this a global issue</sup>.

If we empower the users to make this decision *with the right information*, we can set a global example for a solution to a problem that *could end up being very dangerous*. Even the most basic example of competitor sites bribing ISP's (which is acceptable without net-neutrality) to put their traffic over SO/SE could be *devastating.* Consider the number of developers who visit the Stack Exchange sites daily. It's *literally* millions of hits. *That's a lot.* We can't just sit in the corner of the Internet and ignore everyone, we need to set an example for how the Internet can be protected and used as a *tool*, and we need to help the users understand it. If the U.S. removes the net-neutrality laws, the global community will suffer *and they need to understand that.* This is one of the **very few** U.S. political actions that I *absolutely* encourage international persons to participate in. *This affects us all!*

Stack Exchange is **not** an Internet Service Provider, they're at the whim of the people who service them traffic. We cannot forget that, we need to do everything in our power to *protect* our community, or it could very shortly end existence. Don't discount your users, we're an international community which means *for some of us* this is the first time we've heard of 'net-neutrality' and 'common carrier', **explain it like I'm five.**

Let's turn Stack Overflow *into* the poster-whatever for how a lack of net-neutrality in the United States is a *bad thing™!*

---

### Regarding Foreigners

Some might say that "foreigners" (non-U.S. persons) might not have a say in this, but as I said above this is one of the few times I encourage them to. The scope of this is *too large*. If the FCC pushes and has net-neutrality redacted, we're literally talking about the possibility for the U.S. ISP's (if they really wanted to) to start de-prioritizing international traffic. *That's the actual scope of this issue.* So every site that you use as a non-U.S. citizen (including Canadian, Central and Latin American, etc.) can be crippled or shut down *for you*.

If you don't think that'll happen, and you don't think our ISP's will abuse this if it comes back, you *really* haven't paid attention to the U.S. for the last few months and I feel like you have a significantly larger amount of faith in my government than I do. As a foreigner you all have the same responsibility in this manner that we do: **speak up**. If you say nothing you've effectively aligned with the idea that we don't *need* net-neutrality, and you've said it's O.K. for carriers to prioritize traffic for *any* reason, even arbitrary ones like "we don't like your nation because you **[won't give us a good deal on _____ | support person _____ whom we don't | just aren't a nation we like]**, so no more Internet for you."

So as a foreigner, the specific form Shog9 linked to won't let you fill it out and send a letter to the FCC as you need a United States address, [but the FCC has a contact page](https://www.fcc.gov/about/contact), so you can still tell them to suck-it (figuratively speaking). You can also [view official comments on this proceeding](https://www.fcc.gov/ecfs/search/filings?proceedings_name=17-108) and add your own, simply click "+ New Filing" or "+ Express". (You can even upload documents if you click "+ New Filing".) And if for some reason that link quits working, search for proceeding "17-108", that's the "Restoring Internet Freedom" proposal to eliminate net-neutrality.

---

### An Example

As for a concrete example, use an analogy.

> You're at a barbecue with your friends, two of your friends are really close to the guy handing out food. Well you, you're really good friends with the woman on the grill. So you ask her if she can give you one of the best burgers to come off the grill. She says "of course!", you're friends after all. So she tells the gentleman handing out food that "these two are for my friend." Well you and your friends already paid him off, but he gives them the good burgers and you the burnt one. Why? You all paid your fair share.

If we discontinue net-neutrality that is the grim world we can look forward to. A world where the person you get service from can arbitrarily change the quality of your service to benefit someone else.

Comment: Your answer encourages international users to participate, but you could make it clearer what actions you think they can take which would have any tangible effect on the FCC, on US politicians, on US voters, or on whoever else you mean for their actions to affect. I think that part of the answer could be clearer about what you're seeking/advocating.

Comment: @Glen_b Shog9 already indicated they have a plan for what they plan to say about how people can participate in the upcoming blog-post, this question was finally the first time they asked us for approval: "So let's hear it: why should or shouldn't we all head over to https://www.battleforthenet.com/ right now and use the handy form to send a letter to the FCC?"

Comment: This is exacty the issue I was worried you might be getting at -- how would a foreigner have any impact on the FCC? Indeed wouldn't they open themselves to exactly the sort of accusations (and perhaps investigations) of connections to/influence from other countries that the current administration is struggling with? Isn't the FCC's responsibility to Americans? Indeed such considerations would seem to require a show of *ignoring* international pressure especially in the current climate -- so bringing any would seem potentially counterproductive

Comment: @Glen_b The problem is that this *has* an international scope. If you're not in the U.S., then I encourage you to research how many websites (including Stack Exchange) that you visit that are *exclusively* located in the U.S., and you might find that a lot of the *ultra* large ones like Google, Amazon, Netflix are probably geo-located to your international location (assuming you have one), but I bet some of the somewhat smaller ones are only found either here or there. *This has a global impact, there's no doubt about that.*

Comment: I completely agree it has an international scope. At no point did I so much as begin to suggest otherwise. I was discussing the value of foreigners trying to pressure the FCC -- if their responsibility is only to Americans they will likely get more value (in political capital) from being seen to ignore the international impact than listening to it (as has happened many times in the past with US institutions -- such behavior always seems to play well with a segment of the US population). From the tenor of your response I feel like you didn't really read my comment at all.

Comment: @Glen_b I read it, I just didn't respond to exactly what you said because you're using the wrong point of view. The interesting thing about our government is that they're easy to pressure. The other thing is, *what's the worst that can happen* if you, an individual, sends them a comment that you disagree with net-neutrality? *They ignore it?* Great, so you wasted a couple minutes but *someone, somewhere* probably read it. You can *at least* flood them with messages about how you think it's a bad idea. No action is the worst action: because you're at the whim of *whomever does* take action.

Comment: @Glen_b At any rate, I've updated my answer and if you're going to continue to debate whether or not foreigners should do something I have no interest in that, the [chat room](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1114/discussion-on-question-by-shog9-net-neutrality-and-stack-overflow-stack-exchan) might have a good discussion on it though (maybe they can convince you why participating is necessary and how).

Comment: This starts out by saying how important it is to help people understand net neutrality, then there's an irrelevant wall of text, and at the end a highly contrived and strained analogy that doesn't help that much.

Comment: @Glen_b - Australian here. The biggest problem from my perspective is the precedent that the US will set should these changes be implemented. I think that "foreigners" (myself included) can help by reaching out to our own local elected people and sharing our concerns on the topic with them (rather than the FCC or the US Congresspeople). If they see this concern filtering through based on the US decision they will be less ready to adopt the same practices locally, which in turn could feed back into the US's future decisions/plans if enough of the international community don't support it.

Comment: Add more examples so they do not read about barbecue only :)

Comment: I just post the link about this to chatroom but it seems like not much people care... So sad, I'm from Taiwan, I've just finished the comment to FCC.

Comment: What does this have to do with the bill? AFFAIK the bill and you are aligned, right?

Answer (score 105):

I've only found one article about Net Neutrality that clearly explains the case in favor *and* the case against, gives actual quotations from articulate and high-profile proponents *and* opponents, and does not attempt to force the reader into agreeing with one side of the issue.  For anyone who feels you are missing some orientation to why this is even under debate...

> ...why would anyone be *against* this?  —Shog9

...I *highly* recommend [**"A Tangled Web"**](http://www.freedommag.org/issue/201506-net-freedom/a-tangled-web.html) by Price Colman.

If you're in a hurry, just read the section headed "Good, Bad and Ugly."*

---

Here is one excerpt, just to show the *reservations* that are held by some high profile *proponents* of net neutrality.  (Emphasis added.)

> Many in the tech sector are leery of government and regulatory intrusion. While they endorse the “bright line” and transparency rules, they have reservations about other aspects of the order.
>
> “I think the order did the right thing,” said Corynne McSherry of Electronic Frontier Foundation, a longtime advocate of Net Neutrality and the protection of personal privacy on the Net.
>
> For the EFF, Net Neutrality is “pretty fundamental,” McSherry said. “Think of all the ways in which we use the Internet—to organize, communicate, get jobs, get educated. We depend on the Internet for so many things. That means we need a fair Internet.”
>
> But, she says, the order gives the FCC leeway to crack down on ISPs’ practices that violate the spirit of the order, but aren’t specifically addressed in the order. That worries her.
>
> “**It seems like [the FCC] has given itself a bigger window for overregulation.** The signal to us is that we have to pressure the FCC to do the right thing.”

---

**Personally, I am in favor of Net Neutrality,** but I regard the FCC itself as a necessary evil that must be kept closely in check.  I do *not* trust government appointees to "do the right thing" and I find it odd when people loudly arguing that corporate executives are "evil" and are "only profit-driven," place implicit trust in government appointees to rein in such evil tendencies.  "Who will watch the watchers?"

I am also informed enough to know that **there are many aspects of FCC regulation that I *don't* understand,** and I am leery of oversimplification, especially by those who *themselves* fail to see other points of view.

A call to action **without a commensurate call to *get informed*,** I would regard as a disservice.

That said...if you want to make a blog post such as you describe, I think that sounds like a wonderful idea.  Just, please:

1. Avoid the embarrassing ad hominem attacks on those who disagree that imbue so many of the answers on this very page.  This is a very multi-faceted issue.
2. Avoid inflammatory language (which should go without saying).
3. Avoid oversimplifying the issue.
4. Please make some effort to really consider and understand opposing views, and be sure you are not presenting "straw man" arguments in the guise of "presenting both sides."  The evil "fast lane" scenarios are not seriously advanced *by anyone* (and certainly no one high profile) as a desirable future.

> Well, I'm not gonna lie - I think revoking the current rules is a bad idea, and I'm gonna say that. I'm *not* gonna say you suck if you're against 'em, but I *am* gonna ask folks to come here and elaborate on their reasoning.  —Shog9

Although I *am* in favor of Net Neutrality, I'm in favor with certain reservations.  I have hereby elaborated upon my reasoning.  :)

---

<sub>*If you're writing a lengthy blog post on the subject, though, you don't qualify as "in a hurry."  ;)</sub>

Comment: Quoting for great justice: "A call to action without a commensurate call to get informed, I would regard as a disservice." - this is something that never ceases to annoy me about many, *many* articles I've seen on the topic. In particular, if you're writing a story about a rule or proposal and *don't link to the canonical source* you're doing a massive disservice to readers who wish to become more informed; they're left to either take you on your word or (as I suspect is often the case) discount everything you've said and leave in disgust.

Comment: @Shog9, I've never encountered the phrase "quoting for great justice" before and a google search turns up nothing much enlightening.  Could you please define it?  :)

Comment: @Wildcard: Drop the first word. http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=for%20great%20justice

Comment: I appreciate your answer too, @Wildcard.  Disagreeing with people like grown-ups just shouldn't be all that hard.

Comment: @BenCollins thank you.  I can't work out what the "too" in your comment is in reference to, though....

Comment: Hmm....I...dunno either :-)

Comment: Freedom Magazine is *not* a reliable source.  It is (as explicitly stated on the website) a publication of the Church of Scientology, with no neutrality of its own, and the CoS is an organization with its own vested interests in promoting regulation and censorship of the Net.

Comment: @user362183 I was wondering how long before someone showed up with an ax to grind against Scientology.  You make an odd choice of attack on a group that literally pioneered use of the FOIA to shed light on corrupt government practices and promote greater transparency.  As you say, the affiliation is explicitly stated—better already than most "news" sites—and if you actually read the magazine, you would see that they are emphatically *against* censorship, but instead are strong proponents of *responsible* reporting (i.e., old school journalism, where "facts" are *verified* and bigotry avoided).

Comment: @Wildcard You mean to argue that the organization that committed the largest infiltration of the US government in a [criminal conspiracy to censor information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Snow_White) on the organization that they felt showed it in an unfavorable light is in fact an organization that might actually be interested in supporting censorship?  No, it's not an odd choice to bring it up at all.

Comment: @Servy, the illegal activities of certain members of the Guardian's Office (disbanded in 1983) were a distortion of [the actual program](https://www.standleague.org/facts-vs-fiction/whitepapers/the-snow-white-program-and-the-church-of-scientology-the-true-story.html); even Wikipedia, for all its overwhelming bias against Scientology, admits that the original program called for *legal* action and defense only.  This doesn't negate [decades of work since then by *actual* Scientologists](https://tinyurl.com/y9row7o4) in advocating freedom of information.  Nor is it relevant to the article linked.

Comment: Bottom line: You can say what you like about Scientology or Freedom Magazine, but their journalistic standards are excellent.  I stand by my original statement: The article clearly explains [the case in favor and the case against Net Neutrality](http://www.freedommag.org/issue/201506-net-freedom/a-tangled-web.html), gives actual quotations from articulate and high-profile proponents and opponents, and does not attempt to force the reader into agreeing with one side of the issue.

Comment: @Wildcard The CoS has a track record of suing ISPs to take down specific information, suing ISPs to unmask anonymous internet users, harassing journalists, and criticizing web anonymity.   I'm not sure how they come across as unbiased in this.

Comment: @Wildard Freedom Magazine does *not* maintain high standards of journalistic integrity, and has been roundly criticized for its lack of journalistic standards, e.g. https://www.uni-marburg.de/fb03/ivk/mjr/pdfs/2001/articles/schoen2001.pdf?searchterm=scientology

Comment: The argument that I keep seeing against NN is that it gives the FCC "potential for overreach" or, as the article you quoted says, "a bigger window for overregulation". Why aren't the people who are concerned about this also concerned that without NN the ISPs have a much larger potential for overregulation and censorship with far fewer checks or ramifications? Removing neutrality from any major communications system would open the Pandora's box of first amendment violations.

Comment: @Brian, did you read the article?  That question is addressed.  It's not a one-sided article; that's the whole point of why I cited it in the first place.

Comment: @Wildcard I did read the article, and that's what lead to my question. Could you please clarify which part of the article answers it?

Comment: @Brian, the part I directly quoted is relevant to that question.  Also (especially) the quotes from David Farber in the same section of the article.  To comment upon your question directly, the key is that the FCC has adequate tools for prevention of the dire scenario you portray *without* reclassifying the internet under Title II.  As David Farber mentions, the FCC Chairman at the time **said** they will forbear from the types of draconian control that Title II classification allows...but future FCC chairs (including the current one!) are not bound by that in any way.

Comment: The more I read up on it, the more I think the Title II classification is a *bad thing.*  It's certainly orthogonal from Net Neutrality itself.  [Tech Policy Corner](https://techpolicycorner.org/net-neutrality-v-title-ii-explained-3ad8d576a50a) has an admittedly partisan depiction of the distinction, supporting that conclusion.

Answer (score 100):

As you note (and as is clear from some of the comments and answers), there needs to be an educational component to this effort -- many people don't understand net neutrality in the abstract or the practical consequences of losing it.  People have questions.

SE is a place for questions.

Perhaps we should use our own sites to ask and answer questions about this (questions that people actually have, I mean), and collect links to the ones with good answers in that blog post or some other central place.

There's no *one* site where these questions might arise.  Depending on the question, people might be asking on Law, Information Security, Tor, Webmasters, Politics, Travel, User Experience, Skeptics, or others.  Most of us won't see most of that on our own.

Comment: That's a great example of how to use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: We could make a tag on this site

Comment: @NoahCristino Looks like we already have a 'net-neutrality' tag

Comment: @freginold Then why not use that?

Comment: @NoahCristino We should; help to keep everything linked.

Answer (score 75):

As you work on the post, I think it would be useful to be very careful about how you frame the various points of fact.  For example, the regulation of "common carriers" goes quite far beyond "[not] discriminat[ing] between customers", and the biggest objections to the FCC proposal from free-enterprise advocates as well as from the providers themselves center largely on aspects of that regulatory framework that you don't mention at all (here).  Not a big deal in this post, of course - you're soliciting feedback.  But in an explanatory post, which essentially would be a position paper, if you do the same thing you'd be failing to address the primary objections which would make the whole exercise kind of pointless in my view.

Also, it's worth noting that the FCC rules under discussion have a complicated history, and effectively have only ever been proposals. The most controversial idea is the one that suggests the FCC should re-classify ISPs as "title II carriers" - and it's only ever been an idea.  Like you say: procedural and boring (although if there was a crowd with an interest in arcana and detail, this is probably it).  But I suggest that if you're going to delve into that part of it, handle the facts carefully.  One big takeaway from an accurate understanding of all this is kind of important: "Net Neutrality", as people currently understand it, has only very recently been a thing in the US.  It has historically not been effectively regulated either by statute or regulatory rule - which means that all this time the internet has been working pretty well without it.  That's not necessarily dispositive proof that no action is needed, or that Stack Overflow's position isn't valid, but it also helps us understand that this is not a scenario wherein we return to the Bad Old Days if the "Net Neutrality" position doesn't prevail, or that we will achieve Internet Nirvana if it does.  This is not doomsday one way or the other.

For a detailed perspective into a lot of this nuance, I recommend Episode 72 of the "Political Economy", here: https://ricochet.com/podcast/net-neutrality/.  Brent Skorup does a pretty decent job of laying out the broad view of what proponents of net neutrality are trying to achieve by relying on the Title II classification of ISPs and FCC power to arbitrate violations of it.

`<opinion>`

### Cards on the table

So, I'll put more of my cards on the table, since the direct questions were "why should or shouldn't we.." and "why would anyone be against this?"  I'm opposed to the Title II classification, and I don't think Stack Overflow has a strong case to be for it from a business perspective.  Political perspectives of people in the company are what they are, and I don't view them as particularly relevant here because I'll not be changing any strongly-held opinions in this one post - but maybe I can take a shot at answering the questions at hand from my own perspective.

Note: for context, this is all very US-centric.

I think any scenario where the government doesn't need to be involved is the better scenario. So in a pragmatic approach to this issue, it kind of boils down to demonstrating need (and the contrapositive, demonstrating that regardless of need, there is a downside to government involvement).

### The need (or lack)

The primary common argument *for* net neutrality, as I understand it, is that ISPs might block or throttle lawful traffic, or charge for prioritization ("fast lanes").

I don't know of many cases of this actually happening.  There is the one famous instance between Netflix and Comcast (which they resolved without the help of regulators).

More to the point, ISPs don't have much incentive to do this.  There *are* indeed areas were there is only one option for broadband access - but I think those are getting fewer and fewer - and this trend is only going to accelerate as more wireless ISPs come online: both fixed wireless and 5g/Wimax/Mmmmmagic.  Available options are only going to become more plentiful.

Despite the common refrain of a lack of competition, that complaint is mostly from a consumer point of view.  From, say, Comcast's point of view, there is plenty of competition.  In any major market, they are competing with other major providers like Verizon and AT&T, who also offer multiple modes of access: DSL, Fiber, Wireless.  There are *many* consumers who do actually have a choice.  In my view, it's enough to prevent egregiously anti-competitive behavior from providers.

And indeed - anti-competitive behavior seems to be the primary concern.  But this is already regulated. The Department of Justice and Federal Trade Commission already enforce these laws and have always been able to prosecute in the courts bad actors who violate antitrust laws as they occur.

> Antitrust law and the standards applied by courts have been developed and refined over decades.  In comparison, new regulations contain untested definitions and standards, which would be interpreted and enforced by constantly rotating commission.
>
> Antitrust law governs the conduct of all participants in the internet marketplace uniformly, and prosecutes conduct once it occurs on a case-by-case basis and determines whether parties actually engaged in improper conduct.  Regulation would only apply to a select group of entities, and is a one-size-fits-all approach that creates a burden on everyone regardless of whether they are acting unlawfully.  And consumers often ultimately bear the cost of this regulation." (some paraphrasing)
>
> http://thehill.com/special-reports/net-neutrality-september-16-2014/217862-use-antitrust-laws-not-regulations-to

To address Stack Overflow's interest directly: I think it is exceedingly unlikely that an ISP would apply the aforementioned bad practices.  There is simply no reason, and no business model for them to do so.

Update: It seems like a good idea to address the claim of a lack of competition as a reason for Title II classifications - that somehow, the state of things in Internetlandia resembles the telephone networks and AT&T from the 1930s.  I just don't see any evidence to suggest this is actually true.  According to [broadbandmap.gov](https://www.broadbandmap.gov/summarize/nationwide):

[image: nationalized distribution of fixed-line providers]

[image: nationalized distribution of wireless providers]

It looks to me like there are actually very few people who have fewer than 4 providers available to them.  I don't see why that's not enough to prevent the kind of bad behavior envisioned by proponents, in the main.  It also bears repeating: improvements in wireless technology are changing this a *lot*, and for the better (in terms of access).

### The downside

There are a few, but let's start with forbearance.  Broadly speaking, government entities that have had the power to do something eventually do it.  So the FCC promised to forbear from applying the most stringent parts of Title II (say, like rate fixing - which would be a disaster) - but I just don't trust that promise at all.  Maybe Mr. Wheeler (the chairman in 2015) meant it earnestly, and it appears that he and the commission abided by that promise.  Good for them.  What happens when an entirely different commission decides, arbitrarily, that they will no longer forbear - something I view as all but inevitable if the rules stay in place?  Do we want them to have arbitrary and capricious power over such an important part of the national infrastructure, and a service that over half the country has come to rely on?  I don't.

Skorup makes a extends this argument further with a helpful example in [National Affairs](https://www.nationalaffairs.com/publications/detail/who-needs-the-fcc):

> The FCC's tendencies, in the words of economist and judge Richard Posner, result in "unprincipled compromises of Rube Goldberg complexity among contending interest groups viewed merely as clamoring suppliants who have somehow to be conciliated." The discretion it reserves for itself undermines its work because its approval processes are frequently sidetracked by powerful interests in and outside of government. For example, one wireless company, LightSquared, spent billions of dollars converting satellite spectrum for use as mobile broadband, in the hopes of competing with AT&T and Verizon. The FCC tentatively encouraged that costly process for a few years before rescinding crucial permissions under intense political pressure. The bureaucratic shift immediately bankrupted LightSquared and deprived Americans of the benefits of another major wireless operator.

If the neutrality rules stick, I think it's likely that ISPs will lobby to have content providers regulated as well because in some respects they compete (say, Xfinity vs Netflix - or even Google vs Bing - or how about CDNs, which are effectively fast lanes) and they're going to work to negate competitive advantages that are held over them.  The coiner of the term Net Neutrality also "argued in congressional testimony that the FCC should be charged with "protecting an open society," "safeguarding the political process," and prohibiting media companies from silencing political viewpoints."  Another way to put that is: tell media companies (which would include Stack Overflow) what they are and are not allowed to publish on their distribution networks.  I'm not for that.

Even "Lawrence Lessig penned a piece in 2008 for Newsweek titled, "It's Time to Demolish the FCC," in which he bemoaned the problems of industry capture and the FCC's increased politicization. Echoing many conservative complaints, he concluded that, when it comes to technology, there's an urgent need to "remove the government from the mix as much as possible."

Also, David Clark [amusingly pointed out](http://www.netcompetition.org/net-neutrality/happy-little-bunny-rabbit-dreams-is-what-internets-architect-calls-net-neutrality-assumptions) that a legal regime of net neutrality is seriously anti-investment, which is a common argument against it.

### The way I prefer to think of it

My view is that the prior regime of antitrust enforcement coupled with letting free markets figure things out is the superior approach.

Part of why I think the blanket regulatory approach is a bad idea is that the nuts and bolts of how all this boils out is completely opaque to most people.  How many people understand how peering works?  What about CDNs?  Datacenters?  How do these things apply where all this stuff comes together?  Was the Netflix v Comcast thing *really* an instance of bad behavior vis-à-vis network neutrality, or was it just an instance of a major provider trying its best to make its network work better, and a participant got its finger caught in the door (so to speak)?  Did anyone notice that there weren't any antitrust enforcement actions against Comcast in that case - to me signifying that the way it ultimately worked out was far better than every internet participant having to shoulder the burden of blanket regulation.

To add to this point, definitions are very tricky too.  Why isn't a CDN the same thing as "paid prioritization"?  When Bittorrent was a really "impolite" program and absolutely crushing consumer networks, was it an anti-competitive action for ISPs to throttle it?  Even the basic statement of principle on battleforthenet.com doesn't stand up to very much scrutiny: "Internet providers should not control what we see and do online".  Taken literally, that would mean they couldn't manage their networks effectively.

Kayne and Layton very interestingly note in [US News](https://www.usnews.com/opinion/economic-intelligence/articles/2017-04-10/the-us-should-learn-from-denmarks-decentralized-telecommunications-model) that Denmark, consistently a leader in connectivity and telecom services to consumers, doesn't have a centralized regulator like the FCC.  They dismantled their centralized telecom regulator in 2011.  "That Denmark's broadband market has flourished without centralized government regulation should be instructive to the United States. Clearly, top-down rules are not the only way to produce consumer friendly outcomes. "

To me this is a solution in search of a problem.  Real problems include:

- lack of deeper broadband penetration
- lack of consumer choice

There are definitely others, but these are the ones that come to mind.  The net neutrality rules don't help these problems, and I think I could make a case that they make them worse (regulatory capture, yadda yadda).  Instead, we could try to figure out how to let municipalities build last-mile broadband infrastructure.  We can get the FCC to auction off more of the wireless spectrum that the government is currently hogging.  There are other better approaches to real problems that I think would have a more positive effect.  They just take more work.

Anyway, there it is.  I could go on and on and on, but this is already a wall o' text that only Shog is going to read anyway :-)  Just to be clear, I am not wound up and anxious about this, and I don't think histrionics are appropriate responses to policy questions.  If the FCC keeps the rules, we will muddle through.  I think things will be a little worse if they do, but it's not the end of everything good and right.  If they don't keep the rules, I think it's a step in the right direction, but that's about all.

P.S. - my apologies to upvoters who may now want to retract their votes (which is totally fine)

`</opinion>`

One last thing: good luck.  Politics is hard.

Comment: While I agree with the desire expressed here to be careful in how we frame this, I gotta emphatically dispute the assertion that ISPs are currently *not* classified as Title II carriers. As with the current proposed rule-making, the change to classification was proposed in 2014. It was then *voted on* in February of 2015, passed, and [issued on March 12, 2015](https://www.fcc.gov/document/fcc-releases-open-internet-order) (PDF linked to there contains the two dissenting opinions).

Comment: In short, the classification and relevant rules (which, I should in fairness note, do not include *all* rules commonly applied to common carriers), have been active for over two years, sufficient time for at least the initial outcome to be observed and discussed.

Comment: Ah, so you're right - I didn't realize the 2015 rules had gone into effect - I thought they still had a future date.  

That being said, I don't think that really changes much of my point: I hope the post is better than "RA RA Net Neutrality" and "You suck if you're against this", or as others have already done in other answers, "you can't possibly be rational if you're against this", which as I say, would make this whole exercise pointless.

Comment: Well, I'm not gonna lie - I think revoking the current rules is a bad idea, and I'm gonna say that. I'm *not* gonna say you suck if you're against 'em, but I *am* gonna ask folks to come here and elaborate on their reasoning.

Comment: I _really_ appreciate this reasoned and measured response. As a software engineer who wears many hats at a small (~3k customers) ISP, I support the idea of what I think net neutrality is, but have thus far been able to technically define it. From what I have seen in our telephone subsidiary, the tons of regulations and red tape around telephone service should *not* be applied to the world of technology. (Our telephone subsidiary has merged with the rest of the company but has not renamed because it would be prohibitively expensive (thousands of dollars?) to file the paperwork.)

Comment: Alrighty then @Shog9, I've elaborated ;-)

Comment: ISPs sure seem to think there is incentive to do this. In fact, Verizon has even admitted in court they would do it if they could. Why else would they keep spending so much money trying to push the limits? https://www.freepress.net/blog/2017/04/25/net-neutrality-violations-brief-history

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara that's a fair point (about Verizon admitting it in court), but that same article kind of provides an effective counterpoint: AT&Ts threats about FaceTime didn't materialize, and their action against Skype was short lived.  Besides, saying that they'd be "exploring these types of arrangements", even taken at face value, is not the same thing as making a case for a business model, and is hardly a smoking gun.

Comment: I don't know if you know about slow boiling a frog. There's no tell where they ball will stop rolling (if it ever stops) and considering that infrastructure operators have natural monopolies (due the costs of rolling out the infrastructure, which is kind of the point why it's preferred that the state incurs on those costs) it means that you are at mercy of your operator since they have a massive leverage over whatever terms of the contract between clients and they are.

Comment: “There is the one famous instance between Netflix and Comcast (which they resolved without the help of regulators).” So you would characterize an ISP sabotaging a customer and shaking them down for money, and the customer finally caving to their extortion, a *satisfactory and healthy resolution?* Kind of a case-in-point against your position, if that’s the kind of thing that’s being touted as the success of the unregulated position.

Comment: @KRyan I don't agree with your characterization.  It seems to me more the case Netflix content was having a huge impact on Comcasts networks, and in order to better serve their customers, they needed to come up with some peering arrangement that they could both live with, which they did, Netflix's public protestations notwithstanding.

I see this very much in the same vein as a similar dispute between Comcast and Bit Torrent which was similarly resolved.  Neither of these instances seem to me like an obvious gap that net neutrality would have helped.

Comment: @KRyan you know you're talking about two companies worth billions duking it out, right?  Do we really need "net neutrality" to protect the interests of these huge corporations?

Comment: @Won't I’m a Comcast customer and a Netflix customer. A portion of what I am paying Comcast money for is to deliver Netflix content. Comcast’s sabotage not only affected Netflix—it affected me, too. In fact, during that time, I measured dramatically lower bandwidths than advertised when connecting to Netflix servers. In short, Comcast was not providing me with the service I was paying for at that time. And Comcast suffered absolutely nothing for doing so, and ISPs in generally routinely defraud their customers without any problems. Yes, I think we need net neutrality protect us from ISPs.

Comment: @KRyan "Defrauding" is a very specific legal claim for which I suspect you have very little evidence.  You probably know that consumer ISP agreements don't guarantee _anything_, which is how they are affordable to consumers. And again - you characterize what Comcast did as "sabotage", which I think is inaccurate.

Comment: Ben Collins I don't agree with your characterization, I think @KRyan 's is more accurate. You're saying "It seems to me more the case Netflix content was having a huge impact on Comcasts networks". I would definitely rewrite that as "Comcast customers, having paid Comcast with the expectation that they would be able to access any part of the internet they want at the speeds Comcast advertised, were connecting to Netflix in large numbers."

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 I don't disagree with your rewording - but I don't see why that would then imply that Comcast wouldn't have the right to approach Netflix for a peering agreement to make that access better (and less disruptive to access to _other_ content).

Comment: @BenCollins How is it inaccurate to characterize dramatically slowing down a single company's traffic, with the sole purpose of intentionally disrupting the company and its consumers' ability to use the service that they're paying Comcast for, sabotage?  How would *you* characterize it?

Comment: Its amazing both Comcast and Netflix are still around and their customers are still getting internet and movies for reasonable prices at reasonable speeds without the intervention of the federal government.  How the hell did that happen without NN?

Comment: @Won't Comcast is still around because they have a monopoly, and their customers have no choice but to use them if they want internet access.  Netflix is still around because they paid the extortion money, and then eventually the fact that they were extorted ended up coming out and as a result of the subsequent publicity *improved regulations were passed to make the net more neutral* to prevent such behavior from happening in the future, removing Netflix's need to continue paying the extortion money, thanks to the intervention of the federal government.

Comment: @Won't We have net neutrality. The incident in question in fact prompted it, in large part, because we don’t want Comcast doing it again. If Comcast continued to extort Netflix, I have little doubt that prices would have gone up. Moreover, Netflix was, as mentioned, a huge company able to afford bribing Comcast. A hypothetical up-and-coming Netflix competitor would not. And *that* is the biggest problem. Net neutrality prevents ISPs from picking winners and losers, and that allows for greater competition. ISPs, being monopolies themselves and seeking yet more control and profit, don’t like it.

Comment: @Servy I think that's broadly not true (that Comcast's customers are all monopolized).  But back to your earlier point - let's ask the same question about a comparable situation: was it "sabotage" and "extortion" for Comcast to throttle Bit Torrent traffic?  I mean, that's what their customers wanted to do, right?

I fail to see why the Bit Torrent scenario is perceived as merely network management by most people (seems to me), but with Netflix it's "extortion" and "sabotage".

Comment: @Servy maybe the issue with cable company monopolies should be forefront?  I know you're being a bit hyperbolic, but extortion is actually a crime, and if what happened between those two companies was truly extortion, then Netflix would be running Comcast now.  The intervention of the federal government also prevented companies from combining forces to offer customers special deals--say, for example, AT&T partnering with Netflix to give their customers free access in order to lure them from Comcast.  There are costs to regulations that need to be considered as well.

Comment: @KRyan we're back to a solution looking for a problem.  A solution that turns internet providers into Ma Bell, a stifling regulatory purgatory that suppresses innovation.  If you don't get the reference, go look into it.  I'd prefer that not happen to the internet as well.

Comment: @BenCollins I don’t know who you think felt BitTorrent throttling was acceptable, but I don’t and I don’t perceive net neutrality advocates as being so. It’s just a more niche, and less “pretty” case to hold up because of the associations of BitTorrent with illegal activity. Much easier to focus on Netflix, which is popular, well-known, and not tarnished by illegal usage.

Comment: @Won't The options are monopoly (or monopolistic oligarchy, which amounts to the same thing), or regulation. Those are the options. None others are presenting themselves. ISP competition is a myth.

Comment: @BenCollins It's my understanding that Comcast wasn't throttling/blocking BitTorrent until they paid more money, they were doing it because they simply didn't support that traffic.  (Unless I'm unaware of an offer to remove that for money.)  That would make it sabotage, but not extortion.

Comment: @Servy I just don't see it that way (sabotage or extortion) at all.  I think Comcast and other ISPs have a legitimate right (and even duty) to manage their networks in the way they think best for their customers (and still try to make a profit), which I think they do, generally speaking.  Maybe sometimes they get it wrong, but this is the way the world works.  Customers purchase services that are managed by the providers.  Sometimes some are better than others, and that's not a reason for any government intervention, let alone the federal government.

Comment: @Won't Cable company monopolies *is* a part of the forefront here.  Sadly, the industry itself is a natural monopoly.  It's not a service that lends itself well to competition, as it requires a large and expensive infrastructure, which would need to be duplicated for real competition to exist, and expensive and inefficient solution.  The common solution to natural monopolies in various domains (power, water, etc.) is government intervention.  As far as extortion, there's a general definition of the term and a legal definition, that differ in a matter of degree.

Comment: It's the network you - as a customer - are paying them for, @Ben. Managing congestion is a critical function of running that network; hamfisted restrictions meant to *avoid* having to manage congestion isn't. This calls back to the old days of AT&T, where you couldn't attach a 3rd-party phone or answering machine because (they claimed) it could harm the network in some way; in practice it amounted to a thin excuse to maintain a monopoly on expensive equipment rentals.

Comment: @Shog9 ok, so if they aren't doing a good job of managing congestion, then customers will go elsewhere, and the provider will either adapt or die.  In this case they adapted.  Now Comcast customers get Netflix via Xfinity as well as better network access to it.  It seems like the outcome everyone would have wanted is the one we got.  In any case, I don't see how this makes it necessary (or even fair) for the federal government to resolve private economic negotiations in favor of only one side.

Comment: @BenCollins If they do a bad job of managing congestion then customers won't do a damn thing, because they have nowhere else to go, and their only choice is to just deal with it.  It may be the outcome that *you* want for a major company to be forced to pay a bribe in order for a company to provide the services they had already been paid for, but that's not an outcome that many other people consider desirable, hence the regulation to prevent such behavior.  You may not  see how it's necessary or fair for a government to put policies in place for the benefit of society, but many others do.

Comment: @Servy this is the argument I hear repeated a lot, but I just don't think it's true.    According to https://www.broadbandmap.gov/summarize/nationwide, virtually everyone in the US has access to at least 4 providers (counting wireless, as we should), and a majority have access to more than that.  You can drill down quite a lot in this data, and it's kind of interesting, but in only a few minutes of digging I don't see any obvious evidence to suggest the commonly claimed provider monopoly is common.

Comment: @BenCollins Well, if the FCC gets their way, I'll sit back and hope you're right about no abuse happening... Because I'm in one of those locations, a small town, where I have no other choice on who to use. Sure, I could use wireless, but 1) It's considerably more expensive for as much as I use the internet and 2) Even with the best provider in my area, the service is still patchy at best in the areas where I _need_ it. (I am still not sure where I stand on this whole thing. I have not read enough to tell me one way or another where things really sit.)

Comment: @Kendra just to be clear, I'm not claiming that abuse will never happen.  What I'm claiming is two things: a) I don't perceive a business incentive for ISPs to behave badly on purpose, and b) we already have enforcement mechanisms for handling instances where abuse does happen (antitrust law).  As it happens, I empathize with you because I also live in a place were provider options (and speeds) are more limited than in other places.

Comment: @BenCollins I worded that poorly, I wouldn't think you naive enough to claim abuse would never happen. Apologies there. (And thanks for the useful information well outlined in your post! It's helpful for those of us unsure where we stand.)

Comment: @KRyan Let's be honest here. You're talking about movies and shows you watch for your personal entertainment. Government laws are enforced by the threat of violence (forcibly throwing someone in jail or worse if they won't comply with the law). You're talking about threatening someone with violence because they didn't have enough bandwidth to supply your (and thousands of other people's) personal entertainment. That strikes me as incredibly immoral. Also, the fact that you measured the bandwidth suggests to me that you still found Netflix usable enough, in spite of the slow down.

Comment: @jpmc I rely on my internet connection—and a certain amount of bandwidth—for my livelihood. Comcast hasn't targeted me, my employer, or our clients yet—and I have the incentive of my ability to provide for my family as incentive to insure they never will. Because I know I will never be able to protect myself—even as it is, the service I receive is often vastly inferior to what I paid for, and Comcast has forced me to burn vacation days because they did not deliver what I paid them to and I could not do my job. So no, it's not just personal entertainment. And I find your strawman immoral.

Comment: @KRyan I don't see any evidence that Comcast or any other ISP "targets" anyone who isn't responsible for a massive amount of traffic. So unless you're sending across traffic comparable to Netflix, you have no reason to be concerned. On the contrary, Netflix hogging their networks probably makes getting the bandwidth you need for your job *harder*. That you don't get the bandwidth you desire (and while yes, you pay for it, as I recall, Comcast's terms pretty clearly state a maximum, not any minimum) is a separate problem and would only be exacerbated by the regulation you're supporting.

Comment: "I don't know of many cases of this actually happening. There is the one famous instance between Netflix and Comcast (which they resolved without the help of regulators)." You seem to imply that this was resolved with no ramification to consumers. What if it was resolved by Netfix raising their rates? That's a way to resolve things w/o regulators. What if instead of Netfix, I'm the one who has the conflict? Unlike Netflix, I don't have a user base that would stay loyal to me should I raise rates. So, I go out of business. In the same breath as you bring up a compelling argument, you dismiss it

Comment: @iheanyi How could you have the level of traffic of Netflix without the user base of Netflix? That doesn't make a whole lot of sense...

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't have the level of traffic of Netflix. I think you're missing the point. Let's say the cost is proportional to user base. So the price increase scales with users. For Netflix, their margin could be large enough that they'd still do well even with that incremental increase, without a need to pass those costs on to customers. For a small startup with very little margin, that could be enough to go out of business or force you to pass along that incremental cost which may cost you customers then go out of business.

Comment: @jpmc26 So, there are a few problems, here's a couple: 1. You need more capital to launch a new business, because you must plan for higher interconnect costs. 2. There is a lot more risk, because interconnect costs are less controlled and you can't predict your cost simply by looking at similar businesses. When the cost/risk to enter the market increases, it necessarily reduces the number of players who enter. That's one problem that net neutrality advocates want to minimize.

Comment: @jpmc26 That is a bizarre level of trust you have there in Comcast. Myself, more Comcast employees have lied to me than *haven’t*, so I do not share your trust. I do not trust Comcast to use such an ability wisely. I don’t trust them when they say they used it against Netflix wisely. I don’t trust them when they try to frame it as a function of *ability*, since after all as soon as Netflix threw more money at them all of a sudden the problem disappeared.

Comment: @KRyan I don't trust anyone that much, but if you think people in government are *more* honest than at Comcast, you're kidding yourself. If Comcast doesn't provide *some* level of service, anyone who does will beat the crap out of them. Comcast has a vested interest in keeping their systems going. Some government pencil pusher won't have *any* incentive to care about the impact of their decisions. I find it much more bizarre that you think government officials are that altruistic. It's also possible that Comcast was taking a long view and sunk that money into infrastructure, too.

Comment: @iheanyi But that is the point. ISPs aren't just randomly shutting down whoever. The only case we have of ISPs doing this kind of limiting is in a single case where the amount of traffic was absolutely massive, enough that it plausibly affected their ability to maintain their systems. ISPs have a vested interest in serving as much traffic as they can to attract as many customers as possible, so unless the traffic is big enough to cause a problem or big enough they think they're losing money to a competitor, they don't have any reason to block it. So why would they block you if you're not big?

Comment: @jpmc26, you're making a lot of assumptions. I literally *have* a job that periodically involves using BitTorrent to transfer fairly large datasets, something my ISP was actively throttling just a few years ago. I don't know what KRyan does, but the notion that someone could be affected by these sorts of naive attempts to avoid real network management doesn't strike me as either implausible or even unlikely. If you've never had to deal with this sort of thing, great!

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to dig up data on this, Ben - vastly improves your post. I gotta quibble a bit with the charts you posted: much as I'm looking forward to the day when it isn't true, I cannot seriously consider wireless a competitor to wireline at this time: most providers have either extremely limited geographic coverage, extremely limited data caps, or both. Focusing solely on wireline, over half the country has <=2 providers; that's not a healthy competitive market.

Comment: @Shog9 "naive attempts to avoid real network management" I agree that throttling is probably a less than ideal solution. But for an ISP, what is the alternative and what's the *cost* of that alternative? I do want people to strive to do their best. On the other hand, doing your best costs time and money, and sometimes those resources are best put elsewhere. SO makes those kinds of trade offs constantly; there's a lot I could criticize as being well less than ideal. Regulations don't make those just disappear; it just shuffles them around.

Comment: @Shog9 BitTorrent and Netflix aren't throttled anymore, so you're left asking, "Where's the insurmountable problem that warrants the threat of violence?" I also repeat what I said before: some government pencil pusher is never going to suffer the consequences of their bad decisions.

Comment: @jmpc26 It's not about trust. It's about accountability. Net neutrality regulations ensure that ISPs are held accountable, because ISPs certainly won't hold themselves accountable.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Who holds the FCC accountable, then? Congress? The president? Voters? Don't make me laugh.

Comment: Throttling is all but *necessary*, @jpmc26, particularly when you're oversubscribed (which most ISPs will be for practical reasons, particularly consumer ISPs). Throttling based on content type as a QoS technique to resolve congestion is also practical. Throttling based on content type when there's no congestion because you can't be bothered to manage congestion is just lazy.

Comment: @jpmc26 Ultimately, voters should hold the whole system accountable. Remove the regulations, are they are accountable to nobody.

Comment: @Shog9 the chart shows only 12% have only 1 (or none) available option.   Also, I don't see why wireless providers shouldn't be considered a part of the competitive mix.  They are valid alternatives for lots of people.

Comment: What's your argument there, @jpmc26? "The wolf isn't currently at our door, so let's unbar it and go to bed with bloody steaks hung round our necks?"

Comment: @jpmc26 ISPs aren't randomly jacking up fees? Please! ISPs are well known jack up monthly costs randomly with "cost recovery fees" and other such BS. The cost to rent the same exact cable modem fluctuates year after year. Some are already looking to charge users extra to opt out of targeted advertising based on deep packet analysis. I see no reason to extend them the benefit of the doubt where it comes to net neutrality.

Comment: @iheanyi That isn't random. It's simple supply and demand. Demand for internet services has increased drastically as more types of content have become feasible. I don't especially like price increases, but I'm willing to wait while the market sorts it out rather than screw everything up for a short term fix that will probably make things worse in the long run. As prices increase, so do the rewards for getting in the market, which will attract more competitors (supply). It'll balance out eventually.

Comment: @jpmc26 If it's simple supply and demand, the monthly rental cost of a cable modem should be decreasing not increasing. If it's simple supply and demand, it shouldn't cost me extra when I supply my own cable modem and wifi AP versus renting the one provided by the ISP.

Comment: As I said, wireless internet *as it exists on the market today* has vastly inferior capability to even fairly limited wireline services, @Ben - 10x less data or more. With the demise of Clearwire, I'm not even aware of anyone in the wireless space actively trying to compete with wireline providers nation-wide (happy to be corrected on that); what's left is a spotty patchwork of local fixed-point ISPs, with major carriers directing their focus on emergency / semi-mobile hotspot usage.

Comment: @jpmc26 As price increases, the rewards increase (not always, but I'll concede to make my point) - but so does the cost of entry. Which means the only competitors you can attract are those with significant funding. The history of innovation so far has shown things are best (as in actual competition) when the cost of entry is low.

Comment: @iheanyi Right, and regulation isn't going to decrease the cost of entry, now is it? It'll make it higher, maybe to the point New York's taxi services at at, where the cost of even getting "approved" will be prohibitive, let alone the cost of any infrastructure you need. I'm not suggesting that ISPs are saints, but the government isn't some kind of altruistic savior, either. They have their own agendas and goals, which run contrary to the consumer's at least as often as the actual businesses. And the government is *far* less likely to suffer consequences of making bad decisions.

Comment: @jpmc26 You're correct, regulation won't **decrease** the cost of entry. However, it stabilizes or removes one potential source of cost inflation. Your taxi service example however is flawed - that's a perfect example of how giveaways to an industry lead to cost increases - it's the same problem with how dealerships crafted laws to favor their business - taxi medallion owners pushed for laws that helped ensure the increasing value of licenses to deliberately make it harder for competitors to enter the market and/or guarantee profits despite a lack of innovation in their core business.

Comment: @iheanyi It's not flawed. Regulation categorically costs extra to comply with. By the way, know what the ISPs are gonna do to cover those costs? Hike up rates.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, compliance costs necessarily increase with regulation. However, we expect that given the nature of ISPs (you necessarily need significant funding to enter the market as an ISP), there's significantly less competition than in other industries and more market capture. So here, regulation also has the effect of ensuring the already anti-competitive nature of ISP business doesn't also transfer that property to the users of the service they're providing. Now you're approaching understanding of the Title II classification issue.

Comment: @iheanyi I already understand; I've been saying this stuff the whole time. What's the "anti-competitive behavior" here? The ISPs haven't shown they're doing this with any kind of regularity. We have two instances: Netflix and BitTorrent. Both of those are a source of high traffic that impose a significant burden on their infrastructure. There doesn't seem to be sufficient evidence that this was some kind of anti-competitive behavior; ISPs don't even compete with BitTorrent. So how does regulating their network usage even solve any problems?

Comment: @jpmc26 *"ISPs don't even compete with BitTorrent"* Do you know who companies like Comcast and Time Warner are? They are companies that make money selling media. The kind of people who might get upset if they though people were using BitTorrent to download the stuff they sell. The kind of people who might try to indiscriminately ruin torrent traffic (and with it, my ability to legitimately download some of my favorite Linux distros), just to make a buck.

Comment: @jpmc26 but ISPs do compete. Today, it's in the form of media, tomorrow who knows. The fact is, if we allow anticompetitive behavior in one area of the internet, rationalizing it away as it only hurts Netflix, Hulu, or anyone else who'd ever innovate in that arena, but won't go any further, we leave in a legal framework that makes it hard to fix problems when it expands later. Look at the issues the DMCA is now creating for security research or consumer repair of their own devices. Look at the patent reform issues we're having now. It is shortsighted to ignore problem we can actually forecast

Comment: @iheanyi You seem to have this impression that if we could just *control* everything enough, we could somehow make it perfect or pretty close to it. But over the history of mankind, we've already seen that it *doesn't work* and that the market makes much better decisions in the long run. Most consumers don't care about repairing their own devices, so it isn't surprising if the market doesn't care. You're never going to have a system that creates *your* ideal world, so you have to ask the question, "What are the trade offs?" You're trading a ton of *other people's* money for what?

Comment: @iheanyi Also, DMCA and patents *are* government intervention, so you just made my case that government tends to make a mess of everything.

Comment: @jpmc26 ummm, I don't believe in complete control, but I do believe in regulation. Clean air, non rotten meat, child labor, all regulation. I'm not sure what point you think you're making with DMCA. All regulation is introduced by government. It's disingenuous to pretend they're all for the benefit of consumers when clearly, you've heard of lobbying.

Comment: Also, who has the deepest pockets to influence and lock down government regulations in their favour? It's one thing to have a high financial barrier to enter a market, it's another to have regulatory barriers to your potential innovation.

Comment: "It looks to me like there are actually very few people who have fewer than 4 providers available to them. " -- literally, according to _your own charts_, ***the vast majority*** of people do ***not*** have access to 4 or more wireline providers. At the current point in time, given how unreliable, expensive, and low-quality wireless internet access is at this time, the competitive state of the wireless internet market is _not_ relevant. _Only_ the state of the wireline internet market is relevant. And even according to _your own information_, that market is extremely oligopolistic.

Comment: In the UK, we can choose almost any internet company regardless of which one installed our lines - I don't know exactly how it works, but it's called "local loop unbundling", is a consequency of regulation, and (combined with other legislation such as CCR) promotes competition.  The government's forcing of ISPs to engage in spying and censorship on the other hand though.........

Comment: @MarkKCowan I actually want to pursue something like that here in the US at the local level.  The term "local loop unbundling" has a nice ring to it.

Comment: @BenCollins: I just checked — it isn't just at UK-level, it's a requirement across the entire European Union (as is net neutrality although UK mobile carriers seem to be able to cheat it with mobile tethering restrictions).

Comment: 'It looks to me like there are actually very few people who have fewer than 4 providers available to them.'  Over 75% of the US has 3 or less wireline providers.  Now, over 85% have 4 or more wireless providers.  But, do those tables tell us anything about the overlap to determine the total broadband providers available to the US?  I don't think they do.

Comment: "My view is that the prior regime of antitrust enforcement coupled with letting free markets figure things out is the superior approach." IS BRILLIANT. Net neutrality fixes a problem that doesn't exist (yet), but if it did ( and government stayed out of the way ), the market would put those who used the bad practice out of business. Fix the government involvement that allows for monopoly like companies to exist, and net neutrality will fix itself, or rather you, the consumer, will fix it.

Comment: There are two ISPs I have available to me (in a top-ten US metro area). One is century link, one is cox. Century link cannot in good faith be called high speed internet--it is DSL only where I am (I used to have it, and you can't get more than 25Mbps--but in reality it was consistently ~5Mbps). Cox just implemented a 1TB/month data cap. How is this _not_ uncompetitive?

Comment: @spacetyper: simple - there are two providers competing.  They offer products that have tradeoffs.  Consumers can choose between them.  That's called competition.  Whether or not you think those are good options are immaterial to whether or not competition exists.

Comment: @traggatmot I believe you've misread the charts.

Comment: @MarkKCowan interestingly, the US also has LLUB, but it only applies to telephone companies with monopolies in local markets (ILECs).  I don't know the ins-and-outs of it, so I don't know exactly when it would apply and when it wouldn't.

Comment: Meanwhile I'm at the complete mercy of Comcast because no one else services my address. But, I'd show up under the chart as having at least 2 options. Why? Because CenturyLink at least promises me 1.5mbps. Such competition.

Comment: @BenCollins, the National Broadband Map had a number of issues. Primarily that it's data is based from education, public safety, healthcare, or community (libraries, local government, etc) sources. These types of organizations often do not access the internet in the same manner as a consumer and as such their options are typically different from those presented to consumers. It isn't a representation of an individual/consumer access to broadband. Trying to say these charts show consumers have access to some number of ISP's is simply false.

Comment: @YLearn Of course, I'm open to criticism of the data.  But here's what the SBI says about it: "Since accurate data is critical for broadband planning, another purpose of the SBI program is to assist states in gathering data twice a year on the availability, speed, and location of broadband services, as well as the broadband services that community institutions, such as schools, libraries and hospitals, use."  That sounds to me like they are collecting data about general broadband availability, not just from community institutions.  More importantly: it's the best data we have (afaik).

Comment: @BenCollins, "The data is aggregated from the census block or road segment level data and was provided to NTIA by each state grantee." What data do these grantees collect? "Community Anchor Institutions include schools, libraries, medical and healthcare providers, public safety entities, community colleges and other institutions of higher education, and other community support organizations and entities. SBDD grantees have collected data about the broadband plans to which these organizations subscribe." And finally where did the funding come from? http://www2.ntia.doc.gov/sbdd

Comment: The data was never meant to represent the individual. Rather it is meant to represent the service available to communities through their public resources. The two are not the same.

Comment: @YLearn, I think you are incorrect.  If you'll click through to the FAQ document, you'll find this a few pages down: "The definition of a substantially complete data set has a four‐part test, with each part intended to counterbalance the others. The definition requires the provision of data for the following: a) 70 percent of broadband service providers in a state; b) to 80 percent of households in a state; c) to 90 percent of households in rural areas of the state; and d) to 95 percent of public Community Anchor Institutions."  Households are part of the criteria for complete data reports.

Comment: @YLearn also, to be complete: the funding for this data collection comes from the NTIA (an executive branch agency).

Comment: Wireline includes dialup service. The FCC definition of broadband is now 25Mbit/s down. If you filter for just access to broadband, those graphs don't look as great. Now, there's certainly arguments to be had about what level of service should "count", but having access to 4 dialup providers is quite different than having access to 4 providers capable of >25Mbit/s service.

That said, on my second read of your answer, a few weeks after my first, I'm softening more to your point of view.

Comment: @iheanyi I appreciate that you're at least willing to let stuff roll over in your mind over time ;-)   The FAQ points this out about the data: "Based on the data available, this graphic displays the number of wired broadband providers that the population of the given area can access. This includes providers of DSL, cable, copper, or fiber."  I take this to mean that DSL services capable of 25Mb or more are what's included, rather than all DSL.

Comment: I realize that if there are 2 or more providers offering the same service, that a `monopoly` does not technically exist. However, if you have only a small number of powerful providers for a great number of customers you end up with an `oligarchy`. The economic and political consequences of oligarchies are the same as with monopolies, although less severe. Break up the large oligarchic businesses into lots of small, directly competing businesses and government intervention would not be needed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining all this. One thought I can't follow: "The coiner of the term Net Neutrality also "argued in congressional testimony that the FCC should be charged with "protecting an open society," "safeguarding the political process," and prohibiting media companies from silencing political viewpoints." Another way to put that is: tell media companies (which would include Stack Overflow) what they are and are not allowed to publish on their distribution networks." How did you conclude the second sentence based on the first?

Comment: "Protecting an open society" does not sound like censorship at all. Prohibiting media companies from silencing political viewpoints _could_ be censorship, but it seems plainly anti-censorship, as in, **I don't want Verizon capable of silencing political viewpoints.** "Safeguarding the political process" is a little ambiguous but it is easier to see where it comes from (eg. FB not accepting Russian ads for US politics) than where it becomes censorship of media companies.

Comment: @Shog9 not to completely re-open the topic, but on the particular topic of wireless providers: within the year since this post, I discovered 2 or 3 *unlimited* wireless broadband providers that have excellent coverage all over the country.  Pricey, but real alternatives.

Comment: Unlimited, or "unlimited" @Ben? I'd love to have the option of switching my 100GB+/mo usage to wireless without having to worry about getting downgraded or disconnected. Link 'em if you got 'em!

Comment: @Shog9 For 100G, both options I know of are good to go.  Links: unlimitedville.com ("unlimited for normal usage" - e.g., "unlimited") and unlimitedleasing.com (true unlimited, afaict).  Either should be fine for 100G ballpark.  I have friends in my area who use these and are very happy with them.

Comment: That's awesome, @Ben - thanks!

Answer (score 46):

I've always had trouble explaining what Net Neutrality is to people who do not work in tech. To aid in that explanation, I made this flyer which imagines a world where 'Neutrality' did not exist for electricity providers.

[image: An analogy for Net Neutrality.]

Here's a high quality PDF if you are more into that:

https://github.com/ryanpcmcquen/ryanpcmcquen.github.io/raw/master/assets/a_net_neutrality_analogy.pdf

Comment: this is a poor analogy. the whole argument is specifically centered around content, not something that is undifferentiable like electricity itself. we are talking specifically about content. your illustration is deceptive.

Comment: The analogy is perfect. _With_ neutrality, data is undifferentiated. _Without_, you are charged for each web service you consume.

Comment: but the "control" issue is specifically about CONTENT. it is directed towards specific resources. it is not a bandwidth issue.

Comment: It most certainly is about bandwidth. ISP's throttling content was one of the core issues that brought all of this to light (comcast and other's treatment of torrents). While content censorship is also an issue, that is not what is currently at stake. This imagery is spot on.

Comment: Don't want the hassle of a Fubar package?  Simply switch providers!  Leave your slow, local energy behind with the Premium FUBAR Subscription.  Say goodbye to lights out, and hello to Fubar!

Comment: What would have happened without being classified a utility is at this point pure conjecture. How do you know that unshackled, the power companies would not have innovated and already had superlative solar-panel roofs, energy storage devices and super-efficient HVAC systems? Competition - the fight for survival always wins. The FCC on the other hand is a monopoly. Are you going to similarly argue for phone makers to be regulated as a utility?

Comment: @Καrτhικ I think the point is that, if a big, complex infrastructure is required, it's next to impossible for start-ups to do it. Therefore it can often only be done by one company. There's a choice: monopoly or utility. For water, electricity etc. utility was chosen. For internet, monopoly <del>was chosen</del> <ins>grew <del>organically</del> <ins>however it grew</ins></ins>.

Answer (score 41):

Net Neutrality is really important, and I don't disagree with your motives.  But I just have to call this out:

> So if there's a chance at influencing the outcome of that vote, we gotta speak out now.

**There isn't any such chance.**

Republicans, both in Congress and on the FCC, have been consistently opposed to Net Neutrality in its current form (Title II) since at least 2015 if not substantially earlier.  The current FCC Chairman, Ajit Pai, strongly criticized the Title II plan both [before](http://www.politico.com/story/2015/02/pai-embraces-chief-critic-role-on-net-neutrality-115298) and [after](https://arstechnica.com/business/2015/02/fcc-votes-for-net-neutrality-a-ban-on-paid-fast-lanes-and-title-ii/) it passed, and has been [specifically planning this repeal since at least April](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/04/ajit-pai-announces-plan-to-eliminate-title-ii-net-neutrality-rules/).

But let's suppose one of the other two Republicans on the Commission somehow defects (one of them voted the same way as Pai in 2015, and the other [worked under him](http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/06/29/534828696/trump-picks-republican-lawyer-for-fcc-commissioner-seat), so this is wildly unlikely).  Then what happens?

The White House [doesn't seem to like Net Neutrality](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/03/30/technology/net-neutrality.html).  Neither do the Republicans who control both houses of Congress.  At any time, they could pass a law rescinding Net Neutrality from the FCC's purview.  If by some miracle the FCC fails to repeal the regulations directly, Congress will certainly attempt this course of action.  Whether they would succeed is a bit of an open question, seeing as the Democratic caucus controls 48 seats in the Senate (incl. Independents) and can filibuster.

Regardless, however, the chances for Net Neutrality look pretty grim right now.  So what can we do about it?

- **This is a marathon, not a sprint**: We should be planning ahead for 2018, 2020, and beyond.  Focusing too much on the present is liable to leave us fatigued and discouraged when it comes time for a more winnable battle.
- **Net Neutrality was never the whole solution**: Improving the broadband market will never be down to a single policy or a single vote.  There are other proposals we can and should draw attention to, such as [last-mile unbundling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbundled_access).  Unbundling in particular is more easily sold to consumers, who may not be receptive to the indirect, market-driven benefits of Net Neutrality (but can easily understand "you'll have more broadband options").
- **Go state-by-state**: If the feds are against you, work on the states.  A number of states currently have laws prohibiting municipal broadband.  Previously, the FCC [tried to preempt these laws, but failed in the courts](http://www.latimes.com/business/hiltzik/la-fi-hiltzik-cable-municipal-broadband-20160812-snap-story.html).  So this battle has to be fought at the state level anyway.

Comment: Downvoted because this essentially reduces the conversation to "well, we don't have to have a rationale for our actions, _they_ won't listen anyway!". If you intend to retain moral high ground, you _must_ be able to defend it. Throwing away your reasons and knowledge in favor of blatent partisanship does not make your position stronger; it alienates those who might have listened to you. While it may feel better, it will only hurt your cause in the long run. Your solutions at the bottom also have nothing to do with SE or the proposed blog post.

Comment: @Knetic: What are you even talking about?  I'm not *trying* to justify anything in the first place.  This answer is about political strategy, not moral high ground.

Comment: @Kevin Consider that you're speaking as if to a purely liberal audience. Many members of stack exchange are actually not liberal and will probably still vote for the GOP after this, but may want to know a way in which to influence their representatives on this issue regardless.

Comment: @Magisch [If you find a way, we are all ears](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2017/02/27/why-facts-dont-change-our-minds), really! It's ridiculous difficult changing someone's mind once it's made up, unless they are open to change. So, how to to influence their representatives? Elect someone that is open to be influenced with reasonable arguments and take decisions based on facts, it seems like the only way.

Comment: I'd like to know *why* states are preempting local communities from establishing municipal broadband. From what I've read, most communities that have municipal broadband enjoy greater speeds and lower prices than those that do not!

Comment: @Zarepheth It cuts into the profits of private ISPs and thus they lobby against it on the state level.

Answer (score 31):

## What about non-US citizens?

It's like the whole internet is forgetting there are people from other countries out there who don't have any say (or at least it doesn't seem like they do) in these "letters to important people in power". What can we do?

I've read on many reddit threads that if you're not a USian, you can donate to EFF, but I'm not sure about that either.

---

## What can we do if this doesn't work out?

It seems like we're going to a gun fight with a tiny plastic butter knife from a child's toy house set, if even that. But in this metaphor it's our internet comments vs very real and substantial money deals between large corporations and institutions. Do you think we can simply convince them with our words?

And as a pessimist, at this point in history of the world and the US in particular (talkin bout politics, yes) I'm more interested in the ways around this issue, should shit hit the fan.

The current structure of internet entities, as it is described even in this post, suggests that with all the decentralization that should in theory have been the base of every online service and site, doesn't exist in practice, and is a rare exception instead. Like this bit of technical info from the question:

> […] this is where our servers live so any additional headaches when it comes to providing access are gonna be a problem.

And it's not a secret that a lot of the US has only one or at best two ISPs in the area to connect to the rest of the world with. It's bad for competition and it's especially bad for when all of your 1 or 2 available providers turn evil and block or slow you down.

So, should every important site and service on the internet decentralize so that problems in one node don't result in problems everywhere?

I'm not an internet architechnician, but I'd like to learn about this aspect of the problem. Just to be better informed and possibly even prepared.

Comment: The problem is at the other end. Say you get your Internet service from Comcast. And say they decide that they want you to buy your streaming video from *them*, not from Netflix  So they slow down the traffic coming from Netflix to your house. This has nothing to do with where Netflix's servers are. If you're Netflix you can probably pay the fee that Comcast demands to let your traffic through unhindered; if you're some indie video site, you probably can't. And while *that* much is a US problem, the secondary effects -- like Netflix raising fees to cover that cost -- affect everyone.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, but that doesn't cover the other side of the coin.  If Comcast wants to set up *new, faster* infrastructure to stream their own video service (which would be a much lower cost than setting up faster infrastructure for *everyone*), would they be able to legally do so?  I think not.  Even if the end result would have been (a) sufficient profits from their streaming service to (b) incentivize the creation of the accelerated infrastructure in the first place and (c) enough money *and experience* in dealing with the new infrastructure at small scale to (d) make it available broadly.

Comment: @Wildcard yeah, I don't know those answers either.  I was just trying to explain why it's not as easy as moving servers.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, ah, well *that* is certainly true.  :)  It's really an amazingly multifaceted issue—the least clear-cut of any modern hot button, in my opinion.

Comment: @MonicaCellio so, you're saying that no matter what kind of means of obfuscating where I'm trying to download my traffic from (VPN/Tor), if it's not from the "approved" places by *my* ISP (assuming I'm in the US, and it may be very well Comcast), it will get slowed down? Sounds to me like the only screwed citizens in this scenario are US citizens, as we're talking FCC which has no power outside US (granted, their decision might affect other countries, but not as much as US). Other countries may still have their own regulations in place against this kinda stuff.

Comment: *"if you're not a USian, you can donate to EFF, but I'm not sure about that either."* It's certainly possible to donate (a single time, or recurring) to the EFF even though you have nothing to do with the USA.

Comment: @user1306322 remember that the internet has many layers, and some of them are kind of the *only* route between both points. If someone along the line wants to, they can screw anyone that pass through their network.

Comment: @Braiam then we should strive to have more than just 1 route of communication between important points? Wifi or similar close-ranged mesh networking comes to mind as a potential solution, in absence of alternative high-speed wired connections.

Comment: @user1306322 which would be a cost and management nightmare. On infrastructure, it's recommended that the state regula.. nay, control it, like electricity, health, transport, etc. You cannot trust private interest to not use the leverage that brings natural monopolies to further their benefits.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It's a problem at *both* ends (and in between).  The ISP can not only stifle a competing services just before it reaches the consumer, but also between that competing services' servers and the backbone, or any time traffic from that competing service goes through any part of the network they control (even if they aren't directly servicing either endpoint).  That means that this is *most certainly* relevant for foreigners, because access to those competing services can still be impacted before they leave the country (unless the competing service has servers outside the US).

Comment: I wonder if there's a completely decentralized solution, like a mesh of a huge number of nodes with a long range and no dependency on wires. Where the users don't rely on a single or even as little as <10 connections. Wifi seems too weak for achieving that. Maybe a mesh of LTE/4/5G wireless routers and access points? Latency and bandwidth aside, I'd like to learn about such potential options in case a local ISP goes rogue.

Comment: Strange to think that back when ARPANet was put together it was designed to maintain as good as possible as much as possible of the interconnectivity between the connected Hosts - so that should some links fail in, say, the _unfortunate_ occurrence of something like a _nuclear_ war the remainder would still get their packets through what remained in the network via even a tortuous route. Now it seems the FCC is trying to work exactly in the opposite direction - at least for those who are unwilling/unable to pay for "enhanced" access to the system.

Comment: On a personal note I am seeing this sort of effect here in the UK! I have an Internet Connected PVR from [YouView](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouView) however my ISP/Cable TV [Virgin Media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_Media) operator is not one of the Media companies involved - they have their own Cable TV receivers which duplicates most of the functionality in a different way that YouView provides.  However because of "_differences in interpreting_" a protocol or something the on-line functions of the PVR are totally crippled & useless with neither taking the blame/or fixing it.

Comment: @SlySven: I'm on BT and they *hijack DNS requests*, rewriting all A-record requests to point to two of their servers, *unless you use BT's own DNS* which has censorship, and which *redirects you to adware sites* for non-existent domains instead of giving error/no response (breaking some software that expects RFC-complaint DNS).  After weeks of phone calls BT have still not "been able to find the problem"...

Comment: @MarkKCowan Does [dnscrypt](https://www.opendns.com/about/innovations/dnscrypt/) help to provide a solution to your issue?

Comment: @SlySven: No idea, I set up a DNS proxy (pdnsd) on a cloud server, serving on port 54, then another pdns proxy locally which uses that one (local proxy necessary as system insists on port 53), then I have `systemd-resolved` configured to use the local pdns proxy.  Censorship in the UK is really easy to get around, just a bit annoying.  The DNS hijacking is done by filtering only on port #53 and non-BT DNS servers.  I've also put SSH through ISPs who block it (and also the Great Firewall of China) just by running on port 443 (HTTPS).

Comment: I was considering switching to BT because VM spam email filtering also broke my IPv6 tunnel via the free SixXS broker (they finally shut down after running for 18 years last month as they feel that ISPs should have finally get their IPv6 connectivity sorted out by now) over a year ago - guess which major (Top 3) UK ISP has not yet got IPv6 implemented (well they have ~1000 test users at the moment) - it is due _real soon now_ (at least they are no longer claiming "We are not going to run out of IPv4 addresses for the foreseeable future"...! )

Comment: @user1306322 have you learned anything about decentralized solutions in the past few months? I have read about them before, mainly for use in places with very sparse internet access (rural or 'developing' places). Can't recall the 'movement' that had info on it though

Comment: @cr0 there is apparently a way to use wifi with special towers to make a mesh network with flat hierarchy and thus low latency. The real world examples I've read about are still dependent on the existing bigger ISPs' backbone, but theoretically you could interconnect such wifi mesh towns with optic cables, if you ever got a permit to place the cable. Wifi doesn't seem to require permissions, but as always, local radiotelecommunication laws differ.

Answer (score 26):

## In India

Facebook introduced a scheme called Freebasics in which Facebook and some other sites will cooperate with a carrier called Reliance and provide free access to selected sites. At that time, around 70 sites. Many carriers, as well as websites, come against this saying it will kill net neutrality. They gave free access to some sites for users of specific carriers.

Later the TRAI (Telecom Regulatory Authority of India) asked them to stop doing this. The TRAI is an authority run under Indian Government and control everything related to Telecom (The Internet as well).

In India, there are some rules, but India never supports a **Priority-based speed for customers**.

#### Another one is JIO

Mukesh Ambany introduced a Telecom Company called JIO which provided everything for free for more than a year. First, they provided free service to their employees (in beta phase). Then, to people having selected brand smartphones (Samsung and LYF). Finally, it is opened to the public.

Sometime later, all other companies united and complained to TRAI and TRAI first refused it. Afterward, all companies cut off their prices in order to keep their customers with them.

Because JIO gave free internet (100 Mbps while tested, and 24-26 Mbps in the production phase), free voice and video calls, 100's of free TV channels, free music, movies, and everything, TRAI asked JIO to stop this plan in May and then JIO changed the name of the plan and giving it also for free.

## India doesn't have such very strict rules on the Internet

However, if the ISP is able to prioritize users based on the amount they pay and serve them data based on that,

## It will kill the internet. It will not only affect SO

It will affect many big companies having the server located in the US only.

## And for sure, it will not only affect the US citizen. All of *us*. People from all over the world.

Comment: What goes into USA is blindly ported to India for some reason. Better it is stopped at its origin.

Comment: We Indian has also applied for online petition and show our strict opinion for net Net Neutrality. And by this, the Airtel and many other operators have to step back for this type of actions. TRAI has also supported for equality https://thewire.in/21301/the-rundown-on-trai-net-neutrality-and-how-it-affects-india/

Comment: It's been going for quite a while and many have supported net neutrality by signing the petition. But then they made the emails public, of those who signed.

Comment: @Firelord: What goes into USA is blindly ported over the whole world in a matter of months at longest. It's long overdue for people of the world to acknowledge that the one world government is already alive and kicking, and that it's not something that proverbial 'conspiracy theorists' make up to amuse themselves. And first and foremost, people have to understand that this entity is anything but our friend. Without acknowledging this, humankind falls divided (yes, a 'one world' hypocrisy actually works by dividing, not uniting us) and loses everything, little by little.

Comment: **"It will kill the internet."**  The US only just _got_ net neutrality regulation.  The internet isn't suddenly going to crumble because it's being removed again. I argue that there are other regulations that have created a situation where people incorrectly conclude that net neutrality regulation will help. This regulation is a bad idea that is being held up as a solution to problems that were caused by previous bad ideas.

Answer (score 24):

Here's an attempt to distill all this down to a few sentences:

I want my ISP to invest my money in making my connection faster. Not spend it finding ways to make more money by selectively making my connection slower.

That's what we need regulation to prevent. Because if we don't prevent it, they're not going to leave that money on the table. You might think competition would make this an impossible business plan. It would, if we had that.

Comment: That is indeed one of the (can I say 'emotional'?) arguments for net neutrality: ISP should not double-dip. They already get consumers money for providing a connection.

Comment: You are saying for-profit companies looking for ways to make more profit is bad? Why should you get to decide how they spend their money? You don't see them looking in your wallet?

Comment: @WeckarE. I'm saying a well regulated market is preferable to a peasant uprising where we kill all the rich people and make a musical about it.

Comment: @CandiedOrange, maybe having a proper market first would be a good idea? From the sounds of it, the major problem for lots of the US is no competition.

Comment: @WeckarE. Of course it's bad. Pareto efficiency is only achieved in efficient markets. A necessary (but not sufficient) condition for efficient markets is the presence of sufficient competition. ISP markets are oligopolistic and are therefore inherently _incapable_ of achieving Pareto efficiency without external intervention, i.e. regulation. Given the economies of scale and infrastructure costs inherent in providing ISP services, one should expect that the market will always be oligopolistic. Therefore regulation of said market will _always_ be necessary, because otherwise the profit-seeking

Comment: **_You might think competition would make this an impossible business plan. It would, if we had that._** A thousand times this.

Comment: **You might think competition would make this an impossible business plan. It would, if we had that.**  I totally agree. However with net neutrality regulation, we're asking the people who are responsible for the restriction of competition to add more restrictions to fix it, when instead, they could just as easily allow competition again.

Comment: @SuperJer That sounds like a better plan, but that's the first I've heard of it. How could they allow competition without stealing the infrastructure from the companies that own it?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Allow parallel infrastructure on public rights-of-way.  If you require that a company assures physical installation does not affect other utilities, does not unduly blight public spaces, and will not be abandoned without being removed, you have a good start on your requirements.

Comment: Infrastructure is expensive. Even for Google.

Answer (score 23):

I am sorry but I have a hard time understanding how this influences Stack Overflow and me as an user of the site (from outside the US in my case). I have read the article but it is still a bit unclear to me.

What exactly does it mean if the rules change? Does it influence businesses (aka SO), does it influence US citizens or everyone else too? Does this go further than a political standpoint as we have seen in the past of SO? What is the part of the proposal that should worry me?

I would gladly give my opinion on this, but I don't feel I am qualified enough to do so at this moment.

Comment: This influences/involves SE because they are *not* a large internet provider in the U.S., which means their provider could say "you need to pay us _______ additional or you might start mysteriously losing service."

Comment: Even better: competing sites could bribe (*legally!*) ISP's to prioritize their traffic rover SE.

Comment: You mean their connection to the hub or from the hub to consumers? @ebrown

Comment: Both, in this case.

Comment: In the Netherlands you can fix this things with contracts and SLA's. Why not in this case (for the company).

Comment: At some point every single request has to pass through *our* Internet provider wherever our servers are. So if that provider decided to do something mischievous, it would affect every single user, all over the world.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Unfortunately that's not a reality Americans can enjoy. Many places in the US only have one or two options for who they get Internet from. If your provider doesn't want to sign contracts, then you don't get Internet because there's no one else to go to.

Comment: This is, admittedly, a difficult topic to explain in a way that is particularly understandable (much less compelling). The *immediate* danger is that ISPs (companies that provide service to businesses or individuals) will either block access to sites or artificially slow down access in hope of garnering more revenue (from either/both the site owner or those connecting to the site). The broader danger is that if you stop thinking of ISPs as "common carriers" - akin to, say, a postal service - then you eventually end up with a series of walled gardens where everyone has to negotiate access.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Because those are all restrictions on the *provider* end. Classifying them as Tier II allows the FCC (our communications governing body) to restrict these companies from creating an SLA, for example, that would provide 'Experts Exchange' with a higher priority than Stack Exchange. If we reclassify as Tier I, then that is a legal SLA/contract. By considering them 'common carriers' the risk for abuse is reduced *slightly*.

Comment: It also gives the ISP the ability to not only block or slow access for monetary gain, but to do so to serve their own political agenda.  They could, for example, block or slow access to any site that advocates for a free internet, or anything else that isn't in their own interests.

Comment: Okay. That is clear @ebrown and shog. If that can be the bottom line of the blog I think that would be clear for everyone. Please include samples like the ones above to make it clear for everyone.

Comment: @animuson but you must have a contractual relationship with your own provider that would stop them doing that. Isn't the issue here other carriers, whether backbone or users' ISPs?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Of course there's a contract, but having no other competition means that the provider can give you whatever contract they want under whatever terms they like, and you can either agree to it or not have Internet. Trying to negotiate more favorable terms that prohibit the provider from doing something you wouldn't like just isn't an option in most cases.

Comment: @animuson you mean StackExchange has only one option for its own hosting? That's quite surprising.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I'm not aware of the options in the locations where our data centers are, but yes, many places in the US *do* only have one or two options and they tend not to care about creating custom contracts. They certainly don't compete with each other.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam That's *mostly* for consumer-facing communications. My city, for example, has two providers that service the block I live on (which is in the *centre* of the city!), and I'm not a fan of either. (They shall both rename nameless.) If the one I use (which is a 50/50 guess, so pretty damn easy) were to be bribed to service SE lower than something else, *well that's a problem for me*, but maybe not you. Or it could be? Who knows. The biggest issue is that this would create *unreliability* across the board, domestically and internationally.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam To add a bit to what animuson says, even in a small town (think less than 1.5k people), your ISP options can vary from people down the street. While a company proudly claimed to service my area when I moved here, I found they didn't actually service my specific street in town, so I was stuck with a small, low-speed ISP and no possible way to get better internet. (I was stuck on 1.5 gig bandwidth for 3-4 years!) Go figure it was the specific section most college kids lived in...

Comment: @animuson Indeed. The largest carriers even have legal non-compete agreements (in some cases they've even managed to swindle legislation out of politicians in their pockets) so that they don't have to worry about serious competition.

Comment: @animuson I can understand that being the case for home ISPs particularly in less populated areas, I'm just really surprised that it's the case for the hosting business - particularly as you could just move to a new data centre.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Of course "just move to a new data center" is easier said than done. Such a move would bear a financial cost of 8 or 9 figures, probably. And that's not considering the technical load and workers they have to have to manage such a thing.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam A small number of providers service the entire country, and in most cases they each have their own geographic region(s).  Likewise, that ISP that you just choose to spite (that may well provide access to tens of millions of people) could still limit traffic to your site for any of their customers, or any traffic going to you that goes through them (likely quite a lot of it) for being unwilling to play ball.  The small handful of providers are also highly incentivised to cooperate, rather than compete, in such situations.

Comment: @Shog9 this kind of gets into what I say in my post about framing points of fact, but it's relevant to point out here, too: you say "the immediate danger is that ISPs will either block or artificially slow down access in hope of garnering more revenue" as though it's a fact, but without supporting evidence.  Whether or not this outcome is, in fact, an immediate danger is one of the points of contention between the various views.

Comment: @EBrown it is *much worse than that*. SE already pays *their provider* for bandwidth, and that provider can ask for more if it wants; but there are standard commercial pressures . Without net neutrality, other providers, such as *my provider* could go to SE and say, "unless you pay us as well, our subscribers won't be able to access your site (or it will be slower whatever)". SE isn't likely to be affected directly in the short term, but e.g. Netflix might find that it's streaming doesn't work as well as the subscriber's ISP's streaming offering unless the pay.

Comment: I'd originally written something much, much longer @Ben - there's a ton of history here, both directly (the 1996 revisions to the communication act attempted a different compromise which was later partially dismantled) and indirectly (predicting outcome based on hypotheticals is dodgy, but we can look at predecessors to the Internet and similar markets to gauge how current actors will likely behave). That's when I realized I'd rather put this up for discussion: listening to me ramble on about Compuserve isn't nearly as engaging as encouraging folks to share their own stories.

Comment: "Whether or not this outcome is, in fact, an immediate danger is one of the points of contention between the various views" - This is the reason we can never accomplish anything. Arguing over wether a bad thing will happen is pointless, no-one knows. What we do know is if we block the ability to have the bad outcome, well, no argument there, it shouldn't happen. I fail to see the side of the argument that says "That won't happen". If we agree with that side and it does happen they get to say, "Sorry, I did not think it would happen" and we are stuck with it cause it is not going to change.

Comment: @Eric It's often a _good_ reason to not accomplish something when you can't point to imminent or concrete issues (not totally unlike the YAGNI principle).  Correspondingly, there are costs associated with changes.  Increasing regulation increases the chances of regulatory capture, for example (which in this case we already have, but the "Net Neutrality" rules are prone to make it worse, in my view).  There is more besides that, but the point is nothing is without its own set of tradeoffs.

Comment: @Eric, perhaps, but we *do* know that **horrible** things can happen in pursuit of "preventing bad things from happening."  Did you know that the Holocaust was based on a psychiatric theory and movement (eugenics) which sought to arrest the impending deterioration of the human race due to poor genes?  Your argument could be applied verbatim in favor of *that* preemptive measure, also.  Reread your comment.  Apply it to the supposed danger of gene pool deterioration.  Then reconsider your rationale for taking action: do you measure the *possible harm* as well as the possible avoided harm?

Comment: @BenCollins You say, "costs associated with changes" and yet the *current* regulations are for the net to be free.  The people arguing for changes are the ones who are arguing for the ability of ISPs to engage in abusive behavior.  **You** are the one arguing for a change, and a change that has no benefits.  (Your "best case scenario" is nothing happens and ISPs don't actually leverage their ability to discriminate against people, as opposed to them deciding to use the permission you're proposing giving them to legally engage in such actions.)

Comment: @Shog9, but are there any examples anywhere of ISPs price gouging random non-abusive sites for extra money completely arbitrarily? (i.e. not ones that are super-high-bandwidth?). Or of ISPs shutting down websites they "don't like"? Do you really honestly in your heart believe anyone is going to try to limit access to SE?

Comment: The last question is the critical one, @Benjol: and the answer is, I don't know. I *want* to believe that's just not plausible, but the truth is that even with relatively low bandwidth requirements for any individual user there are enough users in aggregate to potentially make us a target should one company happen to end up serving a large chunk of them. This is where you look for comparable situations in history, and end up finding them in both the telephone and cable industries, doubly unsettling given who currently operates most of the US consumer ISP market.

Comment: @Shog9, this battle is a philosophical one. Which side you fall depends on who you trust the least: the corps that will screw you over, or the state that will screw things up :)

Comment: @EBrown: `Even better: competing sites could bribe (legally!) ISP's to prioritize their traffic rover SE.` — Oh no, does this mean ISPs forcing us to remember ExpertSexChange.com again?..

Comment: @Benjol -- HBO, NBC, and Starz have historically had issues with their streaming services on Comcast, to the point that users couldn't access the services the paid for. It's part of what took HBO so long to come out with a fully independent streaming option. And yes this matters, because it highlights the conflict of interest we currently have with ISPs and why it needs to be codified that internet access be common carrier.

Answer (score 22):

Let me preface this by stating that **I am all for net neutrality**. However, I am strongly against the government defining, requiring, regulating, or enforcing it.

### History

Back in the '90s this debate raged as well. However, it had a different focus. Dialup ISPs competed for your business by offering lower prices, better features, or faster speed. Some of them, noticing a  market need, even advertised that they were 'net neutral', promising the same priority to site X as to site Y, at no additional cost. Net neutrality was a good thing, and was willfully adopted by ISPs seeking to attract subscribers.

### The Effect

Why did this happen? Why were ISPs bending over backward? The answer is competition. You could easily take your business literally to any ISP you wanted in less than an hour of time spent on the phone.

Why does this no longer happen? What is it now that makes ISPs complacent, threatening higher costs for certain services, limiting your bandwidth, and generally assuming you won't be taking your business elsewhere? The answer as you might expect, is the complete lack of competition.  You **can't** take your business elsewhere. Everyone knows that if you want respectable internet speeds, you have to go with cable (or fiber in some places). Unfortunately, that means you have only one option, and depending on your location, that single option is going to be Comcast, Mediacom, or if you're kinda lucky, some local cable outfit. This is because there is only one cable provider in any given area.

### The Cause

There are SO MANY CAUSES as to why we each only get one company to choose from when we want cable internet. Or DSL. Or some of us now, fiber. Some of it dates back 80+ years to regulations that were implemented federally to prevent too many carriers from running too many wires between towns, and between houses and businesses. Some of it is related to city regulation and planning under those same auspices, resulting in bidding wars and ultimately one choice. Some of it also is due to corruption (Legal, usually, but still corruption.  See: 'kickbacks')

Like so many other well-intentioned regulations, the net neutrality regulations will bring us worse internet for more money. Or at the very least, hold us back technologically. Building out infrastructure that can support half an ISP's clients using Netflix simultaneously requires lots of money. Ideally, those that are causing the need for that infrastructure improvement would pay for it (be that Netflix, the ISP's subscribers who use it, or both). Mandating net neutrality basically ensures that ALL the ISP clients will pay, whether they use it or not, and Netflix doesn't need to do anything.

### The Solution

So what's the answer? Asking the FCC to mandate net neutrality is like asking the guy who broke your arm (whether on purpose or by accident) to build you a cast for it. It would have been better to not have the broken arm in the first place, and the guy we're asking is probably the least qualified to fix it anyway. He'll likely just break your other arm when he's done, all the while asking, "You have a cast now. Isn't that better?"

We need to look beyond the net neutrality regulation's initial perceived benefit. Removing it is a good thing, but it's only part of the solution. The petition to the FCC shouldn't be to leave 'Net Neutrality' instated, but to **remove** the other regulations that are leaving us without choices.

We also need to be outraged at any city government who would trade individual choice for kickbacks, or who would hide behind the net neutrality debate as a way of dodging the criticism they've earned themselves.

### Conclusion

There's a way out of this. However, too many people are espousing actions too similar to the ones that got us here in the first place. It's easy to say, "Yeah, the internet should be 'net neutral'." But until the landscape of our infrastructure regulation changes, it's impossible to say, "You know what? I'm taking my dollars to the company who gives me the most value." We've seen this problem solved before, but now we're asking the wrong people to solve it again in the wrong way.

Net neutrality has existed in the wild before, and I think we're smart enough to get back to it without asking the perpetrators of its demise to mandate its blessing.  There would be **so** many benefits to doing it this way.

Comment: Be careful about anthropomorphizing "government"; leads to some really bizarre analogies. The actual history here, as you know, is bizarre enough. That said, real competition would be infinitely better than a handful of weakly-enforced rules... The danger right now is that we can quite easily end up with *neither!*

Comment: @Shog9 I don't know.  As a whole, if you averaged all of our government and distilled it down, I think you'd end up with a pretty solid picture of an incompetent person gathering power around himself, while thinking he's doing the rest of humanity a big favor by doing so.

Comment: Whether or not that's the case, that isn't what we have in practice. We don't drink a homogeneous "Gov't milkshake"; we get different people doing different things at different times. Hence the massively inconsistent approach to telecom over the past 40 years, wherein TPTB encourage competition for a while, then crush it; encourage consumer protection for a while, then call open season; encourage growth, then encourage decay.

Comment: My approach to most any nation-wide issue is to decentralize the solution. The problem with the FCC is that when the fix fixes it for everyone, there's no test/control comparison to see whether it even worked. There's also a suspicious correlation between the growth of our federal government, its unelected regulatory bodies, and the size of company monopolies. Put the control back closer to where the individual has effective say, and a lot of these problems get solved. Have the big government debate, but have it in smaller batches with more accountability. FCC+Net Neutrality isn't this.

Comment: There's something to that, but I kinda doubt we'll be seeing a Bell-sized break-up any time soon. In the meantime, I've watched local governments try to negotiate with national corporations, and it has generally ended with the locals getting a raw deal. All but the largest cities have vastly inferior resources to what a company like Comcast can bring to bear.

Comment: @Shog9 And I think I might disagree about the milkshake. Until it's brought down a notch, government at the federal level is out of control no matter who is in charge. People seeking power always spells aggravation for those who don't. Hence my insistence that local and state government should actually be higher authority than the federal government. Laboratory of the State and all. I think some smart men back in the day mentioned something about that. I think the Net Neutrality regs debate would be a drop in the bucket of their concerns over the FCC and what it has become.

Comment: @Shog9 RE: local gov vs. big corp: A lot of that is due to the subsidized monopoly backing of the federal government. Though I agree with most who say we'll never know for sure.

Comment: As a philosophical point... The federal government was supposed to mainly be concerned with interstate trade. If we had more local companies working together with national interconnection providers, I'd be happy to see the feds concern themselves with the latter and stay the hell away from the former... But that ain't what we have.

Comment: Bingo.  Highfive.

Comment: What most troubles me about this line of reasoning is the underlying subtle-yet-toxic contempt for government that has slowly pervaded the US body politic since the Reagan administration. Without some government oversight, a free market cannot be counted on to become or remain a fair market. The Net Neutrality issue is sure to prove to be a case in point.

Comment: @EricLloyd Oh, I'm not subtle about my toxic contempt. But don't confuse contempt for bloated, uncontrollable federal government with contempt for government in general. When a state or local government implements a bad idea, it can be fixed or abandoned. When the federal government implements a bad idea, it's a catastrophe. Bad ideas need to be able to fail, and the federal government offers the least opportunity for this, but the greatest consequences.

Answer (score 20):

One note regarding the execution of whatever the result will be of this discussion: make sure you're anticipating that small subset of the user base who do not agree with consensus/eventual decision. There are even users who feel oppressed when SO publicly endorses civil rights, so it should be expected that a non-trivial amount of people will disagree with what I expect will turn out to be a site-wide vast support of net neutrality.

You will either have to act in a way that doesn't implicitly represent users who disagree, or be prepared to lose them. This divide has arisen multiple times (whenever SO the company made official statements outside of programming or other relevant scopes). Any decision of the company to handle this conflict is fine, but it should be a conscious one.

Comment: I get push-back when I announce the results of elections. I *always* expect *some* negativity; at the end of the day, I'd rather say what I think and catch flack for it than say what I don't and *still* catch flack.

Comment: @Shog oh, flak is one thing:) But I've seen the aftermath (overstatement, but you probably know what I mean) of the LGBTQ rights event, and I saw the reaction to Joel's recent post. I don't think anyone minds if you express your opinions; it seems to me that what some people object to is if they feel represented by said expressions of opinions. Not that it should matter, but I'm happily represented by these statements, and I wouldn't mind if there were more of them. But these political frictions are what might actually drive users away.

Comment: Needless to say, I wouldn't want to hang with the users who are driven away by these gestures, but SO is supposed to be built around expertise and technical subjects, so the fact that I completely disagree with these people is irrelevant; what matters is that they help build the knowledge base that is SO (and the SE network in general).

Comment: This is what I can't stand, all the political messaging on this site is costal groupthink,  the kind of garbage that got Brandon Eich fired.   Nobody has brought up here that they want to regulate the content of the Internet and make it more like broadcast media.   And in the end we'll need licenses to have websites, podcast and blog.

Comment: @PeterTurner *Brendan* Eich *wasn't* fired. He resigned. Also, if you have something new nobody has brought up, you should post an answer. Just remember, [citation needed].

Comment: @alex I have posted a not so well recived answer already.  As for Eich, I'd say they made it might unconfortable for him for reasons having nothing to do with his ability to perform his duties - worse than being fired.

Comment: *I don't think anyone minds if you express your opinions* - It seemed like plenty of people minded, especially on the last one. Some were "don't speak for me" but some were just "No, shut up" and some were "don't speak for me, oh but there's no way for you to say it in a way I won't insist you're trying to represent me so shut up".

Comment: @BSMP What I meant was "if you express your opinion, people who disagree will hate *you*" as opposed to rage-quitting for political reasons which can be the result of feeling misrepresented. Let's face it: most people already have a solid opinion of Shog9 ;)

Comment: @chill dude nobody's opinions matter more. That is _not_ how our government works.

Comment: @PeterTurner I would agree that nobody's opinions matter more. I suppose I am upset about whose opinions politicians spend more lip service pretending to care about than others, but that actually is fairly pointless, i.e. complaining about whose opinions representatives bother to _pretend_ to represent the most. Hopefully the robots manage to make a perfect society for themselves after they kill us all, although I doubt it, since we would be the ones who made them, and therefore they will be indelibly tainted to some extent with the remnants of our own flaws.

Comment: As a dissenter, standing strongly opposed to net neutrality regulation, I'm not troubled in the least by OP's 'question', or the fact that SE is used as a platform for its publication. I have no right to SE, and I will continue using it for as long as it's available to me and serves my needs.

Comment: Regardless of politics, good to have you on board, @SuperJer :)

Comment: I personally get annoyed when companies, not prominent individuals who work for companies, make public declarations on politics that has no relation to their business. SE has an opinion on net neutrality? Makes perfect sense. SE has an opinion on some civil issue? Makes no sense. Bad example: Starbucks. Just make the effing coffee. Mixed example: NFL kneeling players. I feel like "just play the effing game", but I understand these are individual players, not team owners or the NFL. Good example: most companies that just make a good product/service.

Answer (score 19):

For folks getting their viewpoints from insular sources (StackExchange being one of them), please consider reading these two articles written from a different viewpoint.

In [The FCC’s ‘Open Internet Rules’ Make the Internet Less Open](http://www.nationalreview.com/article/447854/fcc-open-internet-rules-make-internet-less-open), Ian Tuttle, writing for the National Review, asserts:

Relevant portion:

> Net neutrality was always a solution looking for a problem. When, in 2010, the FCC announced its first extensive regulations on ISPs (what would become the core of the 2015 rules), it could cite just four examples of anticompetitive behavior, all relatively minor. In 2005, for example, a North Carolina telephone company blocked the Internet phone service Vonage. In 2007, Comcast slowed down (“throttled”) the operations of file-sharing service BitTorrent.

and its potential dangerous impact:

> None of this was necessary. There was very little evidence that ISPs were engaging in the sorts of malpractice that net neutrality was designed to prevent — and even if they had been, it would not have followed that reclassification was the proper remedy. In fact, a more honest appraisal of the sequence of events is that the Obama administration and left-wing activists succeeded in pressuring the FCC into a maximal power-grab that is likely to do much more damage to Internet freedom than Comcast was doing. **Why is the FCC’s monopoly not as concerning as that of any given ISP?**

In [A Truly ‘Open Internet’ Would Be Free of Burdensome FCC Regulation](http://www.nationalreview.com/article/447354/fcc-net-neutrality-internet-freedom-best-protected-without-government-regulation), Brent Skorup, writing for the National Review, observes:

> The substance of the new rules is almost immaterial, save one, the “general conduct” rule, which with vague language swallows all the others and allows the agency to investigate and prohibit any online service, app, or business practice that it determines is “unreasonable.” When asked which activities the Internet-conduct standard could regulate, the FCC’s then-Democratic chairman replied that “we don’t really know.”

That quote, from then-FCC chairman Tom Wheeler at a press conference shortly after the current rules went into effect when questioned on the general conduct rule, reads in full:

> We don’t really know. We don’t know where things will go next. We have created a playing field where there are known rules, and the FCC will sit there as a referee and will throw the flag.

(source: [Obamanet’s Regulatory Farrago](https://www.wsj.com/articles/gordon-crovits-obamanets-regulatory-farrago-1426457509),  L. Gordon Crovitz writing for WSJ's "Information age" opinion section)

Comment: Great answer. I would only quibble with calling stack exchange an echo chamber. Your answer gives minority opinion, but here it sits with 18 up votes and visibility commensurate with those votes.

Comment: If you want a good example of an echo chamber on this issue, read the comments on any article from ars technica about FCC or Ajit Pai. They are viciously hostile against dissenting minority opinions. I quit the site because of it.

Answer (score 15):

## The practical downside for YOU

Many people fail to see the *practical* application of this. Here it is:

From the *consumer side*, ISPs could:

- **charge you money** to access certain sites (google, facebook, etc)
- slow block sites that they don't like (sites for net neutrality, etc.)
- slow down sites that they compete with (making netflix lag so their streaming service is faster)

From the *website owner side*, ISPs could (for US-based sites):

- Threaten (*legally*) to prioritize a competitor's website unless they pay (SO/SE is really slow, ExpertsExchange is fast)
- Block incoming traffic altogether for certain sites (like [battleforthenet.com](https://www.battleforthenet.com/) or SE) because they don't like them

## But I'm not in America, so this doesn't affect me!

***Wrong.*** Do you use any sites that use American servers? (yes you do, you are viewing this.) Therefore you can **and will** be affected.

Comment: Many countries have state regulators to prevent such abuses. It worked in EU against Microsoft, it worked in Russia against Google. Make a regulator for the internet - problem solved, no foreign help needed.

Comment: @Abyx That was the intent of the net neutrality rules.

Answer (score 10):

I am against Net Neutrality.  Instead of writing a long post that will be ignored and downvoted I will summarize my thoughts.  Also, with all do respect to Shog9 but asking for discussion on this biased forum is a little naive.

The problem that Net Neutrality is trying to solve is ISP charging (or slowing/restricting) access to a given content provider.  It is not about censorship, don't confuse the two problems.  The issues I have are two fold.

### Is this really a problem?

The current standard for broadband and mobile data is to charge a rate for a minimum speed and amount of data transfer, ie 10 GB @ min 25 MBs.  No one seems to think this is outrageous and gladly pays their cellphone/cable bills. You may not like the price but you don't mind paying for the service.  Saying that AT&T or Comcast should not charge for faster speeds or more data is like saying fast food and fine dining should cost the same.  Should content providers be except from the same pricing model the consumer pays?  If Netflix was forced to pay for more bandwidth they may invest in a better way to compress/deliver digital video over the internet or invent the futurenet.

### What is the solution?

Making a regulation that says "play nice" is ridiculous on it's face.  Is the answer to regulate all ISP's to cap profits at 10%?  To say they all must provide 100 MB/s download speeds everywhere?  Let's examine the first one.  If Comcast is capped at 10% profit they can have a healthy business and never upgrade equipment or coverage area.  There is no incentive for expansion.  Instead of being "pro Net Neutrality", purpose a regulation that will work.  Most of us are pro saving the fluffy bunny.  Do we kill the cuddly rabbit to do it?

No proposed regulation I have read makes sense in terms innovation, expansion and profit.  To argue that ISP's should only charge the consumer is fine.  The content providers will pay nothing.  So the entire cost of faster networks to accommodate the higher quality (both in terms of data and reliability) now must fall on the consumer.  Let the free market determine the future of the internet.  It did fine in determining the present growth of the internet.

Comment: +1 While I don't agree with you on this topic, the question did ask for reasons against Net Neutrality and this is a well thought out answer.  I'd encourage you to expand on it, I think it could help others see view points that differ from their own.

Comment: `The problem that Net Neutrality is trying to solve is ISP charging (or slowing/restricting) access to a given content provider. It is not about censorship` Net neutrality is about *both*.  It's not *just* about throttling of a particular entities content, but also about it being blocked entirely.

Comment: `Saying that AT&T or Comcast should not charge for faster speeds or more data is like saying fast food and fine dining should cost the same.`  Your analogy doesn't hold, and it seems to stem from a lack of understanding of what's going on.  What's happening is that you, as a person, pay $X for, say, 10 MBs of internet, but then your internet provider, *on your end of the connection*, only lets, say, 1 MBs of content come through from some company *contrary to what you've paid for*, and even if that companies servers are using an entirely different ISP.

Comment: The problem here is not that the ISP Netflix is paying to connect to the network is asking to charge them for the bandwidth they use; that has always been the case, still is the case, and isn't what people have a problem with.  What happened was *other* ISPs, ISPs connecting the internet backbone to *consumers* of Netflix, would throttle the traffic *if they detected it came from Netflix*.

Comment: Also note that the regulations *aren't* capping profits, and they *aren't* mandating certain download speeds everywhere.  What they are mandating is that traffic going through network needs to all be treated equally.  You can't intentionally slow down certain traffic and not others when it's on the network.  That doesn't inherently prevent ISPs from making a profit.  Making it legal for them to discriminate against certain people or organizations is not essential for their ability to make money.

Comment: I assure you, Netflix and other content providers are paying for their bandwidth, even with the net neutrality rule currently in place. They have invested heavily in [new compression algorithms](http://mdp-labs.co/netflix-leads-with-superior-compression-algorithms/) &c to minimize their bandwidth usage. Thus, some company is *already making money from Netflix's bandwidth usage*. The pending rule change is saying that not only does Netflix have to pay for the bandwidth to the internet, and users' have to pay for connection to the internet, both of them might have to pay *again* to get Netflix.

Comment: How about breaking up the big ISP's?  We know that a big ISP is no better at servimg up the Internet than a small one, so why do we even let them get so big?

Comment: Great deleted answer.

Comment: _"You may not like the price but you don't mind paying for the service"_ I absolutely do mind.  However, I _**have**_ to use the internet.  I have no other options for ISPs in my area so they get to gouge me.

Comment: @zero298 that's an anti-trust issue, not a net neutrality one.

Answer (score 10):

***tl;dr*-**  Net neutrality's core economic value is that it regulates a common service that everyone uses to operate in a manner that's generally palatable to all.  This saves everyone tons of time-and-effort at minimal opportunity cost.

Any proposed change to net neutrality should demonstrate that it:

1. Has a real economic benefit, e.g. by ***significantly*** increasing the positive correlation between desired market behavior and profit maximization.
2. Doesn't impart a large economic penalty on consumers, e.g. by ***minimally*** complicating the economic question of "*Which ISP, if any, is right for me?*" for the vast majority of consumers.
3. Doesn't impart a large societal penalty, e.g. by ***minimally*** causing social/political/legal conflict, or, ideally, ***reducing*** such conflict.  Both society and the market take huge hits whenever such battles rage.

---

#### Ideal market vs. real market

***In principle***, it'd be better if all market participants were free to do whatever they want, allowing rational consumers to engage in the economy as they desire.  Then, arguably, some regulations could exist to prevent blatantly unethical behaviors, e.g. organized crime.

***In reality***, people aren't "rational consumers" because we're cognitively limited.  We're not able to research-and-analyze all of our options at length, then come to an optimal decision after eons of careful consideration.  Any market based on the notion that consumers have infinite time to consider all options is going to fail under the weight of reality.

---

#### Costs vs. benefits

***The core economic value*** of net neutrality is to remove the extensive cost of considering highly complex options that could appear if ISP's were suddenly able to start doing whatever the heck they want, including throttling particular sites, users, etc., at different times, rate plans, etc..  Seriously, you'd have to get a Ph.D. in your local ISP's practices to even begin to make an optimal decision for yourself, and the market simply can't bear everyone spending that much time on a single economic decision.

***The core economic cost*** of net neutrality is that ISP's and users can't arrive at optimal, customized plans, as they could in an ideal free market where everyone had the time to research-and-analyze all of their options.

---

#### Value of regulation = benefits - costs

***The value of regulation*** is the reduction in decision complexity less the opportunity cost of the prohibited alternatives.

For net neutrality, ***we're enjoying far more simplicity in choosing ISP's*** and ISP's engaging with customers.  Additionally, we help ensure free speech, saving us the costs of defending it when infringed.

For losses, ***we have cases where services like Netflix*** can use an out-sized portion of bandwidth, then that cost is distributed to all users.

While the losses *are* losses, the actual economic detriment from them appears to be pretty modest, while the economic benefit of everyone not having to police their own ISP is huge.  Overall, ***the net economic value of net neutrality appears to be hugely positive***.

Personally, I'm glad that I don't have to watch out for what my ISP might be doing; that'd be a real annoyance!  Especially since I've lived in lots of areas where there was literally just one viable ISP.

---

#### Relaxing net neutrality

Conceivably, ***we might want to relax net neutrality*** in some limited, carefully considered ways.

Under the economic principle of coupling desired market behavior to profit maximization, relaxations to net neutrality should allow people to take options that they realistically have time to consider in a manner that better couples costs to benefits, increasing market freedoms.

This retreat from market neutrality makes sense in, say, cellular networks if bandwidth can be too limited.  Then, we'd want carriers to better reflect real costs in their pricing plans.

The danger here is that our system currently allows anti-market practices, e.g. artificial market segmentation and exploitation of pricing power.  ***These behaviors are anti-market.***  No capitalist who believes in the primacy of the free market should want to live in a world where such corrupt tactics are used because these tactics ***demonstrably result in a decoupling of utility vs. profit maximization***.  Any relaxation of net neutrality should ensure that customers don't have to watch their ISP's for such bad behavior.

---

#### The issue of censorship

Since the internet is a primary mechanism for information transit, any modification to it can be used to effect some sort of censorship, even if partial.

Some might argue that censorship could be illegal and fought in the courts.  However, ***having to fight minor acts of censorship in court would be a gross economic burden***.  Our court systems are already expensive and overburdened; we don't need more of that, nor do we want to effectively require that everyone have to get involved in suing their ISP over such issues.

Comment: Even in principle the ISP market shouldn't be deregulated -- even (unrealistically) assuming rational buyers, due to economies of scale https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economies_of_scale the ISP industry is not and will never be even remotely close to satisfying the assumptions of perfect competition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_competition and therefore can _not_ achieve a Pareto optimum without external intervention, i.e. regulation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency Saying simply that "people are stupid" encourages people to remain ignorant of _basic_ economics.

Comment: I didn't read through you entire answer, but one point that I see missing in your "Ideal market vs. real market" section is the fact that we can't vote with our wallet.  You either pay the ISP that will shaft you or you don't get internet.  There is no competition to facilitate offering better service up to being limited by cost.

Comment: *"We're not able to research-and-analyze all of our options at length"*. Whose definition of 'rational consumer' includes this point? This is a straw man.

Comment: *"Seriously, you'd have to get a Ph.D. in your local ISP's practices"* A gross exaggeration based on another straw man.  Numerous highly technical decisions by rational consumers are made all the time, and the economy is not suffering for it. In fact, we can argue the opposite, that piles of consumers constantly criticizing technical products make those products better and easier to use. A situation of "municipal internet" or similar leaves the provider with one critic of import, the government official.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend moving this discussion to a Stack Exchange forum that's germane to the topic and not pursue this as advocacy.

Many people are sick to death of companies inserting themselves into political debates. Many or most participants in the Stack Exchange community won't care about your views and would prefer to not be involved.

Comment: This might be better as a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: @hde I had the same thought, but the OP said he would be clearing out comments so that option wasn't available.

Comment: Shog9 obviously feels strongly about NN, but many of us see the whole push for NN as an effort by Netflix to exert pressure on Comcast during their interconnect disputes. Plenty of people bought into Netflix's narrative. In any case, if the traffic was piling up at Netflix's ISP's routers when trying to route traffic to Comcast customers, and Comcast didn't have a commensurate amount of traffic piling up to get back to Netflix's ISP, I can see Comcast's point about asking for said ISP to pay the majority of the cost of stringing up new lines to send traffic over to Comcast.

Comment: There's no point in being young if you can't find a cause to be passionate about.

Answer (score 9):

I believe that Stack Exchange fails to serve the needs of their core community. Those interested about why I think so can find a [detailed explanation here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281807/165773).

Because of that, I am uncomfortable about SE taking a stand in political, social, ethical, etc. matters pretending to represent the community (which, as I said, I believe they fail to serve).

The above also applies to Net Neutrality. I would much appreciate it if SE abstain from statements that can be interpreted as representing the community.

Comment: to preempt comments about my personal take on NN, I am inclined to support it (though I am yet to complete studying of the materials referred in Shog's post to make sure that I got it right). But anyway, whatever it is, I would object against Stack Exchange pretending to represent my position on that matter for the reasons laid out in this answer

Comment: Oh well... This is the "just do your job" argument which has lead to the most horrific examples in human history. We are talking about the internet as we know it being hi-jacked by people who want to protect their old-world businesses against newcomers, killing innovation in the process. It is no less than a coup. Sure this is "political", most things that matter are. And it is any business's right to take side as it is yours to support that stand or not. You can stay "neutral" yourself, you know.

Comment: @MartinMaat you seem to misread or misinterpret what I wrote, I don't know intentionally or not. I re-read my answer several times and honestly have no idea what could lead to conclusions you made

Comment: Could you make a bogus edit? I upvoted this, but then found out that upholding NN is too important for "don't sign me up until you do your job", and now I want to downvote this but can't because my vote is locked.

Comment: `I am uncomfortable about SE taking a stand in political, social, ethical etc matters pretending to represent the community`... You're completely entitled to your opinion, but I don't see where SE is claiming to represent the community. SE is making its opinion known, just as other companies do -- i.e. Facebook, GitHub, etc. -- but that doesn't imply that its membership supports that opinion.

Answer (score 8):

In general I agree that Net Neutrality is a good thing, or let's put it the other way round: The fundamental lack of Net Neutrality would be a very bad thing. This way around makes more sense, as something that protects you from evil is not necessarily good; the enemy of your enemy is not your friend, just because you share some common interests.

There are two things I'd like to point out in this discussion:

1. Most people have the incorrect belief that the Internet has always been neutral until recent and now the big companies try to change that. The truth is: The Internet has never been neutral. The Internet, as we know it, which emerged from the ARPANET sometimes in the 80s, had no guarantee for neutrality in USA prior to February 26, 2015 when then FCC reclassified broadband Internet access as a telecommunications service. Prior to that date, the Internet may or may not have been more or less neutral as there was no regulation that would force ISPs to be neutral and traffic prioritization at Universities for example (the earliest civil Internet members of all) used to be the norm as bandwidth was scare and expensive at that time. In other parts of the world, the Internet may have always been neutral, never been neutral up to today, or not have been neutral until recently. The fact that despite the lack of any regulation in that area most people always had a rather neutral access in most parts of the western world shows that even without regulation the neutrality doesn't have to be in danger.
2. The consequence of (1) is that by forcing Net Neutrality upon the Internet means, the Internet as we used to know it from the 80s to 2015 won't be the Internet of the years to come. Forcing neutrality is not preserving the status quo, it is creating something new, it is a change. Or let's say it was a change in 2015, as since that day neutrality is the new status quo. Still, it's a pretty fresh change and change is not a synonym for improvement, it only means things will be different and different is no synonym for better. While I'm pretty sure the positive aspects outnumber the negative by far, I'm not neglecting that there might be negative aspects if neutrality is forced without any valid exceptions, e.g. increasing prices, loss of competition, or a decrease in capital investment. As for you the Internet is just a communication medium, but for the companies that keep it alive, it is business.

Keep in mind that use is not the same as abuse. If we'd forbid to sell anything that can be abused, some stores would be pretty empty. The opposite of neutrality is also not censorship. Censorship breaks neutrality but traffic prioritization does as well, just like selectively charging for traffic. I'm strictly against censorship and I'm strictly against any kind of market abuse and Net Neutrality fights both, but it's not a strict necessity to fight both.

All the negative aspects ISPs mention about Net Neutrality are actually true. The fact that most here would wish they were not or don't like to hear them doesn't make these claims false. Well, of course, they are exaggerating the situation a lot, they fear for their income, especially the loss of existing of future income sources, so there's also a lot of whining, take it with a grain of salt; but at its core the statements are not lies. This enforcement will have consequences and it already had a few negative consequences for some people. If the "business" Internet access becomes unattractive, most companies can easily give up on it and concentrate on something else, it's their former customer that will have a problem then.

In an ideal world, there would be plenty of ISPs available everywhere you can just choose from and the competition would give us all low prices and high bandwidths. In an ideal world, we could vote by feet, we wouldn't need a law forcing neutrality; if we desire neutrality and one ISP is not offering it, we go to a competitor. No ISP can survive without customers, so they would have become neutral if that is what customers demand. Yeah, in an ideal world... just that the world is nowhere near as ideal. And the enforced Net Neutrality, for example, won't do anything to improve that situation, it will not change anything there (best case) or it will make it even worse for some people (worst case).

There cannot be light without shadow. And it's okay to accept some shadow. I just cannot stand it when people pretend that the shadow doesn't exist because they want to make their point of view to look even better than it actually is, despite the fact that they are already in the stronger position. It's okay to admit that a solution is not perfect, I mean, what is perfect anyway? Just my 2 cent.

Comment: Eh. Brazil uses a very, _very_ broken system for ISP providers - probably one of the worst in the world - and we can work nicely with Net Neutrality without issues, since the [Marco Civil of the Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_Civil_Rights_Framework_for_the_Internet). Sure, we had some hiccups, but without Net Neutrality we would have been stuck with ISPs taxing a few extra dollars for _Gmail Access_. Or a whole ten bucks extra for _Youtube_. Without this thing, some services that are now changing the way we consume media (like Netflix) wouldn't be viable.

Comment: @T.Sar You are confusing use with abuse. Charging extra for Gmail access would just be abuse. It would also be abuse in a net without any neutrality as it clearly is blackmailing customers and that is always abuse, in every system and in every country.

Comment: Net Neutrality is what protects users against this form of abuse. Without it, this type of "abuse" would be perfectly legal. ISPs would be authorized to charge differently for whatever thing you chose to use. That's the big deal, and that is what people who oppose it aren't grasping.

Comment: You are correct that for a long time the net was neutral *by convention* rather than by regulation.  Providers *choose* to be neutral rather than being legally required to.  There was indeed a change to make that convention into a legal requirement.  But that legal change didn't come out of nowhere.  It didn't just happen out of fear of what might happen.  What changed was *the ISPs* who had started breaking the convention and violating net neutrality.  Since the convention was being broken, and they could no longer be trusted to self-police, *they forced regulations onto themselves*.

Comment: So to then say that we can revoke these new regulations because the ISPs can be trusted to self-police, *is demonstrably false*.  We *know* they can't, because even though they had been for quite some time, *they* choose to stop keeping the net neutral.  They are also the ones who have been fighting to remove these regulations; if they were so interested in following these same policies anyway, by convention, *why would they feel the need to fight them*. The only real reason to be so concerned with repealing them is because *they want to continue the abusive behaviors that they had been doing.

Comment: "If we'd forbid to sell anything that can be abused, **all** stores would be empty." - fixed it for you

Answer (score 7):

I'm not living in U.S., why do I see this banner on every SO site I visit, SO-on-Russian included?
**Upd:** on every device.

It is internal U.S. politics, please keep it internal.

I don't want foreigners to meddle with my country, so why do you ask a foreigner like me to put pressure on the government of your country?

Gathering a cheering mob of bystanders has nothing to do with democracy. There isn't much of a difference between using unrelated people and using shills.

---

Inb4 "but what if U.S. regulations would affect SO in a bad way"?
A: it's their [U.S.] business, I have no say in that.

Comment: No one's asking you to meddle. I'm asking you to become aware of what's going on, and - if you feel moved to do so - speak up. Does what you say matter? That's impossible to know; but if you say nothing then it is guaranteed to not matter. Communication is the *essence* of democracy.

Comment: @Shog9 Cool. Now I'm aware although I didn't want to. But I have no say in U.S. internal affairs anyways, how can you ask me to speak up?

Comment: @Shog9 imagine you'd tell us your salary and ask us to speak up about it so that your boss would raise it.

Comment: Perhaps you have friends in the US, or colleagues. Let them know. Perhaps you have neither, but can apply some of what's discussed here to your own situation. Sad though I would be if this situation in the US is nothing but an example of what to avoid for others, it would still serve a purpose.

Comment: @Abyx Think of what the consequences of the most powerful country regulating the internet (internally) would have on the rest of the world. This wont just affect the US.

Comment: @Shog9 Influence US citizens, I see. Look, I've already told some people from US that Trump is better than Hillary, and now you have Trump. How do you like such influence from foreign people?

Comment: @Shog9 they are speaking up. Apathy is a valid response.

Comment: @tuskiomi That's not an "apathy". It's a displeasure caused by ignorance and disrespect to non-US people.

Comment: @Abyx You think that this is ignorance, but he seems to know very clearly what he wants..

Comment: maybe they wanted Russian hackers to read the banner and do their usual magic to help Net Neutrality win

Answer (score 6):

**Why all giants coming together only for net-neutrality in US?**

If all the giants are coming together for this cause then why only target US? You guys have power to draw the potential of 90% of Internet users, then why only target it towards FCC (concerning only specific country)? Majority of these users will be non-US residents/citizen and will still have to fight for the net-neutrality separately in there own country with much less power, where all these tech giants won't even care to support/highlight the movement.

**Things going on around the world:**

Fight for this same cause has gained much momentum all round the world. For example, [this is what happened in India in the fight for net-neutrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_neutrality_in_India). You can also go and watch videos (majority of them in English) made by various online content creators to support the cause and educate people on how they can stop government form doing bad sending email.

I am sure just like here in India, many other countries have gone through this. Why didn't these same tech giants come together to change things there. Mind well netizens, here is one more US agenda movement where these same companies will go back inside their caves once their goal is achieved in just the US.

I would like to call upon all the people to share how citizens in their countries fought for net-neutrality and let the companies running because us know that their is a whole big world out there beyond US.

**Broaden the scope of this movement to each and every country and I will be the first one to stand there with you in the front to take the bullet.**

Comment: Individual power is all that counts here: a company with a million users speaks in there own selfish interest, but perhaps those users have insight of their own - were they to speak.

Answer (score 6):

If we allow any government intervention, it should be to ***support the free market system.***

If I go to the grocery store and they don't have a certain brand of milk that I want, then i will go to a different grocery store to get the milk. similarly, if my ISP won't let me watch netflix, then i'll go to a **different ISP.**

any government intervention should be to support the **anti-monopolization of ISPs**, instead of telling the ISPs what products they are required to offer

furthermore, if i start my own ISP and i want to block all porn content, or severely slow it down, **why should i not have this right?** if you want porn, then i would suspect that you do not want to be my customer. i'm not going to sue you for that.

**What If I want content from both ISP A and ISP B?**
The direct and rapid response to this would be the emergence of ISP aggregators, that will serve the exact content that we want, at the exact speed that we pay for.

**Why should I have to pay for porn to be streamed to millions of users, when I don't even use it?**

Comment: Suggesting that people go to a different ISP simply isn't possible for most people, as there tends to be too few ISPs serving a given location.  It's not a market that has the level of competition that grocery stores can provide.  It's also not something that can have meaningful competition.  It's extremely expensive to put the infrastructure in place to provide the service to an area; having multiple ISPs in an area means redundantly spending all of that capital; the free market will tend toward monopolies in such circumstances.  That's why utilities are regulated by governments.

Comment: fine, if you want gov regulation, get them to limit each ISP to 1m users max, then comcast will be broken into hundreds of companies, each serving a specific demographic, then you can have proxies on top of these ISPs that while maintaining subscriptions to them, will aggregate services and package them to be tailored exactly to what their customer wants. why should i pay for the millions of gigabytes of porn that is streamed by other users?

Comment: Making the companies smaller doesn't actually solve the problem, as they still have a monopoly in their region, and can therefore abuse their power in that region, giving the people that live/work there no options but to deal with it.  What you're paying for from your ISP is bandwidth, not the type of content that the bandwidth serves.  The porn company is paying for the bandwidth that they're using, just as the company showing children's cartoons is paying for theirs, and one shouldn't be charged more *for the same services* than the other just because you only use one of them.

Comment: When you live an apartment complexes that have deals with providers that limit you to one choice it can be impossible to switch to another provider.

Comment: Free marketing does not work with the internet.

Comment: @Servy - "Suggesting that people go to a different ISP simply isn't possible for most people" - actually a simple thing - if they do not have the option to switch provider restriction should not apply(besides tariff plan you choose). It is easy to prove are there options to switch provider or not.

Comment: @MolbOrg What restriction isn't going to apply when you can't switch providers?  You're saying that providers need to be net neutral if and only if they're the only provider for a location?

Comment: "if and only if" - I do not say that. I against NN and any regulations - the job of a provider for which I pay is to deliver me throughput according to the plan I pay for. However, it can be clearly seen and easy proven situation where concurrency between ISP's does not work and where they have a monopoly. The situation where the market does not work. And it rather would be better to address that issue. An ISP may pursue their policies to run the business more efficiently(freedom of ISP), but in monopoly situation, they should meet some quality standard(Protection of user).

Comment: @Servy With goals to create an incentive to increase the quality of service and fix local regulations. As for standards, which ones it is the question of discussion. There are different solutions for US situation. Their main problem is that they too sparse populated in some areas, and have too old infrastructure in other areas.

Comment: @MolbOrg The current restriction says that ISPs are required to treat all data submitted over their network equally, rather than treating different types of data differently.  There is currently a proposal to recend that, and allow ISPs to discriminate indiscriminately.  You say you're against NN, and then *in the same sentence*, say you expect your ISP to do what you pay for, namely to deliver your content at the specified throughput.  That's what NN is, it's requiring your ISP to simply deliver your data, and do nothing else.  And again, it's rare in the US to have many providers.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure what contradiction you are seeing: "You say you're against NN, and then in the same sentence, say you expect your ISP to do what you pay for, namely to deliver your content at the specified throughput. " - I want to be able to subscribe to an ISP that gives precedence to wordpress content over CNN, I am against the government shoving porn in my children's faces. I do not believe porn should be treated with the same preference as msdn articles.

Comment: And what if your ISP decides that porn should be given significant preference to other content (it's highly profitable after all, unlike MSDN).  You think it's more appropriate that a single corporation have *complete* control over what you have access to through the internet than the government saying that *no one* should have *any* control over what content you can access?  Sure if you had access to hundreds of ISPs, you could find one that offers what you want, but people don't have choice.  They have one, maybe two, companies to choose from.

Comment: if my ISP decides that porn is more important, then i'm sure there will be plenty of people like myself that will create the demand for a different provider. the government can say what ever they want, but in the end you are allowing the government to make decisions for you, and i'm sure you know that they have an agenda, as well as their own definitions of what porn is and what your children should be learning in school

Comment: People have been entirely unsatisfied with their ISPs, and demanding major changes, for *years*.  Notice how much competition that complete lack of user satisfaction has generated?  Basically none.  It takes an *enormous* amount of money to get into the business, and there are many other barriers to entry besides just money, and for anyone that does manage it, there is so little competition that there's no actual incentive to actually do a good job, because you won't have other competitors.

Comment: As for the government making decisions for us, the only decision that they're making here is that *no one is allowed to make decisions for you* as to what content you consume.  If you actually have a problem with other people (whether it be the government, or me, or anyone else) what you can consume, then *you should support that*.  **You** are the one advocating that others should have a say in what you can consume, and that you don't *want* to have the freedom to decide for yourself.

Answer (score 6):

I thought I'd just say this: being in New Zealand, the Great American Net Neutrality Debate seems to be a symptom of a far bigger issue with infrastructure, regulation, and competition. In short, the NZ consensus is:

`Its pretty much a non issue here because our system isnt sh*t`

https://www.reddit.com/r/newzealand/comments/6cffdy/net_neutrality_in_nz/

While you're lobbying for net neutrality, you could also try to get your local loops unbundled properly (NZ did this in 2003) to bring prices down and improve competition and service:

https://www.quora.com/Why-is-there-no-Local-loop-unbundling-in-the-USA

https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2014/06/we-dont-need-net-neutrality-we-need-competition/

By the way, most of NZ has fibre now thanks to a public-private partnership. Result: insanely fast internet for everyone and overall benefits for the economy. Maybe you could also lobby for that too.

In short, blazingly fast internet, the ability to choose from a myriad of ISPs, investment in infrastructure, and robust competition (and a government competition watchdog that jumps on anything that even smells like anti-competitiveness) seem to obviate this issue. Maybe I've totally got the wrong end of the stick but that's how it seems to me.

Comment: underrated advice.

Answer (score 5):

IMO the whole net neutrality thing is a band-aid for a bigger problem.

The real problem is vertical integration. Last-mile communications to homes and small buisnesses is a natural monoploy. When last-mile communications service is vertically integrated with ISP service the ISPs can get away with treating their customers like shit.

Furthermore in some cases the last mile access providers are integrated with tier 1 transit providers. Tier 1 providers don't have to buy any transit and hence have little motivation to set up any new peering.

I think the fears of this affecting foriegners access to american websites are largely unfounded. Hosting is a much more competitive market incentivising the providers to treat their customers well. Hosting providers in turn have a wide spectrum of transit providers to choose from for their international connectivity needs.

Comment: Well, yes. This is very much the larger problem, and NN is at best an attempt to stop the bleeding but is unlikely to heal the greater wound. It would therefore be preferable to keep the bandage intact and seek to address this lack of competition, these incestuous business relationships... Rather than ripping the bandage away while claiming loudly that there would be no wound but for its dressing.

Answer (score 5):

> So let's hear it: why should or shouldn't we all head over to
>   https://www.battleforthenet.com/ right now and use the handy form to
>   send a letter to the FCC?

An aspect of this question which I've not seen or heard discussed is the right-of-way that was granted decades ago (in the US) to private companies (phone company, electric company) to run wire through municipalities on utility poles and from there to houses and apartment buildings.

Maybe someone here knows the legalities? Is there anything local municipalities can do, vis-a-vis that legal right-of-way that was granted decades ago, to demand that those who have the right-of-way not restrict content or favor the content of one content-provider over another?  Is there some federal law governing the terms and conditions of that right-of-way, or is it still subject to state and local law?

Comment: Broadly (because I don't remember the details right now) a few municipalities have tried to run their own pipes and ISPs, and have been fought tooth and nail by the existing providers (AT&T and Comcast spring to mind), who got the state lawmakers involved to try to quash it. I believe there was a case of this in Tennesse two years ago. Ars Technica should have something about it.

Comment: That is where the real fight is and we need to prevent these companies from obtaining local monopolies.  If they don't have these monopolies and leverage at the local level, they surely won't have it at the federal level.

Comment: In my municipality, it is a duopoly on the utility pole: cable company and phone company (if we don't include the copper wire for electricity, which isn't used for broadband here).  Any competing ISP that needs a wire (or fiber) must piggyback on one of the two that are already on the utility poles.

Comment: I am interested in knowing if there is any legal leverage those old right-of-way agreements might offer. Did they give the right-of-way holder carte blanche, or were there some restrictions?

Comment: I'm sure it varies by location.

Comment: Ars article about the Tennessee situation: https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2016/03/tennessee-kills-muni-broadband-expansion-bill-after-att-opposition/

Answer (score 4):

What exactly are you going to do in the Day of Action, July 12?

Will you have a special system wide banner with some message?

Will you shut down SE for a day as sign of protest, so that the authorities will notice?

"Day of Action" sounds good and promising, but I really have no idea what is really behind this, so getting more details of what will actually happen will be nice.

<sub><sup>(I was going to post this as comment on the blog post, but you closed it for comments after getting whole two comments, which makes tons of sense.)</sup></sub>

Comment: Meant to redirect comments here from the start, didn't get it right. Disqus is bad. Thinking dismissible banner pointing at the blog.

Comment: Thanks @Shog agree Disqus is bad, but that's what being used in the blog. Dismissable banner sounds fine, cheers! :)

Comment: Good reason *not* to use blog comments at all then, eh? At least, not when discussion is actually important. Look at the folks here who've spent serious time researching their answers; you think that'd happen on a disqus thread? More importantly, even if someone did... It'd quickly get buried under a mountain of gab.

Answer (score 3):

I hope it's okay to use this to ask questions to learn more about net neutrality here.

A common concern I hear about net neutrality that I haven't heard properly address, is that it may make it more difficult for new ISPs to enter the market, making the monopolies stronger. This seems analogous to a lot of regulations I've seen intended to regulate big players, but ultimately being ineffective to address the core issue, monopolies. Does net neutrality do anything to reduce the monopolization of ISPs?

Comment: No, the idea of net neutrality is to address the fact that ISPs are a natural monopoly.  The idea is that since having proper competition isn't practical or reasonable (as is the case for many utilities in general, due to the infrastructure costs) the best option is to have regulations in place to prevent the monopolies from abusing their position.

Comment: @Servy It may be difficult to break into the market, but not impossible or unheard of. Preventing monopolies from abusing their position is much more difficult. Increased competition is often more effective. I would like to know how net neutrality would change the equation for trying to break into the market.

Comment: It's not impossible for a new ISP to be created, however because the physical infrastructure is so expensive, it takes an absurd amount of capital to go around and actually provide redundant physical connections to an entire area in order to compete with another ISP in that area.  And in the cases where that *does* happen, one is generally going to run the other out of business (at least in that area) and force them out.  Physical utilities are a *natural* monopoly this way, in that free market forces will push a given region closer and closer to a monopoly over time.

Comment: As mentioned, the purpose of net neutrality is not to prevent there from being monopolies, or to make it easier for a ISP to be created; it's to attempt to deal with the fact that monopolies are a reality, and to prevent (certain) abuses from those monopolies.  While it's not always easy to regulate monopolies, in cases of natural monopolies (in particular, utilities like power, water, phone, and internet) that tends to be the only practical option.  In markets that don't have inherent natural monopolies, you're quite right that breaking up the monopolies tends to be easier and more effective.

Answer (score 3):

Every citizen in his right mind who understands what is going on should be Standing Up for Net Neutrality and Defending the Internet from being Piratized (more fitting term than Privatized).

The Internet was built using our (USA) tax dollars.  Now we have ethically challenged corporations and their lapdog corrupt politicians trying to claim it as their private domain and figure out ways to charge us ever more for using it.  This is their modus operandi, socialize the risks, piratize the gains.

The Internet either belongs to no one or belongs to everyone.  It is a public resource and belongs in the public domain.

Should we allow private companies to facilitate Internet Access, Yes.

Should we allow private companies to monopolize local Internet access, **No**, it's not theirs.

There are costs to run the Internet, but [why are American paying so much more for less bandwidth?](http://www.pbs.org/newshour/updates/internet-u-s-compare-globally-hint-slower-expensive/)

Easy, because we don't have [competitive options](https://www.theverge.com/2015/4/1/8321437/maps-show-why-internet-is-more-expensive-us-europe-competition) for Internet Access at the local level.  We don't have competition because private companies claim ownership of the network of optical fibers, coaxial cables, twisted-pair telephone wires, and yes even in some cases [wireless spectrum rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_Act_of_1996) that are necessary for [physical layer access](https://www.lifewire.com/layers-of-the-osi-model-illustrated-818017) to the network.

Other countries typically don't have this hodgepodge of private interests laying claim to sectors of a public network.  The telecommunications networks, postal service, Internet are all public and run by the government or public non-profit organization typically called the PTT.

[This article](http://www.lowtechmagazine.com/2015/10/how-to-build-a-low-tech-internet.html) outlines some solutions on cost-effective Internet Access, both in rural and urban areas.  The key is creating options for Internet access to break the ISP monopolies.  This would include both technology methods and preventing the municipalities from granting monopolies, and rolling back local laws and ordinances that granted the monopolies.  It would include rolling back state and local laws that allows private companies to claim ownership of the network infrastructure mentioned.  These should be owned by the municipality and all citizens in the municipality should have equal right to connect, upload, and download.

Free wifi networks set up by the townships and schools should be encouraged.

While we should all be contacting our congress legislators and the FCC to protect Net Neutrality, our greater effort and fight is at our municipalities and townships.  We must keep in mind that while most of us are too busy with our personal lives to follow Internet Access legislation at the state and local level, this is not the case with industry lobbyists like [ALEC](http://www.alecexposed.org/) (American Legislative Exchange Council) that are dealing with our state and local politicians full time to push through legislation that benefits the ISPs but to our detriment.

If we can take back access to the Internet at the local level, the private interests will have much more difficulty in corrupting net neutrality.  They are doing this now because they can.

Answer (score 3):

> Special thanks to Jon Chan for whipping up a dismissible banner for this, so we didn't get stuck abusing system messages for it.

Feedback for the future: the banner was dismissible on a per-site basis. That meant that anyone who uses several sites had to dismiss it several times. I started to get annoyed at that design about the third time I dismissed the banner. You use network-wide cookies for other things such as authentication or advertising: why not for this?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298260/dismissing-the-net-neutrality-banner-on-one-site-should-dismiss-it-on-all-sites.

Answer (score 2):

Very good points made by Sagar V in his answer about India and how net neutrality came into focus in India.

I don't understand why such companies act in a way that leads towards destruction of net neutrality? Surely, they have got intellectuals who are as much aware as anyone here about the consequences of such schemes/acts.

This should be opposed at all the corporate levels from where such ideas emerge about compromising net neutrality.

Or do these intellectuals just don't care and want to maximize profits at any cost?

Comment: The last paragraph, unfortunately. **Power corrupts.**

Answer (score 2):

**Why should I care about net neutrality if I can't watch Netflix from my country?**

I seems to me that the ISPs want to make their business model somewhat similar to how courier companies work today. Basically they have different prices depending on how quickly you want to receive the packages. Only those that pay for premium services get the merchandise they want to be shipped to their home quickly. Thus, it's the end user whom ends up paying those costs instead of the merchant.

If one sees companies like Netflix as merchants of multimedia content, where only those that pay for a premium service can enjoy those contents at their full capacity of service. The only difference that I see with how courier companies work is that the ISPs currently don't receive a cut of the profit Netflix makes for delivering premium services.

Even more, why should I care if I can't even watch Netflix, Hulu, or HBO Go from my country.

Comment: That's **exactly** why net neutrality needs to be implemented: so that you _can_ watch Netflix, etc.

Comment: That is a Netflix decision because of the licenses they have to pay to provide the service.  It is not an Internet deficiency.  Leave my Internet alone.  Try Amazon Prime or hulu, or crackle or whatever.  But the NET ITSELF SHOULDN'T CARE WHAT IS BEING TRANSMITTED OVER IT.

Comment: You say "Only those that pay for premium services get the merchandise they want to be shipped to their home quickly. Thus, it's the end user whom ends up paying those costs instead of the merchant." but I don't think that is how this works. It would be the Merchant who has to pay to be on even ground with competitors under the new rules. What your describing is how it is now. I can buy a better internet service to get things here faster. What people are worried about is that the burden is shifting onto website as ISPs begin to pick favorites, and small companies could not field the cost.

Comment: @rp.beltran Yes, I'm describing how things work at this moment. If things change, small business would have to pay a higher barrier to entry, but those costs would be passed to the end user anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Glad to see SE is standing up for this. It's a nonpartisan issue which needs everyone's support.

Answer (score 1):

We need to present the pros in a public forum where non-technical people will see it and understand the advantages (and if any, the disadvantages) of net neutrality. Something like MYC's [The FCC Should Pass Laws To Preserve Net Neutrality](https://makeyourcase.org/topic/the-fcc-should-pass-laws-to-preserve-net-neutrality), but with more exposure and a little TLC on the site. With exposure to the point that the press will see and raise awareness, and have a prioritized list of pros to draw from like that site to make the case to politicians.

Comment: "if any", lol. Maybe read some of the other answers on this page.

Comment: @BVernon - I did read some others, so allowed for the fact that not everyone shares SO's view on this.

Answer (score 0):

What can we do?
The most visible thing we can do is have clear tracking of those people in charge who depend on the public's votes. If a well informed public is able to identify individuals they have the power to keep in/out of office, no amount of funding from another source will allow them to keep such a position of power.

Comment: One issue with this is that the members of the FCC making this decision are appointed, not elected.

Answer (score 0):

I foresee that ISPs will work directly with Content Providers to maximize their profits. Businesses will do whatever it takes to make their money, if necessary the Content Providers may take over the ISPs as well. All these will happen with or without net neutrality.

Answer (score -1):

I'm against net neutrality and luckily meta points don't matter that much as I know I will get downvoted. The problem isn't neutrality, the problem is granted monopolies, formal cartelization, over regulation, and lack of competition. You pay for electricity, you pay for water, why not pay for bandwidth? "Oh but bandwidth is too cheap!" That doesn't matter, AWS charges fractions of cents, but it does add up. Water is underpriced too - that's why we have shortages! If you don't like your ISP blocking something, just switch service providers!

For a quick lesson on the nature of competition, read this article. But before you do, answer this question: How many electric light companies do you think were operating in New York City around 1890? How many gas companies were operating in Baltimore around that time?

https://mises.org/library/myth-natural-monopoly

When you refactor something, you don't go breaking it further, you work towards the real solution, which is increase competition. Even [Somalia has the best telecommunications in Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_in_Somalia).

> Somalia now offers some of the most technologically advanced and competitively priced telecommunications and internet services in the world.[2] Funded by Somali entrepreneurs and backed by expertise from China, Korea and Europe, these nascent telecommunications firms offer affordable mobile phone and internet services that are not available in many other parts of the continent... these firms now offer the cheapest and clearest phone calls in Africa.[3] These Somali telecommunication companies also provide services to every city, town and hamlet in Somalia. There are presently around 25 mainlines per 1,000 persons, and the local availability of telephone lines (tele-density) is higher than in neighboring countries; three times greater than in adjacent Ethiopia.[4]

Comment: Your argument is predicated on a fundamental misperception: that there is actually competition for ISPs.  In reality, most places have at most **two** ISPs, and they're big conglomerates who will work in tandem to maximize profits, competition be damned.

Comment: False! There are 1-2 cable companies, maybe a fiber company, 3-4 cell data companies, 1-2 satellite companies, a few dozen dial-up services, and maybe an ISDN or T1 company. Example: NYC Staten Island: TimeWarner cable, Verizon FIOS, T-Mobile data, Verizon data, Sprint data, AT&T data, Hughes satellite, Dish satellite, Verizon ISDN, other lesser nationwide dial-up services.

Comment: Oh, really?  Care to link to an area that has that level of competition?

Comment: hrrrmmmm @Chloe... while indeed, at present, this concerns the USA net neutrality, this is a much larger issue. If this precedent is made, other countries will follow in the tracks, and it's pretty egocentrist (also.. misguided) to assume that every country in the world has such quantity of providers. Where I live, we don't. Two of them, actually owns every smaller ones. Really. Also, you actually might want to verify that all those you mention, are not owned by larger ones.

Comment: You must live in a city with that kind of competition. I do not. I live in that vast swath of land commonly called "fly over country". I have one cable provider, who also provides my phone service. I have a satellite provider, but they can't be classified as broadband because they don't meet the FCCs rules for that classification. There is no fiber here. I have, effectively, one choice if I want to do anything other than load text pages.

Comment: I'm actually holding out hope that mobile broadband is able to become competitive with wired sooner rather than later; I went a couple of months with only a mobile connection about 15 years ago, and it was horrific but things have gotten significantly better since then - the biggest roadblock now is data-caps, which are a real hardship if, for example, you work with large data-sets. Regardless, "wouldn't it be nicer" doesn't solve immediate problems; you can remove rules once there's adequate competition to enact them implicitly.

Comment: @Chloe, I wish.  The company I work for has decidedly sub-par Internet speeds.  A year ago, this became critical enough that we contacted every company providing Internet service in the area (all four of them).  Comcast wouldn't provide business-class service because our office is in an area they classify as "residential", the two wireless ISPs couldn't get a signal, and the phone company is the one selling us our current over-priced, under-speed service.  Competition?  Ha.

Comment: @Shog9 removing rules is a whole heck of a lot harder than adding them, as we are currently experiencing.  I would tend to reverse the argument: we can always add rules later.

Comment: As a broad observation, that rings true @Ben. In this particular context... We've seen it before. The removal of line-sharing rules for DSL in 2003-4 arguably set the stage for the current situation by eliminating a wealth of competition in the ISP market; predicated on the hope that it would spur renewed vigor among telco operators, it instead marked the start of a long decline in DSL, a tough race hamstrung by consolidation and cost-cutting. History shows that a 5-member board can *and does* react much more readily to current trends than large governing bodies - a double edge sword indeed.

Comment: Eh... even when there are a few options for providers, I don't think we can say that a dial-up service *meaningfully* competes with, say, FIOS in any way.

Comment: I'm in agreement with your fundamental statement, Chloe.  Granted monopolies being the worst offender.  Our 'deduplication of services' mandated by the FCC has crippled ISP competition.  Most of us, if we want competent internet these days, MUST go with the only cable or fiber provider in the area (as mandated by the FCC), and just live with their decisions on who gets priority and who doesn't.  Like most other regulation, net neutrality will bring us worse internet for more money.

Answer (score -1):

My answer is really simple:

**The network is the network.  It should not be tampered with.  It is layer 1 - the transport.  It works, so don't fix it.**

If a company like Netflix pays to install caching servers at ISP sites all around then that is just the way it works.  Anybody should be allowed to do that.  I'm glad they do.

**But as for layer 1, the transportation medium, my message is easy and clear:**

**HANDS OFF**

Shut up about QoS as a reason to mess with the network.  Look at how Netflix does it.  It costs them money but gives us all better service.  Having a closer server provides a better QoS.  It does not require messing with the transport medium at all.

**Leave the Internet alone.  It works.**

---

**The ISPs should be regulated like other carriers like the phone companies.**  Monopolies should be broken up, for instance.  5G is about to bring total convergence anyway, so we need to be ready for that part.  But this has nothing to do with actual net neutrality, hence the FCC's position.

Comment: Except there are very few (and in many cases) no other carriers to choose from so your argument is flawed. In my area, I have 1 option. And that is Optimum Online. I cant choose Fios, or Google Fiber, or Time Warner Cable, or any other provider. I'd be forced to move. Now if optimum starts to throttle my speed, then my option is to move? That's a bad ultimatum. You argument holds if we had the option of choosing a provider like we have the option of choosing what kind of car we want to buy. But that's now how it works unfortunately.

Comment: +1 to everything @Javia1492 said. The ISP industry is not one that lends itself well to competition, so many of us can't "simply switch to a different carrier." Your argument also ignores the impact the "hands off" approach would have on small businesses, who could be left in the lurch by ISPs prioritizing bigger, higher-paying companies.

Answer (score -3):

I would love to see an international authority of some sort that can block such bills disregarding the local laws in the country which makes these. The EU (as burouchratic and heavy-weight it is when it comes to decision making) is a nice example for a possible solution. The moment your government (that is part of the EU) starts producing bills that hinder the rights of its citizens (including but not only Internet freedom, freedom of speech, religion, market etc.), a procedure is triggered, funding is reduced or stopped depending on the severity.

The US government tries to push such bills every couple of years. The problem is that such changes affect not only its citizens but also everyone else around the world. But even if it was just a restriction to the rights of its citizens, it would still be an example of malpractice when it comes to law making.

Comment: Hmm. Problem: The US federal government *is* exactly such a government in almost every possible way. (Or were you not aware that it was formed out of a coalition of sovereign, independent states?) It even has the extra boost of having a relatively cohesive population and something vaguely resembling a long history to motivate cooperation. Sad that it is, in the US, the main source of exactly the sorts of laws you decry, just exactly the way your proposed international government would grow to create *still yet even more* terrible laws.

Comment: The states are part of the same country. As for "international government creating yet even more terrible laws" I am not talking about creating laws at all. I am talking about *blocking* laws that are deemed too restrictive. ISO is a fine example of an international NON-governmental organization. Even if we look at the "Restoring Internet freedom" from just a technical point of view there is still enough to throw it away.

Comment: The United States were, as the name implies, originally independent countries banded together in a loose confederacy that over time developed into something much stronger. Those who do not know history are doomed to repeat it, and those who do not know that the US federal government was originally designed to be an extremely minimalistic framework to handle a very limited set of tasks that then somehow metastasized into its present form will simply design other extremely minimal frameworks that "will do just this one thing, we promise!" Definitely for sure this time! Yes!

Comment: The *were* in *US were originally independent countries* is a keyword here. You are missing my point. I'm not talking about some world government but an organization that just like ISO controls very specific aspects that concern all of its members and even outside the organization's structure around the world and not just the interests of the government of a specific country. Please learn more about how ISO works and then you (hope so) will understand what I mean.

Answer (score -3):

There are a lot of legitimate reasons for rolling back Net Neutrality that are overlooked here. If you "really" want to understand the issue from both sides then the article below is a good read to better understand some of the cons of NN (that is, not the cons of the concept itself, but of letting the FCC enforce it).

Normally I wouldn't just copy a link to an answer like this... but given the nature of this forum I don't see any reason to copy the text of this article here when it's formatted much better on the site.

http://www.breitbart.com/big-government/2015/02/25/net-neutrality-is-a-problem-not-a-solution/

Comment: So that's an article from a little while ago about what the author thinks is going to happen when the regulations are put in place, as was written just before they were put in place.  They've now been put in place for a while now.  Do you have any evidence to suggest that what that author predicts would happen has actually happened?  (Also the author states *what* they think will happen without so much as mentioning why they think it will happen, but since the regulation has been out for a while we no longer need to theorize as to what might happen, we can observe what has happened.)

Comment: @Servy There was actually a great article I found when I originally wrote that answer pointing out several abuses that had happened... innovative ideas actually intended to help customers were deemed violations of the rules and lawsuits were opened. I also read about issues where the FCC went after companies for violating privacy... yet the FCC doesn't actually have clear rules written (or at least not at the time... dunno if that's changed) around this subject like the FTC did.

Comment: @Servy The fact you're asking me this shows you didn't look very hard... the heritage website, for example, has numerous articles on the subject. Forbes has some as well, and some other sources. Honestly, at this point the rules are getting rolled back and there's nothing we can do about it. If you care to have a better understanding you can go research some more. If not, then you can complain at me for not citing more sources I guess.

Comment: If finding relevant sources that contain facts about what the law *actually* does, rather than theories as to what it *might* do, why didn't you post them from the start?  You're telling me that you cited a low quality resource that doesn't back up it's assertions because I could go out and find *actual* sources with *real* evidence behind their assertions if I wanted to.  So in effect you're telling me to prove your point for you because you can't be bothered to cite the sources that you think are easy to find?

Comment: @Servy I'd say they are reasonably easy to find. But obviously it take more than 2 seconds or I would do it for you. So I'm saying that if you are passionate about this subject and want to know the truth then you can look them up... but I don't care enough to do it for you because it's not going to change the outcome and I've got better things to do.

Comment: Again, if it's easy to find sources that actually prove what you're claiming, then why did you choose to cite a source that doesn't actually demonstrate anything, instead of one that does.  It's not *my* job to prove your point for you.  It's not *my* responsibility to support you doing your own research and actually supporting your own (very radical) claims for you, which you have chosen to not do on my behalf.  If you want to made radical claims, you need to support them, rather than making wild claims and saying other people are obligated to research them for you.

Comment: @Servy I never said you were obligated to research anything. Just because I make a claim and don't show sources for 100% of everything I say doesn't mean my claim isn't true, but if you want to assume everything you read is false if you have to research it yourself then you are free to do so.

Answer (score -4):

Who wants to really fight for net neutrality - should we not pay our bills, cancel ISP services, stop going to movies, listen to music. Sabotage these companies and services so they themselves vote for net neutrality?

Comment: The fight is to make sure that multiple people don't pay for the same bandwidth usage. For example you paying comcast for your internet and netflix also paying comcast so that you can get their service at a reasonable speed. Netflix should not have to pay their provider and their customers provider in order to ensure good service.

Answer (score -5):

I'm not going to "stand up" nor am I going to "raise my voice" - what the hell do they mean anyway?

First of all, as a technophile kind of guy, my first concern is, "is this a technical issue?" if it is, then good, solve it at a purely technological level and be done with it.

If not, I ask the 2nd question: who has the rights to the property involved? If they are government operated and run then the FCC can regulate the heck out of it for all I care, if they are private then I'm completely against FCC doing anything. The roads to hell are all build with one noble intention after another paved with naivety and a complete lack of insights and meticulousness and prudence. Just because you make your cause sound good and "hip" (stand up? You are implying we are all down on our knees shivering in fear like a coward?) doesn't automatically guarantee that it DOES GOOD.

And as far as I know, the whole matter comes down to throttling bandwidth, no service provider in their right mind will be stupid enough to deliberately block certain sites. That means A. you are giving your competition a leg up and all your competition has to do is to do... well, nothing. and B. it means service providers looking into the contents which you are transmitting over the internet, it costs money and labor to get that done and it's counterproductive. The best thing they can do is to manage traffic based on destination, which can easily be circumvented.

At worst, your visiting Salon.com will be significantly slower than before, while visiting Amazon.com will be as slower as usual. None of which can't be solved by paying a tad bit more on purchasing better packages.

Like I said, I'm not going to "stand up" nor am I going to "raise my voice", we are living in an age of a sickening anti-intellectual trends where slogans and empty, shallow, superficial activism like "Women's March" absolutely champions over cool-headed, careful and prudent logical reasoning. Say what you want, I wish not to be a part of that. I have a valuable asset which weighs a good 4 pounds and it took a good 8 million years for it to came to be. I intend to use it as much and often as I can.

Keep your WWJD armband to yourself.

Comment: "your competition" There _is_ no competition.

Comment: `no service provider in their right mind will be stupid enough to deliberately block certain sites` They've *already done it*.  That's why there was such a strong push to put the existing regulations in the first place.  It wasn't out of a fear that the ISPs *might* start doing this, it was because *they actually did it*.  So apparently the ISPs *aren't* in their right mind.  That, or, as mentioned, there simply is no competition, so they know that consumers can't do a thing about it when they do things like this.

Comment: `if they are private then I'm completely against FCC doing anything.` The government regulates what happens with private property all the time -- the FTC, for example, or the ATF, DEA, FAA, etc.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion as much as the next guy, but what about someone with a startup who can't afford to pay his ISP as much as an Amazon or Google? The ISP would be free to throttle traffic to/from his site(s) at will, in favor of higher-paying domains.

Comment: @Matt Cox Half way into your post you mention competition of providers.... except as Josh Caswell pointed out, there is no competition. So all your "i will not raise my voice", this and that hodgepodge is absolute crap. There is a massive monopolization of the internet in the US, with 2 or 3 major ISPs. Put down the waffle and get your facts straight. Cant fix stupid.

Comment: @Josh Caswell No Competition? Good. Make it an anti-trust case, don't try to spin it into some sort of freedom of speech and bill of rights issue. Cause it isn't.

Comment: @Servy  Which sites are we talking about here? And is it a ban based on IP? Can't people just use VPN or Proxy? Can't people swtich ISPs? What are the news reports? From creditable sources?

Comment: @freginold Because you smoke weed, you don't mind going down the drains and pick up meth right? How's your private property being regulated? It didn't happen to you, at least not to the extend that you can no longer ignore it right? Therefore you are happy? How much tax do you pay? How much of the tax you paid went to where you wanted?

Comment: @Javia1492  All the ISPs formed up some sort of alliance to block certain sites? The same set of sites? Please provide the creditable evidence. And how that cannot be circumvented via using VPN or proxy? What did those sites do to get on the radar like that? What you said is outright laughable. And other than a lack of economic incentive, what stops another billionaire from becoming ISP#4? Maybe it's because most RATIONAL consumers don't think it's a big deal? You are right, I can't fix your stupidity, but I can try to fix your ignorance on economics.

Comment: @MattCox What "partisan crap" are you talking about? A lack of net neutrality affecting small businesses is not a party-line issue. As for `Um Virgin Islands? Hong Kong?`... do you not understand how a company located there would still need to go through US-based ISPs to access US-based customers?

Comment: @MattCox The most famous example is the case of Netflix, where comcast dramatically throttled all traffic from Netflix to their customers until Netflix paid them a whole bunch of money to stop doing it.  You could throttle the traffic by IP, DNS, or any other criteria you would so choose.  If people start using proxies for everything then the providers will start putting pressure on those proxies, throttling or simply not serving them.  People can't just switch ISPs because there is typically one, or possibly two, for any given location.

Comment: @MattCox `How's your private property being regulated?` Are you kidding? Ever heard of zoning laws? How about legal purchase age? Gun carry laws? Vehicle emissions regulations? Any of these ring a bell?

Comment: @MattCox So i have to use a VPN or a proxy to go to a website using a service I am paying for? Very good logic. Nobody knows which sites would be blocked, however, if you also assume nothing will change, you're pretty naive. So.. the reason another billionaire hasnt become ISP#4 is because most rational consumers dont think its a big deal...? The relation between a billion to rational consumers has no connection. Rational consumers dont have a choice here. Please, continue to "educate" me with your apples and oranges logic.

Comment: @MattCox `Make it an anti-trust case`... A lack of competition is not necessarily indicative of an anti-trust issue.  Specifically in this case, there are other reasons for lack of competition.  You should read up on the issue before trying to shout down other people's viewpoints.

Comment: @freginold  why yes I do. Pay your goddam premium, play nice and don't do something to piss off the ISPs. Simple as that. Be farseeing and don't count on making a fortune in the US Market, if you are a "small" business. Or simply be advantageous enough that your user base would rather pay to visit your site, either on extra bandwidth or a VPN.

Comment: @MattCox It's not as simple as that. Your dismissive attitude and lack of insight on this subject are indicators that either (1) you don't care very much about it -- in which case you must be very bored to keep commenting -- or (2) you don't handle being disagreed with very well.  If it's the second option, you should spend some time learning more about the subject before taking such an aggressive stand.

Answer (score -6):

It's pretty clear that Net Neutrality is about companies vs customers. On the one hand, you have effective monopolies who want power to screw over their customers. On the other, you have choice-less customers. You could decide that having monopolies screw over their customers endlessly is just fine, or you could decide that maybe you should do something about that.

In any case, although I think that you have to be either incredibly stupid or tremendously bad faith to be against Net Neutrality, I already have substantially more powerful net neutrality regulations in my country, an abundance of ISPs offering ever better speeds for ever lower prices, and a glut of competition.

The only thing I can suggest, since I am not American and therefore cannot participate in the regulatory process, is that Stack Exchange move their servers from the United States. For the Day of Action, simply shut down all US servers and force your users to access the website through foreign servers (ideally also shut down Canadian servers since they might provide an acceptable experience). This should provide them with an adequate taste of what their experience will be like.

Comment: "I think that you have to be either incredibly stupid or tremendously bad faith to be against Net Neutrality"

This is a disappointing sentiment.  Reasonable and honest people can disagree about a _very_ broad array of topics, not least of all this one.

Comment: Which is your country?

Comment: `simply shut down all US servers and force your users to access the website through foreign servers` = I don't think that is simple as it sounds (and even if it is easy) I don't think this is the right approach because (as far I understand) is ISP's problem, not Stack Exchange.

Comment: @BenCollins: Reasonable and honest people *can* disagree about a very broad array of topics, but there are plenty of topics they *don't* disagree about, for instance, murdering other people is probably bad, the Earth is ~4.5billion years old, and evolution happens. There is no rational case for being anti net neutrality.

Comment: @cat United Kingdom. We have a great ISP market.

Comment: While hosting servers in the UK solves the problem of people connecting who don't have to cross US networks, it does not solve it for everyone else.

Comment: I am in favor of Net Neutrality, but agree with @BenCollins and in particular I think you do yourself no favors by demonizing your opposition.  After all, *"you have to be either incredibly stupid or incredibly bad faith to **resort to ad hominem arguments**."*  Also, the picture is NOT black and white as you paint it; this is a classic case of FCC overreach even if we happen to like the results *this* time.  See the section "Good, Bad and Ugly" in [this excellent *bilateral* article on the subject](http://www.freedommag.org/issue/201506-net-freedom/a-tangled-web.html).

Comment: @DeadMG: I'm not aware of any dispute about the legitimacy of murder, except among stone-age tribes that just got in touch with civilization. But the other two examples are unfortunate; the middle one *is* debated by people who are making a plausible effort to be rational and who are not blatant frauds, and the third one is ambiguous, and only one of its possibilities is really indisputable. So it really sounds as though you are willing to paint anyone you disagree with strongly enough as irrational or dishonest, based not on **showing** them to be irrational or dishonest, but on disagreeing.

Comment: The middle one may be debated by honest people, but not honest *and* reasonable people. The last one is neither ambiguous nor disputable.

Comment: As for demonizing the other side, it's hard not to demonize people who paint their skin red, wear horns, eat babies, and have no rational motivation for doing so but do it just because they think the world should work that way.

Comment: @DeadMG: How fortunate are Science and Internet Freedom to be defended by close-mindedness and insults! I would be interested to know what, in this analogy of demonization, "eating babies" actually refers to. Or indeed what dressing up like demons would represent — the only logical possibility would seem to be opponents of evolution who take pride in calling themselves irrational or dishonest, but the world seems to be fresh out of those. Barring an explanation for why those particular insulting characterizations were described, I think the "argument" can be dismissed.

Comment: "either incredibly stupid or tremendously bad faith"  I'm pretty smart, so it stands to reason that I have precisely zero faith that the FCC can handle net neutrality regulation with care and responsibility.

Comment: `It's pretty clear that Net Neutrality is about companies vs customers.` I don't think that's true. Plenty of companies have come out *in favor of* net neutrality. It may be more accurate to say it's about **ISP companies** vs customers.

Comment: Downvoted because of the ad hominems. Net Neutrality as a concept is something that most of us agree with, including the "detractors". (Though I'm also open to be corrected on this.) "Net Neutrality" as referring to the regulations of the FCC is something else, which has many complicated issues that honest and reasonable people are trying to point out. It is also something that you, being in the UK, do not have, though you may have some form of regulations designed to enforce the concept, they are probably nothing like the FCC's version.

Comment: They don't need to move their servers.  They should do like Netflix and have caching servers near you to improve service.  But the net itself is fine.  Leave it alone.

Answer (score -6):

I have to admit a lot of my viewpoints are clouded by listening to the No Agenda show on the way to work.   But I'm not a democrat or a republican, just a contrarian so I have to respectfully disagree that we should ever ask the Federal government to pass any laws respecting business, entertainment, health care and education as a matter of principle.

I've had the same dumb DSL modem for 11 years and have done just fine with it.  There are no shows I can't watch on Roku, no websites I can't visit and I frequently work from home with several remote desktop and putty sessions running concurrently over a VPN.

I live in a rural community and utilize a universally reviled ISP - I should care about this, but I don't.  So personally, I guess I don't care because I don't think my situation is going to get worse or better.

---

The arguments I've gleaned from Adam and John on No Agenda are as follows, and you can take them or leave them, but they might as well be presented and discussed so I can know better whether they're just full of hot air.

1. There are certain things that *should* receive priority, namely doctors performing surgery over the Internet.   http://naplay.it/928/2-06-00
2. There have frequently been provisions about legal and lawful content (legal and lawful are [apparently two different things](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-legal-and-vs-lawful/))
3. Loosely interpreted, regulating content for its lawfulness could lead to massive amounts of censorship, take downs for perceived hate speech and licensing for Blogs and Podcasts.
4. Strictly interpreted, regulating content for its lawfulness still means relying on ISPs to do meta-data analysis which is still an invasion of privacy.

Use: https://search.nashownotes.com/  to find some info, it's hard to point links straight to the content, but there's a lot of articles (and the text of many bills).

Comment: Why is it that you don't think your situation will get any worse or better? What exactly does having a "dumb DSL modem" have to do with Net Neutrality? It sounds like your setup is pretty effective; if only everyone's was so good. Also, this sentiment that the federal government shouldn't pass laws respecting the public sector explains why you are neither Republican or Democrat. In fact, you are a Libertarian. And frankly, the broadness of the statement strikes me as utterly absurd. The government shouldn't have *any* laws regarding business or education? What laws should the government have?

Comment: You lost me at surgery.

Comment: @AndrasDeak sorry, specifically, I meant surgery performed over the Internet.  That might be a strawman argument though, I've got no idea if things like that exist if their QoS is currently enhanced by lack of neutrality.

Comment: Having a dumb old DSL Modem means I find it highly unlikely that anything the government does is likely to affect anything.   Maybe I am lucky - I thought living in the sticks made things worse. I was down in Charleston visiting my wife's aunt a few weeks ago and her Internet connection was atrocious.   I'd like to consider myself a distributist, as libertarianism is antithetical to the Golden Rule. I'm all for government breaking up the big corporations, just not telling them how  to do their business once they're broken up.

Comment: You're working through a VPN and don't think this is exactly the kind of not categorized traffic (since its not readable) which will be the first dropped on backbones and uplinks if your ISP get fees from NetFlix or Google to give a high priority to their traffic ? sounds naive

Comment: @tensibai dropped?  I don't think anyone is talking about dropping traffic, just rate limiting and at the rate I consume the data, I don't think it's gonna matter much - that's the point.  I think some data should be prioritized, I think those who can buy it should be able to buy additional bandwidth, but it shouldn't negatively affect any one else's experience - it's up the the telco's to make sure they've got the right sized pipe and not oversell.

Comment: @PeterTurner what do you think happen when a high priority traffic occupy 80% of the bandwidth ? Low priority packets are dropped in favor of high priority, needing a restransmit from the client. The whole point of ACK packets in TCP... At a certain point, if VPN bandwidth is limited on an uplink and enough clients used it, it raise to 100% use of the limit, you have to randomly drop packets you can't send in a timely fashion

Comment: (That's just how QoS works and analyzing your own connexion today will show you this already happen because there's QoS for certain services (voice, tv) with no distinction between providers, if you open the door to make a distinction, there will be problems for those not rich enough to compete.

Comment: @tens well I can tell you my business (remote data center monitoring) would be toast if we (and our customers) had to pay every ISP in the country extra dough to maintain the pipe we've currently got.    It's non-sense that B2B traffic would be denigrated by lack of net neutrality, they can't toast every SSH session in the planet, the ISPs would probably just wind up shooting themselves in the foot - they're not _that_ smart.

Comment: @PeterTurner why that ? If what google pay for youtube, facebook pay for being served quickly and what netflix pay for same reasons overcome any other professional use, I see no reason for it to not happen.

Comment: So your argument is that now, with regulations in place to prevent ISPs from treating your content differently, you have adequate service, how in the world does that mean that it is going to be okay to support allowing them to discriminate against you and favor serving others over you?  That you have adequate service now, despite having what you feel is a shady provider, means that *the current regulations are working*.  That's not an argument to get rid of them, it's an argument to *keep* them.

Comment: @servy, I don't believe any of the regulations have gone into effect yet.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297816/net-neutrality-and-stack-overflow-stack-exchange/297843?noredirect=1#comment966479_297826

Comment: @servy So... any regulations that have gone into effect during the last 11 years have had zero effect on my experience, that is not evidence that they're working and not evidence that their repeal will have any negative effect.  The only bump I got was from 1.5 megs to 10 and that was because I elected to give my ISP a few more bucks per month (and get _free_ long distance!).

Comment: @PeterTurner The regulations were put in place because the ISPs were being abusive in certain situations, and the regulations were put in place to prevent them from continuing that behavior and allowing it to spread.  That you weren't personally affected by the cases that brought the issue to the forefront doesn't mean that there isn't evidence of their effectiveness, or the problems that are inevitable when they're not there.  Since your personal experience doesn't have evidence either way, but the experiences of others *does* have *considerable* evidence, your assertion doesn't hold weight.

Comment: This is another uninformed post, at least three of your bullet points talk about CONTENT, Net Neutrality is NOT about content. There are other laws that address that, though most fall far short from meeting there expectation. You need to learn the issue or don't both posting if you don't care as you stated.

Comment: @htm Prior iterations of the law are about content,  this _rule_ is not even Net Neutrality as it has been [offered by Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_neutrality_in_the_United_States#Attempted_legislation), it's just a cop-out rule put in place by a lame duck administration overstepping its reach for the nth time and should rightly have been destroyed by any administration that claimed it cared anything about putting an end to over-regulation.

Comment: The prior iterations are about delivery of priority content (specific to service providers revenue), not content as you state in your bullets.

Comment: @htm yes and they're almost all about "Legal" and "Lawful" content.  Not sure how you vet that without packet inspection.

Answer (score -6):

## The recent bill is a good step forward towards net neutrality.

This bill will classify the internet in a way that lets the government control what the ISPs can send over their networks rather than companies.
In the united states, I do not fear the corruption of government nearly as much as the wrath of large companies.

Internet lines will be classified as government infrastructure, and tampering with them will be a federal crime. This deters malicious middlemen because now the internet companies aren't the ones pressing charges. It's the feds.

The government doesn't have nearly as many ways to abuse your data as big companies do. As a matter of fact, big companies are PAYING to get your data as you read this. This bill won't solve that problem though. It WILL solve many of the insecurities we have with ISPs collecting data, however.

The government has no incentive to censor or throttle the internet. With plenty of third party software that could censor anything the government would censor 'as a service', There's no reason that the government would need to censor anything. Letting them take the internet into their own hands won't cause any difference in browsing, aside from a better future.

Comment: "The government has no incentive to censor or throttle the internet." I would like to live on the planet you do. Sadly, I don't think there are actually any governments, anywhere, that this is true of. Certainly not the US, land of three-letter agencies and multi-billion-dollar interception operations. (Hmm, sounds like big companies aren't the only ones "PAYING to get your data as you read this".)

Answer (score -7):

From how I read the proposal (and I read all of it), all this sets out to do is revert regulations to a pre-2014 state, with additional (not less) oversight from the FCC.

In 2013 ISPs were not abusing their power, what is there to make us believe they will do it now?

All this action truly seems like unneeded fear mongering to me.

Comment: "In 2013 ISP's were not abusing their power" Most people would beg to differ. If anything, their abuse of power has gone unopposed for far longer then that.

Comment: In 2013, NetFlix wasn't consuming as much bandwidth as it does today, and ISP are not allowed to enforce NetFlix to pay a fee or be unavailable to their customers actually. If you're a netflix user, would you switch ISP¨every 6 moths to follow netflix ? (That's one in many, google has the same kind of bandwith usage proportion for ISP, the same principle arise). That's why net neutrality is important, to prevent ISP to select who is allowed to be seen by peoples. (More or less the same discussion exist in France)

Comment: There was such a big push to put these regulations in place in the first place precisely because the ISPs *were* abusing their power back in 2013.  They had started doing exactly the types of things people had feared they might do, and that was part of what helped build sufficient support to get these regulations put in place to begin with.  It wasn't (just) out of fear of what might happen, it was a direct response to what had *already* happened.

Comment: "In 2013 ISP's were not abusing their power" Actually, it was the '90s, when we as consumers could choose our ISPs and hold them directly accountable with our dollars.

Comment: @Tensibai Netflix does not consume an isp's bandwidth, it is the isp's customers and what they do that consumes the bandwidth. It is easy to blame netflix because they are so popular but it should be remembered that if netflix was not around then the traffic would just go to another streaming service such as amazon, hulu or youtube. It is such a shame that a company gets blamed for the traffic when it is the consumers who chose to use it.

Comment: @JoeW I'm doing the exact opposite to blaming Netflix, I'm saying ISP can't  select which traffic they allow actually and that is a good thing. Netflix is just an example of provider which can be impacted and someone being a customer of Netflix would have to choose his/her ISP according to this which is a bad thing IMHO.

Answer (score -7):

> why should or shouldn't we all head over to https://www.battleforthenet.com/ right now and use the handy form to send a letter to the FCC?

Because we're not all Americans?

> Even folks who aren't based in the US have probably benefited from the work of those who are at one point or another

This is irrelevant to net neutrality.

> if nothing else, this is where our servers live

Then this is a problem with Stack Exchange as a company and has nothing to do with any of the Q&A sites. You may write a blog post or make a public statement, but don't drag politics into the Q&A sites. They're not soapboxes: they're not for righting wrongs or for promoting an agenda.

Your post and most of the answers are written for Americans, with "foreigners" as an afterthought. [Your recent survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017) shows that about 75% are not from the US.

By all means, go public, protest, blackout your corporate web site or your blog, but leave the Q&A sites alone.

Comment: It affects your ability to access the site, so no, it's *not* just SE's problem.  It affects everyone who would like to use the site.  Yes, that would affect SE as a company, but it wouldn't *just* affect them.

Comment: @Servy what *is* SE's problem?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter The negative effects of losing net neutrality in the US.

Comment: This directly affects the entire SE network if implemented so you don't get to hide behind the *"please no politix"* flag on this one. There are times you have to have an opinion on what's going on outside your window and this is one of those times. SE are also free to use the SE network for whatever they see fit, including protecting their own business and livelihood.

Comment: @ivarni the issue here is that **not everybody agrees with your statement**. There are those who think net neutrality is bad, is a stalking horse for regulation of internet content, or just a ploy to benefit one set of giant powerful corporations (google etc) against another set of corporations who are smaller and less powerful (ISPs). Question is not who is right but whether you want to alienate those users who disagree by having the site take sides..

Answer (score -9):

## **Say No to Politics on Stack Overflow**

Really. Stop it with the politics.

Of course it's your right to post political views on your web properties.

But: Even if you are in the right, you are alienating those users who disagree with you.

Comment: I disagree. This question is a place to discuss the pros and cons of net neutrality. Not all users are in agreement. That's what makes the discussion useful.

Comment: "Say no to politics" except the politics you speak of will affect a majority of its users you mention would be alienated as well as the website itself.Do you enjoy being ignorant?

Comment: Politics are part of living in a democracy, move to Russia if you are not satisfied with how the process works here. Disagreement is one of the key parts of democracy and of course the ensuing compromise, when things work correctly.

Comment: Stack Exchange exists only on the Internet, and if net neutrality ever ends it would be a death sentence for pretty much the entire Internet (including SE). That means NN is important enough to be exempt from the "no political discussions" rule.

Comment: @dorukayhan "would be a death sentence for pretty much the entire Internet". Have you thought about seeking professional advice?

Comment: @Javia1492 "...on Stack Overflow". I care about politics. But I don't care to have politics everywhere.  SO is about programmers helping each other with technical issues. Just as the people maintaining the sewers, gas mains and electricity lines that zig-zagged under the Berlin Wall had to cooperate regardless of politics, so do we.

Comment: @htm11h I care about politics. I don't care to have politics everywhere and in everything. That is only desirable to those who want a totalitarian state.

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO They had to cooperate because if they didnt they would be killed. As far as SO being about programmers, yes, however, we programmers use this site. If the site is at risk due to some policies being pushed by the US government, then as US citizens/users of this website, one would think you'd take action to support the website (assuming you even care).

Comment: @Javia1492 "They had to cooperate because if they didnt they would be killed" Have you considered seeking professional help? West Germany wasn't going to kill anyone for refusing to cooperate. Actually, neither was the DDR, they only **killed people trying to *escape* the totalising philosophy which insisted that everything was political**.

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO Except East Berlin built the wall. What is your argument?

Comment: @Javia1492, there is no "except". That's my argument. The people who insist that everything is political are the people who built the wall. People whose job is to maintain infrastructure have to cooperate across boundaries *regardless* because goodwill and common humanity *must* transcend politics or we are all in deep trouble. StackOverflow ought to be siding with "transcend politics". That's what I am asking for.

Comment: It seems reasonable that SO may request users to take up it's cause on this matter, but making it an SO question with answers and comments for debating reduces SO to Slashdot or Reddit.

Answer (score -10):

### Stackoverflow is everything Net Neutrality isn't.

This statement is ridiclous (and how I actually ended up here):

> "Great! Let’s hear ’em. Instead of yet another mess of blog comments
>   that no one reads, I’ve kicked off a discussion over on Meta: – please
>   join in!"

https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/30/raise-voice-proclaim-need-net-neutrality/?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=system-message&utm_campaign=netneutrality

The mere fact that I was invited to a discussion in which my response is "blurred" along with not being able comment here without earning some type of reputation first is a cruel trick. **Don't ask for someone's voice if you don't even allow them to use it!**  If a false sense of merit makes ones voice any more valid then please tell people before they get here:

> "please join in!" (after you earn the right by our judgmental community)

*"Neutral" does not mean allowing someone to comment on answers, vote, and in-turn not reciprocating the same courtesy to others. Another example is when there's no explanation for a question getting deleted, it just simply just disappears like it never even happened because some high-up <strike>wanker</strike> person deemed so. **That's called biased, and it happens here every minute of every day** -- give someone at least an indication of why such action was taken instead of leaving them in the dark. *This is very unsettling*, and the mob mentality that it brings with it.

### A very prominent and famous programmer once said (about this site) in an e-mail, "If I took my car in the shop and returned minutes later to find they turned it into scrap do you think I'd ever go back?"

Alienating someone because they a first time visitor, don't think or act in some particular way doesn't make them less valuable. I came here today (for the first time on meta) because the blog "invited" me to do so. I was immediately put on an uneven playing field and this is not how fairness or neutrality works -- there's no concept of it here. It also drives people away that could have more (good) to offer than the majority of people perpetuating the bad put together.

### If the goal here is for someone to come to the conclusion that they're not welcomed and that this site an extremely poor representative for Net Neutrality it speaks that message in volumes.

Comment: Just watch the negative votes roll in so this post can be hidden... Nobody truly has a voice here unless they are the people who control it.

Comment: I hear you but there is really not much constructive to find between the meta noise. Don't expect upvotes for something that really brings nothing to the table .

Comment: @rene: Why do you ask for someones opinion though and not allow them to give it? It doesn't make a whole lot of sense... I would've made this a comment, but unfortunately I'm not "privileged" enough.

Comment: You wrote an answer here. With your opinion.

Comment: @ctfd You've given your opinion, and now others are giving _their_ opinion on what you wrote.

Comment: But why do you allow people to vote down my opinion so that it becomes hidden? Suppression isn't the answer to allowing ones voice to be heard.

Comment: It's not hidden...

Comment: @rene: Also the fact that I cannot vote any other answers up or down is ludicrous, how is this deemed at all fair?

Comment: Your opinion seems to be that commenting on meta should be allowed at all rep-levels which is a valid opinion but has not much to do with the topic at hand and if you post it as an FR you'll find plenty of similar requests explaining that it would open up so many SPAM possibilities that they rather not. Again, explain to me why  not being able to comment is relevant  to have here as an answer?

Comment: Write a good answer/question. 15 rep is not much to gain. Or get 200 on SO so you get the association bonus.

Comment: I'm trapped here, can't you see? You got me to write my opinion, and I don't get the same privilege to vote answers up or down, comment, etc. This is not how a fair system works... it's dictatorship.

Comment: That is right. It is still a bit within the SE network rules. Do know that downvote privilege is down to 100 here, 125 on normal sites so SE is not deaf for this kind of critique.

Comment: You know English, right? 3 accepted suggested-edits and you got your comment everywhere privilege. That could be earned in the time you spend going back and forth with me ... oth it is nice talking to someone.

Comment: I came here from the blog, and did not see anything mentioning that. And obviously I know English, unless you've got your own "stackoverflow" definition.

Comment: Well, that not being mentioned was maybe an oversight on SE's part. On the other hand you're the first to lash out about it and you're not the first to answer, nor the first 1-rep user. So I guess it depends a bit per user how they handle such a setback.

Comment: @Cai: Alright. So what is this called exactly? http://i.imgur.com/WZcQVuu.png

Comment: That starts at -8 and if you hover over it, the blur will be gone.

Comment: @rene: Why blur it though? I suppose to make it less important looking...

Comment: Meh, it's faded. It's not hidden... Not sure what any of this has got to do with net neutrality though

Comment: Yes, it is. in normal Q/A it is ofc to signal to casual readers: watch out, this answer might not be that good. Some, like you, find that troublesome if the question is not meant to let the best answer rise to the top but have a collection of opinions. I'm sure there is an FR to disable this feature on true discussion posts.

Comment: Remember that Stackexchange is rarely political like this. These rules are ideal for 99.9% of the questions that come here. Also, the last part of your answer seems to miss the meaning of Net Neutrality all together. It has nothing to do with how forums are moderated.

Comment: It's unfortunate that it's biased in this way. I noticed that the majority of the answers which are downvoted and blurred are authored by lower reputation users also, which only makes it more clear what is at work here.

Comment: Keep in mind that those answers are not just down voted, I see a +10/-18, +11/-20, +33/-55. It is not that they are just plain negative votes, they just happen to attract more *nay* sayers ...

Comment: If you have a problem with the rules of Stack Exchange, you should lay out the changes you think should be made, with logical reasons (tabling any "it's a conspiracy and they are censoring me because they don't like me") and post a new question on meta. That's where this belongs. It makes no sense here, and so you are getting down voted. People will read what you have to say, but people who use Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites appreciate how useful they are, and love them for it, so don't expect to make friends by coming here and trying to tell everyone Stack Exchange is evil.

Comment: @rp.beltran: Please don't try and put words in my mouth that I never said. My point is that I was unable (and still am) to participate in the "discussion" that I was invited to join in on in the same manner as everyone else here. It's misleading to tell someone that and then outright exclude them from commenting or voting as others can do. Being forthright is a better way of handling things so that people don't see through the cracks and start making these realizations.

Comment: [Related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271315/245360) on how new users here on MSE should give their feedback on network-wide proposals or discussions.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Thank you for finally making the only sensible comment here.

Comment: @rene: Trust me, the best answer does not always rise to the top. Here it's dictated by a select group which have total control over of it. I have no ability to vote as a newcomer and the outcome is predetermined based on one's status.

Comment: @ctfd You see, having to pass a test before getting your driver license isn't a dictatorial attitude - driving is a privilege you earn when you show yourself responsible enough to do that. It's the same with the SE. Until you show that you are a good user, with nice behavior and good reputation, you won't get any privileges.

Comment: @T.Sar: That's a really bad analogy. Opinions are not what decides who receives a license to drive a car, rather a written and driving test with a defined (set) criteria which is the same for everyone. As a driver I can't disallow someone from getting a license because I don't like how they drive. Being a "good" user can be interpreted however you want, but in order to get any privileges here someone is required to fulfill expectations (which are undefined) to those already with privileges.

Answer (score -11):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_neutrality), net neutrality "is the principle that internet service providers and governments regulating the Internet should treat all data on the Internet the same, **not discriminating ... [against] content**" (my emphasis).

## I very strongly disagree with this.

Let us look at an example. In Germany, distributing pornography to minors is forbidden by law. German websites with pornographic content must therefore install an age verification system to prevent minors from accessing their content. But since websites from other countries are not governed by German law, a German minor living in Germany will find a wealth of pornography by searching for "porn" in any search engine.

In effect, net neutrality subverts this specific German law.

Now you can think of minors watching porn however you like, but I am sure you will agree that in this case a national law, that was agreed upon through a democratic process, has been made obsolete by the principle of net neutrality.

There is a lot of other content – from nazi propaganda to ads selling drugs and weapons – that are illegal in Germany, but are a mere search engine query away for anyone living there.

If you think about it, basically *ISPs make money by distributing illegal goods*.

Interestingly enough, no one cries about ISPs blocking child porn sites. And that means that proponents of net neutrality do not really believe in net neutrality. They are not fighting for equal distribution of all content, or they would loudly oppose the blocking of child porn.

**What proponents of net neutrality really do is force the US American idea of free speech – which includes the unhindered distribution of pornography, racism, and instructions on how to build bombs – on countries that do not follow this ideology (which is the rest of the world).**

---

Personally I think that all content that is illegal in a certain country should be blocked from entering that country. And that until such filtering is technically possible, *all foreign content should be blocked*. Such a block would certainly inspire those making money from the distribution of content to invent such filtering methods.

If Germany alone blocked all foreign internet traffic, the money that American companies would loose would cause an instant leap in artificial intelligence.

Comment: Without net neutrality, your ISP could tax you 10 extra bucks per month for you to have access to Youtube. Or Gmail. Or Stack Overflow.  Or Facebook/Twitter. Actually, they could make every single website that is attractive for some reason a subscription based service. Also, your post doesn't make any sense - Net Neutrality isn't about distributing content for other countries, is about how ISP deals with content _inside US_. You missed the point by a mile.

Comment: @T.Sar (1) I explicitly discussed only the content aspect of net neutrality. I did not voice my opinion on other aspects of net neutrality, and I think they should not be confused with each other. (2) The legal discussion in the US may be about what goes on in the US, but it affects thouse outside of that country, too, and, most of all, the idea of net neutrality applies to everyone, as the answers about, for example, India have made clear.

Comment: "proponents of net neutrality do not really believe in net neutrality... or they would loudly oppose the blocking of child porn" That's a bit of a leap

Comment: If your kid has free, unrestricted and unsupervised access to the internet, _blame is on you_. Porn is the lesser of the issues there - perfectly okay content with user-interaction, like chat rooms or facebook, is far more dangerous than any risquè image they can find on the internet. They can end up making contact with the type of people you wouldn't want them nearby. Internet is not a babysitter, nor a place for children to be alone.

Comment: The current net neutrality regulations in place, those that are attempting to be repealed, don't prohibit ISPs from blocking *illegal* content.  They can and do have the ability to do that.  There also aren't any new proposals being advocated that would prevent that.  So you're just arguing a straw man.

Comment: I'd be surprised if any search engine would display results which led to child porn, or sites selling drugs, or anything like that. Those sites are supposed to be blocked by clauses stating that drug(etc)-related sites are illegal, not by monitoring all access to all content. If you're not convinced, read up about MegaUpload.

Comment: Your argument is completely baseless. You are arguing about content not speed or performance which is what net neutrality is about. Half the problem in this debate is that people DO NOT UNDERSTAND THE ISSUE. German laws have failed at blocking content and the same has happened in the US, taking away Net Neutrality does not change the content laws already on the books. Please learn the issue before you post.

Comment: > And that until such filtering is technically possible, all foreign content should be blocked. < I'd love to see how you would use the web with this rule implemented. You could whitelist only IP-addresses from your country and see how far you get using this own idea of yours :P

Comment: @htm11h That is your understanding of net neutrality, but other people do not limit net neutrality to speed and performance. See my quote from Wikipedia.

Comment: @user364227 forget Wikipedia, read the proposition. What if the telephone companies in the early days were able to prevent home users from making calls in favor of corporate customers that paid higher rates. What if your gas utility service was shut off at peak demand times because larger buildings (like apartment or factory) that required the utility paid more during those demand times. I do agree that the distribution of illegal content is questionable, but the same people that create the smut, or drugs, use electricity and gas to heat and lite their work space. Your argument is baseless.

Comment: The american idea of free speech is the only explicit and codified idea of free speech. Np let country has that. Germany can stick it with their censorship. From a country that only 90 years ago engaged in one of the world's biggest genocides via propaganda and censorship, Germany's laws on censorship should concern you greatly.

Answer (score -14):

Here's the problem I continue to have with Net Neutrality:

> It's a solution in search of a problem

Seriously. The arguments I've seen for vary wildly between (a small taste of what I've seen)

- ISPs can ban Google or any website they please
- ISPs will throttle websites to extort money (most point to the [Comcast/Netflix spat](https://technical.ly/philly/2014/05/09/graph-shows-netflix-speeds-changed-comcast-deal-comcast-roundup/) long before this rule)
- You pay for bandwidth and everything should be treated the same
- If we let in "fast lanes" everything else could become slow

But that's not a compelling case for having the government step in and, ad-hoc, make up rules about what can and cannot be done on the Internet. If [AT&T wants to sell its users unmetered video streaming](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2016/12/fcc-says-att-is-violating-net-neutrality-with-directv-data-cap-exemption/), why is that a bad thing?

Here's my reasons not to oppose this going back to the way it was

1. The government took a [1934 law about telephones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_Act_of_1934) to do this. That should give everyone pause. Telephones and the Internet are not the same thing.
2. If and when blocking/throttling becomes a problem, we should pass a law about it. You know, the whole democracy thing. This is too important to leave up to 3 people in Washington to make up as they please.
3. There's a ton of `ZOMG BAD THINGS!!!11` ideas running around about this (like blocking Google). I hate making decisions based on someone's bad ideas of how the Internet works and what bad things *might* happen. [When Slate has an article about chilling out about this, you know it's gone pretty sideways](http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/future_tense/2017/05/don_t_freak_out_about_the_fcc_s_new_approach_to_net_neutrality.html).

Now, here's a good counterpoint: Netflix and streaming services are eating up a ton of bandwidth. Like [37% of the Internet in North America](http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/01/20/netflix-boasts-37-share-of-internet-traffic-in-north-america-compared-with-3-for-apples-itunes). Did Comcast play dirty? Maybe. But there's an important point - when one company is eating up 1/3 of your resources, and you need to expand, do you

1. Split the cost equally among all your current paying customers, even though only 1/3 are using this service
2. Charge the service for having your techs help them reach your customers with a "fast lane", and then have them pass that cost along to their customers (they get faster service, you get better service in the non-fast-lane)

Net Neutrality means you can only do #1. Because all traffic is equal.

- [Ajit Pai, chairman of the FCC, in his own words on why he's against Net Neutrality](http://reason.com/reasontv/2017/04/26/fcc-ajit-pai-net-neutrality-internet)
- [Forbes contributor who is skeptical](https://www.forbes.com/sites/joshsteimle/2014/05/14/am-i-the-only-techie-against-net-neutrality/#7e1b4f9370d5)

Comment: Please don't spread the fallacy that a single customer chewing up a third of your bandwidth actually matters *at all*. It doesn't. Data transfer is cheap as can be and continues to get cheaper every day. You might be interested in reading this: [How much does data really cost an ISP?](http://broadbandnow.com/report/much-data-really-cost-isps/)

Comment: Would you also use this argument against the US Constitution and the Bill of Rights? Much of its language is preemptive and broad so that it can be applied over the course of hundreds of years. Net neutrality is another such effort that foresees obvious and immediate dangers and seeks to prevent them.

Comment: You say there are no problems net neutrality could solve, but you bring up the example of Netflix vs Comcast, which is an actual problem it is meant to solve...

Comment: The Internet is also a utility. It should be a dumb pipe just like electricity and water. If ISPs get the right to filter access to sites (aka intelligent pipes), then they should be responsible for the content too. That means when somebody is using AT&T to download child porn, it becomes AT&T's fault for allowing it.

Comment: So you claim that we shouldn't preemptively have regulations to prevent ISPs from doing things that they haven't yet done, while, *in the same post* going over a case of an ISP doing the exact thing that this type of regulation is designed to prevent.  This *isn't* preemptive.  It's reactive.  ISPs *had* their time being unregulated and being trusted to just not abuse that trust.  They choose to abuse that trust.  You're saying we should trust them *again* to not do the things they've already done.

Comment: Also there's a difference between net neutrality throttling and charging per bandwidth usage. There's no free access debate on charging someone for using 60GB and being charged more than someone using 30GB. Data caps and blanket speed throttling in *general* are a different matter.

Comment: @Machavity "If and when blocking/throttling becomes a problem.." It is! Right here, right now, for me. I'm from Russia, but I'm not much different in term of how I want my Internet access to work. You are basically suggesting to drink a lethal dose of poison and then call the ambulance *if and when* you will start dying. So, I'll tell you this: you can enjoy drinking poison on your own, but you may not involve others.

Comment: ISPs can (and sometimes do) impose data caps in addition to charging extra for more speed.  If the real problem is a small percentage of users chewing up all the bandwidth, then it doesn't matter HOW it is being used, just that it is and so the solution is NOT to block a certain site, but instead to enforce the caps. Boom! Net neutrality AND conservation of resources coexisting peacefully.

Comment: Data caps don't solve bandwidth problems. In fact, they don't solve any problem faced by the ISP. They are simply invented to make money. However, whilst they are a simple exploitation, they are not inherently un-neutral if they are applied equally. It's only when you start to talk about paid favouring that they're un-neutral. Bandwidth caps are entirely reasonable and fair, and paying to increase your bandwidth to *any* site is perfectly neutral. Paid favouring here is still un-neutral though.

Comment: I, for one, **appreciate** @Machavity taking the time to clearly express the case in opposition to Net Neutrality.  Whether you agree with him or not, at least both sides are now represented.

Comment: I think it's important to note that the ISPs here have an artificial monopoly. It's not like we get to choose which road to take to a popular club - we have to take their road, so if they know we are going to the popular place they are charging us and that place more. Capitalist arguments fail here, because it's not a free market.

Comment: @NathanielFord: I'm not sure the monopoly is actually *artificial*. It's a logical consequence of the very substantial costs of building infrastructure, and the still considerable costs of maintaining it. If a given company owns the infrastructure in an area, another company will need to duplicate that investment in order to compete at all, or else lease the infrastructure at a higher rate. If, on the other hand, the infrastructure is *not* owned by the company that built it, you can easily see why this would very strongly disincentivize any company from building infrastructure!

Comment: I think this post has a fundamental misunderstanding. If video streaming from Netflix, etc. takes up 37%, who the **** is on the receiving end? You charge *them* too, as it has always been done.

Comment: `If AT&T wants to sell its users unmetered video streaming, why is that a bad thing?` -> If there would be a free, open, and functioning market then I would agree, but there isn't, and it's not likely to develop any time soon either. In many ways Net Neutrality is just a band-aid on a defective and broken market, but until we can fix that, NN sounds like a good idea to me. In addition, there are also other concerns besides the ones you outlined, e.g. ISPs can start blocking "illegal" content with no clear appeal procedure (like YouTube is doing), which effectively all but destroys Fair Use.

Comment: "the very substantial costs of building infrastructure" A _very substantial_ portion of which has been subsidized, directly or indirectly, by the public over the last half-century.

Comment: I think this answer makes some salient points that should now be hidden by downvoting. While the individual MB may not cost a lot, ISPs *do* have to invest in infrastructure, and have to get paid for that. Companies whose business model relies on having ever more bandwith at their disposal, or individual customers who insist on downloading the internet should pay a larger share that those who would be fine with yesterday's internet infrastructure, shouldn't they? I for one would rather pay my share of the total traffic than subsidize heavy downloaders.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Depends on the country.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker " If there would be a free, open, and functioning market then I would agree, but there isn't" -- I don't think there's a conceptual problem with a new company going about and putting new cables into the ground. Expensive, you say? Well, that's kind of the point, isn't it?

Comment: @Raphael I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that the FCC is in the United States.

Comment: "I don't think there's a conceptual problem with a new company going about and putting new cables into the ground" The [existing providers certainly seem to have a "conceptual" problem with it](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2014/02/isp-lobby-has-already-won-limits-on-public-broadband-in-20-states/).

Comment: @Raphael This natural monopoly development is really why public services (like internet) shouldn't even be run by a private corporation. But secondary to that I'll take a super-regulated industry with capped profit margins.

Comment: @Magisch Yea well, we can discuss that. But the fact is that it's not. Nor is water, electricity, waste water, or even train tracks (in many/some countries). Nobody discusses "electricity neutrality" -- of *course* certain consumers have priority over others -- there's a market. I guess I'm confused where the demand for "net neutrality" comes from; there does not seem to be any precedent in "public" infrastructure. The history of the internet as "free" space that grew somewhat organically is no precedent itself.

Comment: @Raphael The protection of the internet as the free space for human endeavour and creativity is one of the most important things to secure right now. And no, water companies can't just suddenly stop your water because the billionaire next door wants to have a decadent water slide on a hot day.

Comment: @Magisch That's a rather philosophical argument, not an economic one. If that's your perspective, I recommend you lobby for de-privatising the internet, as opposed to restricting the private market.

Comment: @Raphael You completly failed to reply to my second point, for public service providers there is absolutely precedent for regulating what they can and can't discriminate on.

Comment: @Magisch These things differ so heavily between countries, and I'm not sure what the exact situation is anywhere. I'm pretty sure there are prioritizations on electricity in Germany, though (hospitals, airports, certain industries over households). In many countries in the world, 24/7 electricity is *not* the norm and only the very wealthy have it.

Comment: @Raphael No, generally not. Important places all have generators and outages are so rare in our mostly publicly (hah!) run electricity grid that in my 22 years of life I've experienced a total of 3 power outages, none of which were longer then 30 minutes.

Comment: +1 While I don't agree with you on this topic, the question did ask for reasons against Net Neutrality and this is a well thought out answer. I wish this wasn't downvoted so low, this post seems useful in answering the original question, 'Why would anyone be against net netraulity.  Instead of downvoting into oblivion an answer we don't like, how about we have a reasonable and rational conversation about it?

Comment: Yes, Net Neutrality only allows you to do #1. Your customers are already paying you for the bandwidth they are utilizing. Where the content comes from should not matter. It is your customers utilizing it not the content provider. If your customers were getting the content from 1,000,000 separate providers instead of a single provider, are you going to 'work with' each of them? If your business model is flawed, then perhaps you need to change it, how it changes is between you and your customers.

Comment: @Raphael: There can be prioritizations for electricity usage, but that is an extremely different thing to prioritizing whoever can pay the most. In this country, the prioritizations are set out in law and the rest is free access, equal obligation to all. NN is even more important because there is nobody else to buy from. If our energy providers started refusing to sell to some businesses or jacking up rates, those businesses would just go elsewhere. In the US this cannot be done.

Comment: @Raphael It's not about "cables in the ground". I can choose from a myriad of electricity and gas providers ... yet only from two internet providers. Anyone can set up an ISP in their bedroom, and in the past many actually have, but for various reasons in many countries (not just US) ISPs have been taken over by a monopoly or duopoly.

Comment: -1, despite agreeing that _some_ retreat from full net neutrality could be reasonable.  The issue here is that, if an ISP can start modifying how people access sites and which they access, then that opens the door to all sorts of dynamics and political games that the vast majority of Americans simply don't have time to play.  So, while allowing ISP's to charge heavy users more might not be a bad idea, other retreats from neutrality can allow corruption simply because people won't have time to fight every little battle.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I see. In Germany, we have many more internet providers (event though they all buy from the same, formerly state-owned company).

Comment: @Machavity, Re **1)** How is ISPs banning Google not an issue? Bing can pay your ISP a million and say ban Google, and you'd have no more Google. How is that not a problem?