# Dismissing the Net neutrality banner on one site should dismiss it on all sites

Tags: feature-request, design, notification-bar

Recently I have seen net neutrality banner on the top of any SE site:

> [image: banner]

I've closed it on MSE, but saw it again on SO, I've closed it too, and saw it on ruSO... and so on.

Please don't show it again on any other SE sites if I already close it once.

Comment: Ah, good point. I don't know if we'll have a chance to make the changes needed to make it behave that way this time (the banner isn't gonna be live long enough for it to really matter, basically), but we should keep it in mind for any future dismissable banners that apply to multiple sites (I believe this is the first one we've ever done that does).

Comment: Well it's bit tricky: what about sites you join after dismissing it on a site? Should the banner be dismissed there too?

Comment: I think SO give that much important to net neutrality

Comment: @ShadowWizard Eh, not really an issue. Even if all we can do is minimize impact... we could set a cookie for most Q&A sites at .stackexchange.com, which would also catch all new sites. That'd reduce the number of dismisses down to 7 (assuming no new SLDs). There are other things we can consider as well (e.g. account id-based entry in a cache shared by all sites for logged in users). Not sure if I'm missing any implications there off the top of my head, though... Hence my theory that it'll be a "next time" kind of thing. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard On a second read of your comment... IMO the answer to "should the banner be dismissed on sites you join after dismissing it" is a solid "yes". This request reads to me as "make the dismiss work network-wide".

Comment: Thanks @Adam, this makes sense indeed.

Comment: @Adam while at it, is this possible to bring the banner back after dismissing it? Someone might click the dismiss by mistake, or later regret it and check again what it said. If done network wide, better also add some option to bring it back, no?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Eh. If all else fails, there's always incognito windows. I could see a more robust feature set for account-specific, less temporary notices, but for stuff like this? I think it's fine not to worry about it too much.

Comment: Gah. I just switched devices and now I have to dismiss them all again - could this *also* be account-based so that I don't have to dismiss it on different devices?

Comment: Isn't it fun when a small feature turns out in a 6 to 8 weeks monster with many fail cases. And here we are only talking about a banner ... don't get me started on a Q/A feature ...

Comment: @Adam lol, of course... blonde moment, forgot about that option.

Comment: If we close a banner on a site, it doesn't appear again. But when I change to other site, it is showing up. I closed it again. I think there should be a dialogue box like we see when we unupvote a comment.

Comment: When I saw this meta question earlier, I didn't care. ~8 SE sites later, I care. Bad UX. _Almost_ as bad as the "we use cookies" warnings I have to keep dismissing all across the web; almost.

Comment: [Ffffffffffffffffffffuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju4Z9.png)

Comment: @Won't [too late](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38725282#38725282) my friend.

Comment: >  (the banner isn't gonna be live long enough for it to really matter, basically) < --- [the same banner is now being used to advertise Podcast episodes!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334137/dismiss-the-meet-the-overflow-and-podcast-episode-banners-network-wide)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've hacked a very simple [userscript](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/blob/master/dismiss-banner/dismiss-banner.user.js) ([direct install link](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/raw/master/dismiss-banner/dismiss-banner.user.js)) which lifts the heavy burden of dismissing the banner for you.

For reference, here's the current source:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Dismiss Net Neutrality Banner
// @namespace   https://github.com/Glorfindel83/
// @description Automatically dismisses the Net Neutrality banner whenever you visit a (new) site.
// @author      Glorfindel
// @version     0.1
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
  "use strict";
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#net-neutrality-dismiss").click();
  }, 100);
})();
```

As with all userscripts, you'll need a userscript manager, e.g. [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Chrome, to install it.

Comment: Chrome hasn't let me "directly" install scripts like this for years; they have to be in the store. What am I missing?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).

Comment: That's better; thanks

Comment: I find it crazy that we need to install an extension and a userscript to get sane behaviour from a banner on Stack Exchange. Stack Exchange, y'know, where all the programming experts of the world hang out?!

Comment: Turns out setting a cookie once for the .stackexchange.com domain prevents the banner from showing up on all sub-domains: `document.cookie = "net-neutrality=closed;path=/;domain=.stackexchange.com;max-age=3600"`. Leaves only dismissing on SO, SU, SF and the few other custom domains.

Comment: I can tell that you poured hours of work into this code, +1 for effort :P