# Net neutrality banner has a bad design ... on Graphic Design

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, notification-bar

There's a design problem with the Net Neutrality banner. Apart from the fact that you have to dismiss it [on every site you visit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298260/dismissing-the-net-neutrality-banner-on-one-site-should-dismiss-it-on-all-my-ass), it looks awkward on [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) (of all places ...) – the dismiss button is only partially visible:

[image]

There might be more sites affected by this, but I'm afraid the banner will be burnt into my screen if I see it more often so I can't check.

Comment: hmm. probably they want to show the graphic designers what a bad design will look like

Comment: it's fixed in repo and waiting for build... but honestly I'm not even sure if you will be able to see it fixed before we take this banner off.

Comment: Thanks @Paweł. I'm pretty sure I won't see it, because (a) I already dismissed it and (b) I have a [userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298295/295232).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A quick inspect on the element shows the actual issue, when compare the other sites with the GRAPHIC DESIGN notification bar, the following class caused the alignment issue.

```
.s-hero._small .-container, .s-hero._small._fixed-width .-container { 
    padding: 0
```

changing the `padding: 15px` (the same as in the other site's notification bar) will solve the problem.

Screenshot after changed the **padding**:

[image: Notification bar style issue]