# Code of Conduct banner looks awkward on some sites (GD, AU)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, code-of-conduct, notification-bar

The new Code of Conduct banner is displayed awkwardly on some sites; there's a rather large gap between the top bar and the banner. Check [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) (... the irony ...)

[image]

and [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/):

[image]

On [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/), [similar problems](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5750/39069) have been reported.

Comment: Not really the same issue, but it also breaks [Photography.SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5750/updated-code-of-conduct-banner-messing-up-site-design)

Comment: Eh, I'm not sure if this is something to be fixed right away, as the banners are ephemeral anyway.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος there will always be a new banner. At least this one is looking better than the [previous incarnation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298278/295232).

Comment: @Glorfindel That's why I said "right away". ;-)

Comment: On https://ux.stackexchange.com/ it fully covers the site name and logo, which is pretty bad user experience...

Comment: Looks much better now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2usH1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sites will be fixed by the soon to roll out unified theme. Good news is that two of them are in the first batch and graphic design will come shortly after.