# Parsing post titles depends on site

Tags: bug, internal-links

Looks like question titles parsing from the address works fully only on MSE. The following links tested in preview mode via iOS app:

```
 - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536546/176217
 - https://stackoverflow.com/q/24478830/3240681
 - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345125/3240681
 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298260/339911
```

> [image: mse]
>
> [image: so]
>
> [image: mso]
>
> [image: ruso]
>
> [image: ruso.meta]

This is probably intentional behavior, i.e. parse only affected to site links, but I don't understand why not to allow full parsing for any site.

Comment: This is definitely by design. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108475/284336 seems to have been something they're planning to revisit but haven't. Should probably be a FR with a request for full network integration of the link conversion.