# Can the AI banner disappear globally once dismissed on any site?

Tags: feature-request, design, notification-bar, ai-tools, overflowai

I've dismissed it here on MSE, but I still see it on [Super User](https://superuser.com). Given that I've already seen and dismissed the banner once, I don't really want to have to dismiss it on each site.

[image: New! Learn more about AI on Stack Overflow]

(Ignore the font size - that is a mobile bug)
Possibly related: [Dismissing the Net neutrality banner on one site should dismiss it on all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298260/dismissing-the-net-neutrality-banner-on-one-site-should-dismiss-it-on-all-sites)

Comment: It also doesn't appear on all sites for some reason.

Comment: I see it only on Stack Overflow. (Not here, and not on other sites.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack I’ve added a screenshot

Comment: Ohh. I get it now. They put it only in the tech sites, but e.g. not in arqade, cooking, etc.

Comment: I don't know, I didn't see it on super user and I haven't dismissed it. Seems a little buggy.

Comment: I added the selector for it to my mod strike userscript (https://stackapps.com/questions/9747/user-style-for-mod-strike); that will remove it (and moderation features) across all sites.

Comment: This should be how it works already, if dismissed by a logged in-user. It seems like there might just be a short sync delay – I initially still saw the banner on Server Fault after dismissing it on Super User, but it is gone from Server Fault as well now.

Comment: @V2Blast Is it also supposed to dismiss the "join this community" banner?

Comment: @bobeyt6isstricken: Looks like it's not intentional. I'll file a bug report internally.

Comment: @cocomac based on the comment above, maybe replace [tag:feature-request] with [tag:bug].