# Can I still get involved in the fight for Net Neutrality if I'm from a different country?

Tags: discussion, net-neutrality

WRT [Stackoverflow and Net Neutrality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297816/net-neutrality-and-stack-overflow-stack-exchange)

I'm from South Africa. I don't know what the politics in the US is like and I don't know exactly whats happening. Most poignantly, I have no senator or representative to contact.

Can I still get involved? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297821/245360) in the question you linked:

> Some might say that "foreigners" (non-U.S. persons) might not have a say in this, but as I said above this is one of the few times I encourage them to.
>
> So as a foreigner, the specific form Shog9 linked to won't let you fill it out and send a letter to the FCC as you need a United States address, [but the FCC has a contact page](https://www.fcc.gov/about/contact), so you can still tell them to suck-it (figuratively speaking). You can also [view official comments on this proceeding](https://www.fcc.gov/ecfs/search/filings?proceedings_name=17-108) and add your own, simply click "+ New Filing" or "+ Express". (You can even upload documents if you click "+ New Filing".) And if for some reason that link quits working, search for proceeding "17-108", that's the "Restoring Internet Freedom" proposal to eliminate net-neutrality.

Comment: Ah I wish i'd seen the answer...