# Edit by deleted user is incorrectly attributed on some pages to anonymous users

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, anonymous-visitors

Look at this edit:

[image: Seems to be by a deleted user]

On its "link" page, however, it has no username:

[image: Shows no name]

It seems to be an approved edit by a deleted "user173448". However, clicking on the button to get to the review page, it says it's by an anonymous user:

[image: Actually by an anonymous user]

**What's up?**

Looking at the Internet Archive, I found that [the user with that ID did exist, once](https://web.archive.org/web/20160702111642if_/http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/173448/jww). Thus, it was not an anonymous user.

Comment: Can you link the post so others can investigate?

Comment: @Alex this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/51991 https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/297816/revisions

Comment: @Alex https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297816/399694—linked on images

Comment: There is a known bug where suggested edits by deleted users show up as having been suggested by an "anonymous user", when they actually aren't.